# Do you use NULL or 0 (zero) for pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, null

In the early days of C++ when it was bolted on top of C, you could not use NULL as it was defined as `(void*)0`. You could not assign NULL to any pointer other than `void*`, which made it kind of useless. Back in those days, it was accepted that you used `0` (zero) for null pointers.

To this day, I have continued to use zero as a null pointer but those around me insist on using `NULL`. I personally do not see any benefit to giving a name (`NULL`) to an existing value - and since I also like to test pointers as truth values:

```
if (p && !q)
  do_something();
```

then using zero makes more sense (as in if you use `NULL`, you cannot logically use `p && !q` - you need to explicitly compare against `NULL`, unless you assume `NULL` is zero, in which case why use `NULL`).

Is there any objective reason to prefer zero over NULL (or vice versa), or is all just personal preference?

Edit: I should add (and meant to originally say) that with RAII and exceptions, I rarely use zero/NULL pointers, but sometimes you do need them still.

Comment: wait, isn't a null pointer required to evaluate as false regardless if null is zero internally or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c#comment12629545_9895101 and http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html confirm this

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Here's Stroustrup's take on this: [C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null)

> In C++, the definition of `NULL` is 0, so there is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. Another problem with `NULL` is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard code, `NULL` was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.
>
> If you have to name the null pointer, call it `nullptr`; that's what it's called in C++11. Then, `nullptr` will be a keyword.

That said, don't sweat the small stuff.

Comment: Bjarne wrote this before C++ 0x started working on a new null type.  It will be the case that NULL will be used for this type when it is available for a platform, and I think you'll see a C-change in the general consensus about this.

Answer (score 127):

There are a few arguments (one of which is relatively recent) which I believe contradict Bjarne's position on this.

1. **Documentation of intent**

   Using `NULL` allows for searches on its use and it also highlights that the developer **wanted** to use a `NULL` pointer, irrespective of whether it is being interpreted by the compiler as `NULL` or not.
2. **Overload of pointer and 'int' is relatively rare**

   The example that everybody quotes is:

   ```
    void foo(int*);
    void foo (int);

    void bar() {
      foo (NULL);  // Calls 'foo(int)'
    }
   ```

   However, at least in my opinion, the problem with the above is not that we're using `NULL` for the null pointer constant: it's that we have overloads of `foo()` which take very different kinds of arguments.  The parameter must be an `int` too, as any other type will result in an ambiguous call and so generate a helpful compiler warning.
3. **Analysis tools can help TODAY!**

   Even in the absence of C++0x, there are tools available today that verify that `NULL` is being used for pointers, and that `0` is being used for integral types.
4. **[C++ 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) will have a new `std::nullptr_t` type.**

   This is the newest argument to the table.  The problem of `0` and `NULL` is being actively addressed for C++0x, and you can guarantee that for every implementation that provides `NULL`, the very first thing that they will do is:

   ```
    #define NULL  nullptr
   ```

   For those who use `NULL` rather than `0`, the change will be an improvement in type-safety with little or no effort - if anything it may also catch a few bugs where they've used `NULL` for `0`.  For anybody using `0` today... well, hopefully they have a good knowledge of regular expressions...

Comment: Those are some rather good points, I must admit. I am glad that C++ 0x will have a null type, I think that will make a lot of stuff cleaner.

Comment: Nice summary. A small nitpick - the new null will be the keyword 'nullptr' and/or the new type 'std::nullptr_t'

Comment: @Richard, why not do the opposite? You can use Meyers nullptr_t then when 0x gets avaliable you remove the `#include` and keep in the safe side all the way.

Comment: @fnieto:  Good point.  That approach has a safety advantage for C++ '98/'03 too.

Comment: `#define NULL nullptr` seems hazardous.  For better or worse, lots of legacy code uses NULL for things other than 0.  For example, handles are often implemented as some integral type, and setting them to `NULL` is not uncommon.  I've even seen abuses like using `NULL` to set a `char` to a zero-terminator.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I would only say it was hazardous if there was a danger of the code silently compiling and having a different meaning.  I'm pretty sure that this isn't the case, so in fact all the incorrect uses of NULL would be detected.

Comment: @RichardCorden: Um, that assumes that those other uses of `NULL` are actually incorrect.  Many APIs have long used `NULL` with handles, and that is in fact the documented usage with many of them.  It's not pragmatic to suddenly break those and declare that they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: It's not black and white.  If you're using such an API then you'll have to quickly change NULl back to 0.  If you're not using such an API then you can take advantage of the places where the usage *is borken* and fix them.

Answer (score 49):

Use `NULL`.  `NULL` shows your intent.  That it is `0` is an implementation detail that should not matter.

Comment: 0 is not an implementation detail. The standard defines 0 to be whatever bit pattern represents a null pointer.

Comment: As if ..!! Dude, C++ is a low level language! Use 0, it's a well known idiom.

Comment: I understand that it is a part of the standard.  It is an implementation detail as far as reading the code goes.  The reader should think "NULL pointer" not "0 which in this case means NULL pointer, not a number I could be doing arithmetic with."

Comment: +1. Agreed with Andy. @Ferruccio, Implementation *detail* of programmer's idea is not the same as compiler's implementation *defined*

Comment: if you use NULL, in a plain code without complex header, you will find the error of "NULL is not defined in this scope"..

Comment: if "NULL is not defined in this scope" occurs, then just `#include <stddef.h>`

Answer (score 47):

I always use:

- `NULL` for pointers
- `'\0'` for chars
- `0.0` for floats and doubles

where 0 would do fine. It is a matter of signaling intent. That said, I am not anal about it.

Comment: ya probably should use 0.0F for floats, to avoid the implicit typecast

Answer (score 34):

I stopped using NULL in favor of 0 long ago (as well as as most other macros). I did this not only because I wanted to avoid macros as much as possible, but also because NULL seems to have become over-used in C and C++ code. It seems to be used whenever a 0 value is needed, not just for pointers.

On new projects, I put this in a project header:

```
static const int nullptr = 0;
```

Now, when C++0x compliant compilers arrive, all I have to do is remove that line.
A nice benefit of this is that Visual Studio already recognizes nullptr as a keyword and highlights it appropriately.

Comment: Using NULL will be more portable long term.  'nullptr' will be available for some platforms and not for others.  Your solution here requires that you use the preprocessor around your declaration to ensure that it's only present when required.  NULL will do this automatically.

Comment: I disagree. It will be less portable in the short term until compilers catch up. Long term, it will be just as portable and maybe a little more readable.

Comment: Plus you can always #define nullptr NULL for your non-C++0x compiler.

Comment: I agree that `NULL` is overused, I've seen it used to refer to the zero terminator character in a string!  I don't think that justifies avoiding it entirely though.

Answer (score 23):

```
    cerr << sizeof(0) << endl;
    cerr << sizeof(NULL) << endl;
    cerr << sizeof(void*) << endl;

    ============
    On a 64-bit gcc RHEL platform you get:
    4
    8
    8
    ================
```

The moral of the story.  You should use NULL when you're dealing with pointers.

1) It declares your intent (don't make me search through all your code trying to figure out if a variable is a pointer or some numeric type).

2) In certain API calls that expect variable arguments, they'll use a NULL-pointer to indicate the end of the argument list.  In this case, using a '0' instead of NULL can cause problems.  On a 64-bit platform, the va_arg call wants a 64-bit pointer, yet you'll be passing only a 32-bit integer.  Seems to me like you're relying on the other 32-bits to be zeroed out for you?  I've seen certain compilers (e.g. Intel's icpc) that aren't so gracious -- and this has resulted in runtime errors.

Comment: `NULL` perhaps is not portable, and not safe. There might be platforms that still `#define NULL 0` (according to [Stroustrup's FAQ: Should I use NULL or 0?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null) quoted by the top question and it is among the first search results). At least in older C++, `0` has a special conceptual meaning in pointer context. You should not think concretely about bits. Also note that in different integer contexts (`short`, `int`, `long long`) "`sizeof(0)`" will be different. I think this answer is a little bit misguided.

Comment: (Personally as a C programmer in daily life, I came to visit this question to understand why people want to use `NULL` instead of `(char *)0`, `(const char *)0` or `(struct Boo *)0` or `(void *)0` or whatever to expresses the intent more clearly - without being (in my opinion) too cumbersome.)

Comment: Vote up. it's happening at msvc2013 C compiler. in 64bit, 0 when convert to a pointer is not guarantee to be NULL Pointer.

Comment: NULL is well defined in the standard, so it is absolutely portable. but using NULL is more clear, and after you upgrade to C++11, you can search and replace NULL to be nullptr easily, but for 0, how can you do for it?

Answer (score 17):

If I recall correctly NULL is defined differently in the headers that I have used. For C it is defined as (void*)0, and for C++ it's defines as just 0. The code looked something like:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL (void*)0
#else
#define NULL 0
#endif
```

Personally I still use the NULL value to represent null pointers, it makes it explicit that you're using a pointer rather than some integral type. Yes internally the NULL value is still 0 but it isn't represented as such.

Additionally I don't rely on the automatic conversion of integers to boolean values but explicitly compare them.

For example prefer to use:

```
if (pointer_value != NULL || integer_value == 0)
```

rather than:

```
if (pointer_value || !integer_value)
```

---

Suffice to say that this is all remedied in C++11 where one can simply use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, and also `nullptr_t` that is the type of a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 16):

I would say history has spoken and those who argued in favour of using 0 (zero) were wrong (including Bjarne Stroustrup). The arguments in favour of 0 were mostly aesthetics and "personal preference".

After the creation of C++11, with its new nullptr type, some compilers have started complaining (with default parameters) about passing 0 to functions with pointer arguments, because 0 is not a pointer.

If the code had been written using NULL, a simple search and replace could have been performed through the codebase to make it nullptr instead. If you are stuck with code written using the choice of 0 as a pointer it is far more tedious to update it.

And if you have to write new code right now to the C++03 standard (and can't use nullptr), you really should just use NULL. It'll make it much easier for you to update in the future.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup prefers using 0 just because he doesn't like macro but also doesn't want to introduce a new keyword. the history proves he was wrong.

Answer (score 11):

I once worked on a machine where 0 was a valid address and NULL was defined as a special octal value.  On that machine (0 != NULL), so code such as

```
char *p;

...

if (p) { ... }
```

would not work as you expect.  You HAD to write

```
if (p != NULL) { ... }
```

Although I believe most compilers define NULL as 0 these days I still remember the lesson from those years ago:  NULL is not necessarily 0.

Comment: You were not using a compliant compiler. The standard says NULL *is* 0 and that the compiler should convert 0 in a pointer context into a proper true NULL value for the arch.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  This was in mid-80s before ANSI produced a C standard.   There was no such thing as compliance then and compiler writers were free to interpret the language as they saw fit.  That's why a standard was necessary.

Comment: @EvanTeran This isn't true for C. `(void *)0` must _compare equal_ to `NULL`, but it doesn't actually have to be `0`. Some people have argued that `NULL` should be `0xffffffff...` or `0xf7ffffff...` since `0x00` may be a valid address, but so far, most implementations use `NULL` = `0`.

Comment: @yyny you are mistaken. There is a difference between the "null constant" and the "null value".

The null constant is BY DEFINITION, `0` according to the standard, this is what you write in your code. 

However, the compiler may choose to emit a different VALUE for the null constant in the resultant machine code. 

In other words, when you write `p = 0;` (where p is a pointer), the compiler will see the `0` as the null constant. But when emitting the instruction to store "null", will store the machine-specific null value which may or may not be literally the address `0x0`.

Answer (score 11):

I usually use 0. I don't like macros, and there's no guarantee that some third party header you're using doesn't redefine NULL to be something odd.

You could use a nullptr object as proposed by Scott Meyers and others until C++ gets a nullptr keyword:

```
const // It is a const object...
class nullptr_t 
{
public:
    template<class T>
    operator T*() const // convertible to any type of null non-member pointer...
    { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    operator T C::*() const   // or any type of null member pointer...
    { return 0; }

private:
    void operator&() const;  // Can't take address of nullptr

} nullptr = {};
```

Google "nullptr" for more info.

Comment: Any third-party library that defines NULL to anything other than 0 (or `(void*)0` if being compiled as C code) is just asking for trouble and should not be used.

Comment: Have you ever actually seen a library that redefines NULL?  Ever?  If such a library ever existed, you'd have bigger problems than the redefined NULL, such as that you're using a library that is dumb enough to redefine NULL.

Comment: Well over a decade ago I vaguely remember having to deal with some 3rd-party headers, possibly either Orbix or ObjectStore, that did define NULL. I think I have a pathological hatred of macros after wasting several days and nights trying to get various 3rd-party headers to work with windows.h.

Comment: "don't like macros" is an odd critique of an object-like #define.  Maybe you mean to say that you don't like the C-preprocessor?

Comment: @Andrew - The only benefit of `NULL` over `(type *)0` is searchability, it seems to me. Otherwise it seems unnecessary obfuscation if it were not a C idiom. I personally think the idiom of spreading `NULL`'s all over the place deserves to die. `NULL` is useless macro in my opinion. Occam's razor got some work to do here...

Comment: Redefining standard macros is undefined behavior iirc.

Comment: NULL is a standard macro and should not be redefined in any third party library.

Answer (score 10):

I think the standard guarantees that NULL == 0, so you can do either.  I prefer NULL because it documents your intent.

Comment: If you have nested structures, I think saying `foo.bar_ptr = (Bar *) 0` expresses the intent much clearer than `foo.bar_ptr = NULL`. This habit also empowers the compiler to catch misconception errors for you. For me, `foo.bar_ptr = 0` expresses the intent as well as using `NULL` if I know that `foo.bar_ptr` is a pointer.

Answer (score 10):

Using either 0 or NULL will have the same effect.

However, that doesn't mean that they are both good programming practices. Given that there is no difference in performance, choosing a low-level-aware option over an agnostic/abstract alternative is a bad programming practice. **Help readers of your code understand your thought process**.

NULL, 0, 0.0, '\0', 0x00 and whatelse all translate to the same thing, but are different logical entities in your program. They should be used as such. NULL is a pointer, 0 is quantity, 0x0 is a value whose bits are interesting etc. You wouldn't assign '\0' to a pointer whether it compiles or not.

I know some communities encourage demonstrating in-depth knowledge of an environment by breaking the environment's contracts. Responsible programmers, however, make maintainable code and keep such practices out of their code.

Answer (score 6):

Strange, nobody, including Stroustroup mentioned that. While talking a lot about standards and aesthetics nobody noticed that it is *dangerous* to use `0` in `NULL`'s stead, for instance, in variable argument list on the architecture where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)`. Like Stroustroup, I prefer `0` for aesthetic reasons, but one has to be careful not to use it where its type might be ambiguous.

Comment: And in those dangerous places you can still use `0` provided you specify which `0` you mean -- for example `(int *)0`, `(char *)0`, `(const char *)0` or `(void *)0` or `(unsigned long long) 0` or whatever. This in my opinion expresses the intent much clearer than `NULL`.

Comment: Sure, if you don't know what `NULL` stands for.

Comment: I personally find it a little bit distasteful to *needlessly* cast something to `(void *)` when I could use the exact type. I purposefully gave example of (typically) 64-bit integer in the list because it is analogous to the pointer case. Furthermore, if my recollection that older C++ defined `NULL` as `0` is accurate (it is years since I programmed in C++),  then we witness no improvement in program correctness. Newer C++ standard fortunately provides  `nullptr` keyword, so we can get rid of this `NULL` uglity and the whole controversy when writing newer C++.

Comment: Well, that's why casting to `(void*)` has been abstracted to `NULL`. And `NULL` actually does express the intent quite clearly most of the time. And I think your recollection is wrong. Not sure about standards, but in practice I believe it's been `(void*)0`. And yess, `nullptr` is a nice prettifier, though it amounts to the same `NULL` thing — specifying null-pointer without specifying type.

Comment: Quote from [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null): "In C++, the definition of `NULL` is **0**, so there is only an aesthetic difference." Please see the accepted, topmost answer by Martin Cote. I do not know if things have changed since the C++11 standard and its implementations manifested (`nullptr` keyword).

So using `NULL` in some places (variadic argument lists), even if it expresses intent in your opinion, could in some/many platforms just produce the exact wrong code you were trying to avoid and make the C programmer that debugs your C++ code *really* confused.

Comment: C++11 `nullptr` is a **keyword** and much robust than `NULL` which is a **macro**. Using `nullptr` - when available - should more widely amount to correct code across platforms whereas `NULL` could lead to surprises.

Comment: @FooF, on some platforms — maybe. In my reality it worked and therefore I suspect it's been defined as a pointer. As for robustness, yes, what I was trying to say that using `nullptr` bears the same message as `NULL`, that was only regarding expressing the intent you mentioned in the very beginning.

(Preprocessing `NULL` on modern `gcc` yields `__null`, whatever it is).

Comment: To tell the truth, I am surprised that Stroustrup's FAQ still — after birth of C++11 and C++ compiler communities and vendors having concluded this is not practical — says `NULL` macro is defined as `0`. Coming to personal taste, I think `NULL` macro is an useless relic/idiom — almost as ridiculous as defining macros for `(short) 0`, `(unsigned long long) 0`, `'\0'`, and so on (especially when we already have `0L`, `0.0f`, `0.0` etc defined by the core language).

Comment: @FooF, when it comes to personal taste, I don't like capitalisation ;)

Answer (score 4):

I try to avoid the whole question by using C++ references where possible.  Rather than

```
void foo(const Bar* pBar) { ... }
```

you might often be able to write

```
void foo(const Bar& bar) { ... }
```

Of course, this doesn't always work; but null pointers can be overused.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with Stroustrup on this one :-)
Since NULL is not part of the language, I prefer to use 0.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly personal preference, though one could make the argument that NULL makes it quite obvious that the object is a pointer which currently doesn't point to anything, e.g.

```
void *ptr = &something;
/* lots o' code */
ptr = NULL; // more obvious that it's a pointer and not being used
```

IIRC, the standard does not require NULL to be 0, so using whatever is defined in <stddef.h> is probably best for your compiler.

Another facet to the argument is whether you should use logical comparisons (implicit cast to bool) or explicity check against NULL, but that comes down to readability as well.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use NULL as it makes clear that your intent is the value represents a pointer not an arithmetic value.  The fact that it's a macro is unfortunate, but since it's so widely ingrained there's little danger (unless someone does something really boneheaded).  I do wish it were a keyword from the beginning, but what can you do?

That said, I have no problem with using pointers as truth values in themselves.  Just as with NULL, it's an ingrained idiom.

C++09 will add the the nullptr construct which I think is long overdue.

Answer (score 1):

I always use 0. Not for any real thought out reason, just because when I was first learning C++ I read something that recommended using 0 and I've just always done it that way. In theory there could be a confusion issue in readability but in practice I have never once come across such an issue in thousands of man-hours and millions of lines of code. As Stroustrup says, it's really just a personal aesthetic issue until the standard becomes nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me once... I am going to redefine NULL to 69. Since then I don't use it :P

It makes your code quite vulnerable.

**Edit:**

Not everything in the standard is perfect. The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant not fully compatible with C NULL macro, what besides the type hiding implicit convert it in a useless and prone to errors tool.

NULL does not behaves as a null pointer but as a O/OL literal.

Tell me next example is not confusing:

```
void foo(char *); 
void foo(int); 
foo(NULL); // calls int version instead of pointer version!
```

Is because of all that, in the new standard appears std::nullptr_t

If you don't want to wait for the new standard and want to use a nullptr, use at least a decent one like the proposed by Meyers (see jon.h comment).

Comment: `NULL` is a well defined part of the C++ standard. Letting people who like to redefine standard macros edit code in your project makes your code 'vulnerable'; using `NULL` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Well I argue for not using 0 or NULL pointers at all whenever possible.

Using them will sooner or later lead to segmentation faults in your code. In my experience this, and pointers in gereral is one of the biggest source of bugs in C++

also, it leads to "if-not-null" statements all over your code. Much nicer if you can rely on always a valid state.

There is almost always a better alternative.

Comment: A guaranteed segmentation fault (and it _is_ guaranteed on modern systems when you dereference `0`) is _useful_ for debugging. Much better than dereferencing random garbage and getting who knows what result.

Answer (score -4):

Setting a pointer to 0 is just not that clear.  Especially if you come a language other than C++.  This includes C as well as Javascript.

I recently delt with some code like so:

`virtual void DrawTo(BITMAP *buffer) =0;`

for pure virtual function for the first time.  I thought it to be some magic jiberjash for a week.  When I realized it was just basically setting the function pointer to a `null` (as virtual functions are just function pointers in most cases for C++) I kicked myself.

`virtual void DrawTo(BITMAP *buffer) =null;`

would have been less confusing than that basterdation without proper spacing to my new eyes.  Actually, I am wondering why C++ doesn't employ lowercase `null` much like it employes lowercase false and true now.

Comment: In general I prefer NULl to 0 for pointers. 

However '= 0;' is the idiomatic way to declare a pure virtual function in C++. I would strongly advise you don't use '= NULL;' for this particular case.

Comment: This is the most funny comment on StackOverflow. You probably already know now that the example you gave is a syntax for pure virtual function and not a pointer. And yes @danio is right, you should not use NULL for pure virtual function.