# For a NULL pointer, should I use NULL or 0?

Tags: c++, pointers, null

#### Duplicate

> [Do you use NULL or 0 for pointers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c)

When dealing with `NULL` pointers one can do this

```
if(ptr != NULL){ ... }

or this

if(ptr != 0){ ... }
```

Are there reasons to prefer one over the other in `C++`?

Comment: This same question has already been answered on StackOverflow: [Do you use NULL or 0 (zero) for pointers in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 16):

Use `NULL` because it indicates *semantically* what you mean.

Remember, the point of programming isn't to tell the computer what to do.  The point is to tell *other humans* what you're telling the computer to do.

Comment: "The point is to tell other humans what you're telling the computer to do" -- lovely! but I prefer to use `0`, it's a well known C++ idiom and shouldn't confuse anyone!

Comment: NULL is meaningful only if you came to C++ from a C background.

Comment: One place NULL can get you trouble is when implementing templated code.  0 will work for values templated to be pointers, as well as other types; NULL, OTOH, can cause compile errors when the template is instantiated for non-pointers types.  (I otherwise agree with making the code communicate your intent to the human reader though)

Answer (score 6):

Either will work; so will:

`if (ptr) { ... }`

Checking explicitly for NULL demonstrates intent of the if and for that reason, I think it aides maintainability to check using:

`if (ptr != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Frank Probably because some people will disagree with the second part. Personally I find it easier to read the first version, same thing but less verbose.

Answer (score 3):

if( ptr != NULL ) reads better than if(ptr != 0).  So, while you may save 3 keystrokes with the latter, you will help your coworkers maintain their sanity while reading your code if you use the former.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't much matter.  Every professional programmer will know what `ptr = 0` and `if( !ptr )` means and it is perfectly compliant with the standard.  So, do what you will, but whatever you do, just do the same thing all the time.