# Conditionally assigning PHP values

Tags: php, ternary-operator

For the very common case of assigning a value to a variable based on the outcome of an expression I'm a fan of ternary operators:

```
$foo = $bar ? $a : b;
```

However, if $bar is a relatively expensive operation and I want to assign the result of $bar to $foo if the result is truthy, this is inefficient:

```
$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery() ? SomeClass::bigQuery() : new EmptySet();
```

One option is:

```
$foo = ($result = SomeClass::bigQuery()) ? $result : new EmptySet();
```

But I'd rather not have the extra `$result` sitting in memory.

The best option I've got is:

```
$foo = ($foo = SomeClass::bigQuery()) ? $foo : new EmptySet();
```

Or, without ternary operators:

```
if(!$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery()) $foo = new EmptySet();
```

Or, if program flow operators are not your style:

```
($foo = SomeClass::bigQuery()) || ($foo = new EmptySet());
```

So many options, non of them really satisfactory. Which would you use, and am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PHP 5.3 introduced a new syntax to solve exactly this problem:

```
$x = expensive() ?: $default;
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. 
>  Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

Comment: I personally avoid PHP 5.3-only syntax, and prefer `$x = expensive(); if (!$x) $x = $default;`

Comment: Wow; I was just going to comment with "PHP needs the [GNU extension for ternaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319075/ternary-conditional-operator-behaviour-when-leaving-one-expression-empty)"

Comment: ah ha - missed that in the manual. I assume that means there isn't a better method for 5.2.x (which I have to support in the medium term)?

Comment: @Hamish: see the other two answers ;) .  But mark this as the answer anyway, because being less than 5.3 was not specified in the question.

Comment: Too bad PHP didn't go with the Javascript/Actionscript solution: Because a value processed in a conditional is not cast to boolean unless it's combined with `&&` you can do `var x = expensive() || default;` This uses an already-familiar syntax and would benefit PHP in more than just one somewhat esoteric case.

Comment: @Renesis I agree - especially since PHP 'truthiness' testing is so loose - it is almost a bug that boolean operators cast objects to bools!

Comment: @DanyCaissy I'm late catching it, but please don't edit "man page" into "main page". That wasn't a typo, learn what [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) are.

Comment: @meagar Haha I guess you meant manual page? I hadn't seen it shortened that way in 2010 ;)

Answer (score 7):

Can you update SomeClass:bigQuery() to return a new EmptySet() instead of false?

Then you just have

```
$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery();
```

Comment: That would actually be my preference - unfortunately I'm building on top of a library that made this mistake from day-0 and now they have too much stuff hanging off the API to fix it :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery();
if (!$foo) $foo = new EmptySet();
```

Revision two, credit @meagar

Comment: It's annoyingly verbose, I personally prefer the other answers.

Comment: Realized a way to reduce verbosity.

Comment: Why not `if (!$foo) $foo = new EmptySet();`? Slightly fewer foo's.

Comment: Of course, now it's practically the same as @ontrack's answer.  Still, it's my opinion that assignments should never be in a condition.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of your last option:

<strike>$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery() or new EmptySet();</strike> this doesn't actually work, thanks for noticing.

Used often in combination with mySQL code, but seems always forgotten in comparable situations:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Although personally I prefer one you already mentioned:

```
if(!$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery())
    $foo = new EmptySet();
```

Comment: Actually, that needs to read:
`$foo = SomeClass::bigQuery() or $foo = new EmptySet();` which is equivalent to the 3rd option.