# PHP foreach doesn't select the dropdown list

Tags: php

I have a this html:

```
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
```

and my php:

```
<?php
exec('uci get sms_gateway.setting.filter',$filt);
echo '<form action='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].' method="post">
<select name="filter">';
foreach ($filt as $value){

if ($filt = "yes"){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" selected>Yes</option><br>
          <option value="no">No</option><br>ini yes';}
else {
    echo '<option value="yes">Yes</option><br>
          <option value="'.$value.'" selected>No</option><br> ini no';
}
}
echo '
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    {
        $data = $_POST['filter'];
        echo "<br>halo ". $data;
    }
    }
?>
```

the `$filt` only has one string it's either `yes` or `no`
when it's `yes` I want the yes part on the dropdown menu selected, but when it's `no` I want the `no` part on the dropdown selected. How should I do that?

Comment: Firstly, you're doing an assignment `if ($filt = "yes"){` rather than a comparison `if ($filt == "yes"){`

Comment: I tried that, but it messed up my code, the output of `no` on the dropdown list becomes `yes` while it should stay `no`

Comment: You need to pass your POST and set the variable for it, then compare.

Comment: Can you please write the code? I'm sorry I'm still learning...

Comment: `foreach ($filt as $value)` you're doing `as $value` so try `foreach ($filt as $value){

if ($value == "yes"){`

Comment: Then you have 2 sets of braces `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    {
        $data = $_POST['filter'];
        echo "<br>halo ". $data;
    }
    }` which should error out.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my answer below which you can mark as solved and also noticed a missing closing `</form>` tag, which is also in my answer; just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code:

`foreach ($filt as $value)` you're doing `as $value` so use:

```
foreach ($filt as $value){
 if ($value == "yes"){
```

Then you have 2 sets of braces which are not needed; they're just extra keystrokes for nothing:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    {
        $data = $_POST['filter'];
        echo "<br>halo ". $data;
    }
    }
```

Change it to:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $data = $_POST['filter'];
        echo "<br>halo ". $data;
    }
```

Another thing I spotted, a missing closing `</form>` tag.

---

Just for the record, you were also assigning using a single `=` sign, instead of comparing using two `==` for:

```
if ($filt = "yes")
```

which theoretically should have read as

```
if ($filt == "yes")
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

There's many things wrong with your code, you're treating "$filt" as both an array and a value, you're also assigning (=) instead of comparing. I'll give you a working example instead of trying to fix your code:

```
<?php $possibleValues = array('yes', 'no'); // All possible options ?>
<?php $valueYouWantSelected = 'yes'; // 'yes' will be selected ?>

<select>

    <?php foreach ($possibleValues as $value): ?>

        <?php $selected = ($valueYouWantSelected == $value) ? 'selected' : null; // Select this option if it equals $valueYouWantSelected ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
            <?php echo $value; ?>
        </option>

    <?php endforeach ?>

</select>
```

If you're confused about how I assign $selected, check out [ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329697/conditionally-assigning-php-values).

Also, I'm using [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), it makes it easier to organize PHP code within HTML (and colors code properly in your editor).