# How assign two value to one variable in php

Tags: codeigniter

I want to assign two values to one variable in php.I am using codeigniter and in model i need to assign two values to one variable.How i do that.
Here is code of my model.

```
public function close_bid()
{
    $status = 'Assign';


    $this->db->where('bid_status',$status);

    return $this->db->get("project_bid")->result();
}
```

I want if $status is equal to assign or $ status is equal to Complete then where condition is checked.
I am trying that but its not working:

```
$status = 'Assign' || $status = 'Complete';
```

Comment: if-else or the ternary operator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329697/conditionally-assigning-php-values

Comment: Here how i write in my code

Comment: Mr Dave Help me how i assign two values here...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the where condition to be active if status is assign or complete?

Comment: Yes i want this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign 2 values in 1 variable used array. but in your case you don't need that.

**you can do this:**

```
$this->db->where('bid_status', 'Assign');
$this->db->or_where('bid_status', 'Complete');
return $this->db->get("project_bid")->result();
```

**or this:**

```
$status = ['Assign', 'Complete'];

return $this->db->query("
         SELECT *
         FROM project_bid
         WHERE bid_status = ?
         OR bid_status = ? ", $status)->result();
```

I did not test that, but i think it will work.