# C: Ternary operator giving error when leaving one expression empty

Tags: c

I am attempting to use some code utilising a ternary statement in order to run a specific part, however, when I do this, I get the warning:

```
expression result unused
```

And the code in that particular section does not run.

The code in this case is:

```
i != a ?: printf("|%*s\\\n", i, "");
```

Why would that be? According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319075/ternary-conditional-operator-behaviour-when-leaving-one-expression-empty), this form of the ternary operator, in which there is no alternative for the case, should function, however, it simple skips over it here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why use a ternary where one part is empty?  Wouldn't this be a plain if statement?

Comment: What are you trying to do, obfuscate your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
(i != a) ? (i != a) : printf(...);
```

Note that you won't end up using the `i != a` result, hence the warning. Best to write this as an `if` statement:

```
if(i==a) printf(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there some form however of the ternary statement which is equivalent to: i != a ? printf(...) : printf(...) ?

Comment: Uh, that *is* a ternary statement.