# Objective-C: Shortcut for "id = (property) ? property : defaultObject;" - does it exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

A fairly common pattern is: if some object exists, I want to use that object in my code, but if it is not set, I want to fail over to some default value.

Using a background image as an example, and assuming some `UIImage *backgroundImage` property that may or may not be set when this code is evaluated, the verbose way to do this might be:

```
UIImage *image;
if (self.backgroundImage) {
    image = self.backgroundImage;
} else {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
}
```

A more compact method is:

```
UIImage *image = (self.backgroundImage) ? self.backgroundImage : [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

**My question is: is there an even more short-hand way to accomplish this?**

Something like:

```
UIImage *image = self.backgroundImage || [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

I can't find anything in the [Clang Literals documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), but this sort of short-hand may not actually be considered a 'Literal', or even be part of Clang for that matter.

(I'm also unsure where the "(truth statement) ? id1 : id2" syntax is documented for Clang/LLVM; knowing where the exhaustive set of those short-hand statements are would also be grand!)

Comment: Clang/LLVM does not "document" stuff that is part of standard C. Read Kernighan and Ritchie!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> UIImage *image = (self.backgroundImage) ? self.backgroundImage : [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
> ```
>
> My question is: is there an even more short-hand way to accomplish this?

Yes; just omit the middle term:

```
UIImage *image = self.backgroundImage ? : [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

Documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

And in Swift there is now the `??` operator which does just what the `?:` operator does in Objective-C.

Comment: In case it's not clear from the link: this is a gcc language extension that is also supported by clang.

Comment: Cool, I did not know about that variant of the trinomial operator. Thanks for sharing. (voted.) I gather it's not standard C however?

Comment: Unfortunately not every gcc extension is picked up by clang... @robmayoff do you know how to find out which ones are and which ones are not?

Comment: I believe it is part of C11 which is why clang supports it.

Comment: It supports [“a broad range of GCC extensions”](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not part of C11.  See [N1570](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.5.15.

Comment: @robmayoff Unfortunately clang does not support some of my favorites in that "broad range of GCC extensions" (such as [this one](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions)) - I wish they were more explicit about exactly which ones are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the most short way in this case is:

```
UIImage *image;
if (!(image = self.backgroundImage)) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

The if statement check if is `self.backgroundImage` is `nil`, and in the same time assign it to `image`. If is `nil`, assign the new object to `image`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered that there is a GNU extension to C that allows omitting the second operand of the conditional operator (ternary if):

```
UIImage *image = self.backgroundImage ?: [UIImage imageNamed:@"default"];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319144/3617012