# I do not understand the operation of inverter string

Tags: c

I'm studying two functions that invest strings the problem is that I find it hard understand how they work I see strange things in the code as, this part

```
return b = c & '\n';
```

another thing is the way you use the ternary operator

```
b + e ?: f(0);
```

the first expression is omitted I leave the two functions

```
int b, e;
void f(c)
{
    e = 13 & c;
    if(isspace(c)) return;

    b++, f(getchar());
    b--, putchar(c);
    b + e ?: f(0);
}

int f(c)
{
    static int b;
    if(isspace(c))
        return b = c & '\n';
    f(getchar());

    printf("(%c)\n", b);

    return putchar(c) == b && f(c);
}
```

someone explain to me how this goes?

Comment: is this really valid `c`?

Comment: It does not make any sense to me. Maybe someone can explain

Comment: @Wimmel Yes.  It's making deliberate use of archaisms and is written to be confusing, but it's valid C89.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319075/ternary-conditional-operator-behaviour-when-leaving-one-expression-empty explains `?:`

Comment: @zvol is `?:` really standard C89? Not just GNU extension?

Comment: @hyde Er, yes, `?:` with nothing in the middle is a GNU extension only.  The thing that looks wrong but is standard C89 is `int f(c)` with no type for `c`.  (Either C99 or C11 deleted this backward compatibility wart, I don't remember which one.)

Comment: Cheroku, why are you examining the code, where did you get it? Looks like intentionally obfuscated piece.

Answer (score 1):

Your first expression:

```
return b = c & '\n';
```

will assign the value of the expression`c & '\n'` to variable `b` and return it. 
`c & '\n'` is a bitwise operation, doing a logical AND operation on binary representations of `c` and `\n`.

To make it more illustrious, let's take the ASCII table and decode those chars:
`c` : decimal 99 -> binary 01100011
'\n' : decimal 10 -> binary 00001010

So we just `AND` them bit by bit, as a result we get `00000010`, which is decimal 2. The `b` variable is assigned that value, and the same value is returned.

```
b + e ?: f(0);
```

is a ternary conditional statement, which will first check the logical value of `b+e` and if it evaluates to `true` will do nothing (as there is nothing before `:`), otherwise will call the function `f`.

Comment: Can you explain more about the first point to this being done

Answer (score 0):

Both of these functions appear to have been deliberately written to be confusing, to the point where *I* am not 100% sure what they are supposed to do, or whether they actually do it.  So instead of explaining them, I am going to give you my own program that does what I *think* they are supposed to do, but in a less peculiar fashion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void reverse_word(void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
        return;
    if (isspace(c)) {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        return;
    }
    reverse_word();
    putchar(c);
}

void skip_whitespace(void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
        return;
    if (!isspace(c)) {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        return;
    }
    putchar(c);
}

int main(void)
{
    do {
        reverse_word();
        skip_whitespace();
    } while (!feof(stdin));
    return 0;
}
```

You will note that `reverse_word` and `skip_whitespace` are almost the same.  Ponder the differences to understand how `reverse_word` works.

```
$ echo 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' | ./a.out
eht kciuq nworb xof spmuj revo eht yzal god
```