# Assign optional return value to variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method which can return nil. If it doesn't return nil, it should replace a local variable:

```
NSString *errorMsg = error.localizedDescription;
if([self errorMsgFromErrorCode:error.code]) {
    errorMsg = [self errorMsgFomErrorCode:error.code];
}
```

Is there a smarter more compact way to do this without having to call this helper method twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`errorMsg = [self errorMsgFromErrorCode:error.code] ?: error.localizedDescription;`

Comment: love the compactness of the ternary operator

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the ternary operator worked this way when the second parameter is omitted. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319075/ternary-conditional-operator-behaviour-when-leaving-one-expression-empty

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional operator:

```
NSString *errormessage = [self errorMsgFromErrorCode:error.code] ? [self errorMsgFromErrorCode:error.code] : error.localizedDescription;
```

and in swift the shortest form is  nil coalescing operator (??)
for e.g

```
var perhapsInt: Int?
let definiteInt = perhapsInt ?? 2
print(definiteInt) // prints 2 
perhapsInt = 3
let anotherInt = perhapsInt ?? 4
print(anotherInt) // prints 3
```