# Looking for a pointer ignoring instruction when null

Tags: c++, pointers, c++03

I use a monitoring class `Progress`. In a lot of functions, I update the progress if given. The progress variable is optional and given by pointer that could be null. A lot of part of my code look like this:

```
void do_the_job(Progress* progress)
{
  do_part_1();
  if((bool)progress)
    progress->set(0.25f);
  do_part_2();
  if((bool)progress)
    progress->set(1.0f);
}
```

Before creating it myself, **I'm looking for a kind of smart pointer checking for me if it's null and ignoring the call if null.** Somthing that could be used like this:

```
void do_the_job(boost::could_be_null_ptr<Progress> progress)
{
  do_part_1();
  progress->set(0.25f); // ignored if null
  do_part_2();
  progress->set(1.0f); // ignored if null
}
```

*For compatibility reason, I don't use C++11 or >C++11. Please, only solutions working with C++03.*

Comment: There's certainly no reason to check it more than once in a function. You could just have, at the start of the function, `if (!progress) return;`. Another option might for the context in which all these functions are called to ensure that it does not pass a null, depending upon how that part of your code is designed.

Comment: can't you use  conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a safe navigation operator for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149760/is-there-a-safe-navigation-operator-for-c) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785426/c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator-equivalent-for-c or many more. Spoiler: no, this can't be done, and it can't be coded in a library either, not even in a modern version of C++.

Comment: `if((bool)progress)` is pointlessly verbose, just do `if(progress)`.

Comment: @lurker the progress is only a monitoring tool. (for example for a progress bar). If the pointer is null, the function must do the job, just ignore the update of the progress object.

Comment: Use a null object ie an instance of `Progress` that doesn't do anything. Then `do_the_job` doesn't need to check whether `progress` is null.

Comment: @underscore_d: I asked for a C++03 answer, you link to a C++17 question.

Comment: @Caduchon ...wherein they say this still isn't (as written, without unbearable verbosity) possible in C++17, so of course it wasn't possible in C++03. Do you get it yet?

Comment: In that case, you should have a look at the posted answer. It puts the responsibility on the object (struct) itself to handle the case where there is no instance rather than to put that burden on every case where you attempt to use it.

Comment: @JackHughes: it simplifies the content of the function `do_the_job` but not the call when the user doesn't use the progress (example: `do_the_job(0);` is easy to call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should not have to bother with a null pointer so design the `Progress` such that it can be used like this:

```
void do_the_job(XProgress& progress)
{
  do_part_1();
  progress.set(0.25f);
  do_part_2();
  progress.set(1.0f);
}
```

Getting there is simple:

```
struct XProgress {
   std::shared_ptr<Progress> instance;
   void set(float x) {
       if (instance) instance->set(x);
   }
};
```

In any case you need some instance on which you can call `set`, so there is no way to avoid reimplementing `Progess`s interface.

Sorry, missed the "only C++03". If you cannot use `shared_ptr` use the memory mangagment mechanism of your chioce. Perhaps a raw pointer that gets deleted in `XProgress` destructor is fine if you disable copying.