# When was the NULL macro not 0?

Tags: c, null, macros, history

I vaguely remember reading about this a couple of years ago, but I can't find any reference on the net.

Can you give me an example where the NULL macro didn't expand to 0?

Edit for clarity: Today it expands to either `((void *)0)`, `(0)`, or `(0L)`. However, there were architectures long forgotten where this wasn't true, and NULL expanded to a different address. Something like

```
#ifdef UNIVAC
     #define NULL (0xffff)
#endif
```

I'm looking for an example of such a machine.

**Update to address the issues:**

I didn't mean this question in the context of current standards, or to upset people with my incorrect terminology. However, my assumptions were confirmed by the accepted answer:

> Later models used [blah], evidently as a sop to all the extant poorly-written C code which made incorrect assumptions.

For a discussion about null pointers in the current standard, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky).

Comment: `NULL` doesn't expand to an address.  Are you truly asking when the `NULL` macro was defined to something else, or do you mean to ask when was the underlying representation of the null pointer constant not all-bits-zero?

Comment: Last I saw, it could expand to either ((void *)(3L - 2L - 1L)), (((((0) * 0x55)))), or ('\0').  (That's in C.  Some of these would not be allowed in C++.)

Comment: The answer you accepted does not answer your question, as asked. Either correct the question (if that's not what you wanted to ask), or re-accept some other answer. The details are in the comments.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The C FAQ has some examples of historical machines with non-0 NULL representations.

From [The C FAQ List](http://c-faq.com/), [question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html):

> Q: Seriously, have any actual machines really used nonzero null
>   pointers, or different representations for pointers to different
>   types?
>
> A: The Prime 50 series used segment 07777, offset 0 for the null
>   pointer, at least for PL/I. Later models used segment 0, offset 0 for
>   null pointers in C, necessitating new instructions such as TCNP (Test
>   C Null Pointer), evidently as a sop to [footnote] all the extant
>   poorly-written C code which made incorrect assumptions. Older,
>   word-addressed Prime machines were also notorious for requiring larger
>   byte pointers (`char *`'s) than word pointers (`int *`'s).
>
> The Eclipse MV series from Data General has three architecturally
>   supported pointer formats (word, byte, and bit pointers), two of which
>   are used by C compilers: byte pointers for `char *` and `void *`, and word
>   pointers for everything else. For historical reasons during the
>   evolution of the 32-bit MV line from the 16-bit Nova line, word
>   pointers and byte pointers had the offset, indirection, and ring
>   protection bits in different places in the word. Passing a mismatched
>   pointer format to a function resulted in protection faults.
>   Eventually, the MV C compiler added many compatibility options to try
>   to deal with code that had pointer type mismatch errors.
>
> Some Honeywell-Bull mainframes use the bit pattern 06000 for
>   (internal) null pointers.
>
> The CDC Cyber 180 Series has 48-bit pointers consisting of a ring,
>   segment, and offset. Most users (in ring 11) have null pointers of
>   0xB00000000000. It was common on old CDC ones-complement machines to
>   use an all-one-bits word as a special flag for all kinds of data,
>   including invalid addresses.
>
> The old HP 3000 series uses a different addressing scheme for byte
>   addresses than for word addresses; like several of the machines above
>   it therefore uses different representations for `char *` and `void *`
>   pointers than for other pointers.
>
> The Symbolics Lisp Machine, a tagged architecture, does not even have
>   conventional numeric pointers; it uses the pair `<NIL, 0>` (basically a
>   nonexistent `<object, offset>` handle) as a C null pointer.
>
> Depending on the "memory model" in use, 8086-family processors (PC
>   compatibles) may use 16-bit data pointers and 32-bit function
>   pointers, or vice versa.
>
> Some 64-bit Cray machines represent `int *` in the lower 48 bits of a
>   word; `char *` additionally uses some of the upper 16 bits to indicate a
>   byte address within a word.

Comment: +1 for finding the solid examples. FWIW, I think ISO C now mandates that 0 in the source code means null pointer no matter the underlying representation used. But that's from memory and I don't have a copy of C1x floating around at the moment.

Comment: In C source code the NULL macro would still be either an integer constant expression that evaluates to 0 or a (void *) cast of the same.  The resulting pointer value might have a representation that isn't 0 but that doesn't mean the source code can assume it will be 0xffff or anything like that.

Comment: @Windows Programmer: true now that the C standard mandates that NULL is a null pointer constant (as opposed to just any constant equal to a null pointer). All of those machines predate the standard, though, so it's certainly possible that one of them did `#define NULL ((void*)-1)`, or `#define NULL __nullpointer`, where __nullpointer is a compiler built-in, or whatever. They're the right places to be looking for such a thing.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Can you point any text in the standard that rules out `#define NULL __builtin_compiler_magic_nil_pointer`?

Comment: See my other comment. I'm not sure, though, I might take back part of what I said. `__builtin_compiler_magic_nil_pointer` might be all right, provided that the implementation defines (as an extension) that `__builtin_compiler_magic_nil_pointer` is an integral constant expression with value 0, or that it behaves like one in every possible way. g++ in fact does #define NULL to `__null`, but gcc (in C mode) doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is completely bogus. The examples given in C FAQ are the examples of machines with non-zero *null-pointer values*. The question was about non-zero `NULL`, i.e. about a non-zero *null-pointer constant*. Null-pointer value and null-pointer constant are two completely different things. The answer mistakes one for another, which is a rather widespread mistake (a newbie mistake, should I add).

Comment: The question was about what `NULL` expands to. This answer has absolutely nothing to do with what `NULL` expands to. Yet, the autor of the question says "Exactly what I was looking for" (???). Apparently the author is confused (misunderstands the difference between NPC and NPV, as I said above).

Comment: Steve Jessop, read the first edition of K&R or read some older technical reports from Bell Labs.  Go back far enough and there's no void or void*, but still an integral constant 0 in source code when converted to a pointer at compile time would have to convert to a null pointer no matter what its bit representation was.  #define NULL ((char*)-1) would not have been acceptable.

Comment: @Windows programmer: Are you sure K&R had the concept of type-specific null-pointer value, as opposed to simply converting integral `0` to pointer to address `0x0`?

Comment: What the FAQ says about the Cyber-180 is true.  The internal representation of null pointers was not all 0 bits. But the C compiler I worked on certainly ensured that `NULL==0` was true.  I don't recall exactly how the `NULL`  macro was defined in the `.h` files, but it would have been either `0` or `((char*)0)`. (This was just before ANSI-C, so there was no void* at the time.)

Answer (score 6):

There was a time long ago when it was typed as `((void*)0)` or some other machine-specific manner, where that machine didn't use the all-zero bit pattern.

Some platforms (certain CDC or Honeywell machines) had a different bit pattern for NULL (ie, *not* all zeros) although ISO/ANSI fixed that before C90 was ratified, by specifying that `0` was the correct NULL pointer in the source code, *regardless* of the underlying bit pattern. From `C11 6.3.2.3 Pointers /4` (though, as mentioned, this wording goes all the way back to C90):

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 4):

In C compilers, it can expand to '`((void *)0)`' (but does not have to do so).  This does not work for C++ compilers.

See also the C FAQ which has a whole chapter on [null pointers](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

In the GNU libio.h file:

```
#ifndef NULL
# if defined __GNUG__ && \
(__GNUC__ > 2 || (__GNUC__ == 2 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 8))
#  define NULL (__null)
# else
#  if !defined(__cplusplus)
#   define NULL ((void*)0)
#  else
#   define NULL (0)
#  endif
# endif
#endif
```

Note the conditional compilation on __cplusplus.  C++ can't use ((void*) 0) because of its stricter rules about pointer casting; the standard requires NULL to be 0.  C allows other definitions of NULL.

Answer (score 3):

C compilers usually use `((void *)0)`. The reason is passing `NULL` to functions with variable arguments (or now rare but still legal functions without prototype). When pointers are larger than int, `0` will only be promoted to `int` and will thus not read correctly as pointer.

C++ compilers can't use that definition because C++ does not permit implicit cast from `void *` (casting `0` to any pointer is special-cased). However C++11 introduced new keyword `nullptr` that is a null pointer constant of special `nullptr_t` type implicitly convertible to any pointer type, but not number. This solves both the variadic argument problem and the implicit cast and additionally more severe problems with overload selection (`0` for obvious reason selects `int` overload over pointer one). It is legal to define these yourself for older compilers and some C++ compilers tried that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` macro in C expands to implementation defined null-pointer constant. It can be anything (since it is implementation-defined), but in pointer context the effect is always the same as if it expanded to constant `0`.

There has never been a time in standard C history when `NULL` expanded to something specifically not `0`, unless you consider `(void *) 0` as "not 0". But `(void *) 0` for `NULL` is widely used to this day.

Comment: There has never been a time in _ISO_ C history ... early compilers had different bit patterns long before the 0 was codified as NULL regardless of the underlying bits. Although, given my advancing years, there's no way I could remember which ones they were :-)

Comment: Chapter and verse please?  The ISO C standard explicitly says that NULL can expand to whatever the implementation wants it to expand to.  `4.1.5. Common Definitions <stddef.h> [...] The macros are NULL which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and [...] `.  This should not be confused with other text that says that the expression 0 converted to pointer type is always a valid way to get a null pointer constant.  Which has nothing to do what what NULL expands to.

Comment: @janks, I think @paxdiablo is saying that in ISO C, `0` in pointer contexts is the null pointer constant, but in pre-ISO (pre-ANSI) C, this wasn't necessarily true.  Presumably in those variants one would write `NULL`, or whatever magic number the null pointer happened to be.

Comment: @Alok, yeah, that's exactly what his first paragraph said.  But then he contradicted it by saying that "there has never been a time in C history when NULL expanded to something specifically not 0", which is rubbish.  The standard doesn't require it to, and he would have to have used every implementation of C ever, without exceptions, to prove the negative.  We once believed there were no black swans because we'd only seen white ones.

Comment: @janks: elsewhere in the C standard, a "null pointer constant" is defined to be either an ICE with value 0, or else one of those cast to `(void*)`. That's not "whatever the compiler wants", and I think AndreyT is right to say that any such thing is "specifically 0". The standard forbids `#define NULL ((void*)0xFFFF)`, even if 0xFFFF converts to a null pointer on that implementation. I think it's probably wrong to ignore pre-standard C, since the question is clearly about ages past, but the standard does forbid black swans.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Can you cite the text from the standard that you feel forbids `#define NULL ((void*)0xFFFF)`? The "as-if" rule says that an implementation can do whatever it pleases so long as the observable side-effects of your program match those of the abstract machine.  While it would be pretty stupid, I can't see any reason why the implementation cannot define NULL in a strange way, and then "fix-up" any context where NULL is used such that it respects the semantics of the abstract machine.

Comment: @janks: In n1256, the text defining a null pointer constant is 6.3.2.3/3. The text which says NULL is a #define to a null pointer constant is 7.17/3. The program which would fail the as-if rule if NULL were #defined to `((void*)0xFFFF)` is one which stringifies NULL and prints it out, for example `#define SSTRING(A) #A #define STRING(A) SSTRING(A) int main() {const char *ptr = STRING(NULL); printf("%s\n", ptr); }`. Plus some linebreaks.

Comment: Yes, the stringize argument is clever, it's the only thing that I can see that could arguably forbid a strange definition of NULL.  Unless perhaps the implementation could detect when you're trying to stringize NULL, and substitute some magic.  But I personally don't believe that 4.1.5 combined with 3.2.2.3 are sufficient to rule out a strange definition of NULL.  I read 4.1.5 as saying "ICE 0 and ICE 0 cast to void* must be legal forms of the null pointer constant", not that they are the only legal forms of the null pointer constant.  I didn't write the standard though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I think when the standard says, " such-and-such is called *foo* ", it means to define "foo", not just to give examples of "foo".

Comment: What I meant to say is that since the moment `NULL` appeared as a specified part of the language, `0` was a valid way to define `NULL`. I.e. there never was a time `NULL` was *requred* to be defined as something non-zero. It could be defined to something platform specific (anything), but `0` was always required to work just as well. (Again: since the moment `NULL` was introduced. CRM C, for example, makes no mention of `NULL`.)

Answer (score 1):

In modern C, `void *pointer = 0;` is meant to initialize "pointer" to not point at anything. It is platform-specific as to whether that is accomplished by setting the bits of "pointer" to all-zero.

In the past, this formal meaning of "0" in a pointer context was not established. It was necessary to set the pointer to the actual value that the platform treated as "doesn't point anywhere". As an example, a platform might choose some fixed address that never gets a page mapped to it. In this case, in an old compiler, the platform might have defined `NULL` as:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0xFFFFF000)
```

Of course, today, there's no reason not to define it as `((void*)0)`.

Comment: 'In the past, this formal meaning of "0" in a pointer context was not established.' -- right, where 'In the past' means 'Before the invention of the C language'.

Comment: @Windows: no, that's not the case. It was not established as of K&R C, first edition. `void *ptr=0;` did not have a defined meaning.

Comment: To the best of my recollection that is correct, there was no "void" or "void *" as of K&R C, first edition.  However, the formal meaning of "0" in a pointer context was established at the beginning of C in 1970.

Comment: [K&R1](https://ia801303.us.archive.org/1/items/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20[UA-07].pdf) page 97: "C guarantees that no pointer that validly points at data will contain zero, so a return value of zero can be used to signal an abnormal event, in this case, no space. We write `NULL` instead of zero, however, to indicate more clearly that this is a special value for a pointer. In general, integers cannot meaningfully be assigned to pointers; zero is a special case." See also chapter 5.6 "Pointers are not Integers."