# Redefining NULL

Tags: c, null

I'm writing C code for a system where address 0x0000 is valid and contains port I/O. Therefore, any possible bugs that access a NULL pointer will remain undetected and at the same time cause dangerous behaviour.

For this reason I wish to redefine NULL to be another address, to for example an address that isn't valid. If I accidentally access such an address I will get a hardware interrupt where I can handle the error. I happen to have access to stddef.h for this compiler, so I can actually alter the standard header and redefine NULL.

My question is: will this conflict with the C standard? As far as I can tell from 7.17 in the standard, the macro is implementation-defined. Is there anything elsewhere in the standard stating that NULL *must* be 0?

Another issue is that plenty of compilers perform static initialization by setting everything to zero, no matter the data type. Even though the standard says that the compiler should set integers to zero and pointers to NULL. If I would redefine NULL for my compiler, then I know that such static initialization will fail. Could I regard that as incorrect compiler behaviour even though I boldly altered compiler headers manually? Because I know for certain that this particular compiler does not access the NULL macro when doing static initialization.

Comment: This is a really good question.  I don't have an answer for you, but I have to ask: are you sure it's not possible to move your valid stuff at 0x00 away and let NULL be an invalid address like in "normal" systems?  If you can't, then the only safely invalid addresses to use would be ones you can be **sure** you can allocate and then `mprotect` to secure.  Or, if the platform has no ASLR or the like, addresses beyond the platform physical memory.  Good luck.

Comment: How will it work if your code is using `if(ptr) { /* do something on ptr*/ }` ? Will it work if NULL is defined different from 0x0 ?

Comment: See this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky

Comment: @Borealid Well... in theory I can move the contents from there, but the CPU manufacturer (Freescale) has made a heavy hardware optimization on all registers in address space 0-255. This is known as "zero page", and all registers residing within this address space will have much faster access time. If I move the whole register map upwards, I will mess up this hardware optimization.

Comment: @Xavier Luckily, all code for this system will be MISRA-C compliant, so I won't have that problem. MISRA-C bans the usage of non-boolean expressions inside if-statements. MISRA-C compliant code must be written as if(ptr!=NULL).

Comment: Are these legal in MISRA-C? `x = !ptr;` `y = ptr && 1;`

Comment: C pointer have no forced relation to memory addresses. As long as the rules of pointer arithmetic are complied with, a pointers value may be anything. Most implementations choose to use the memory addresses as pointer values, but they could use anything as long it's a isomorphism.

Comment: @bdonlan That would violate (advisory) rules in MISRA-C as well.

Comment: Shoot the person who had the great idea of making 0 a valid memory address?

Comment: @Andreas Yep that's my thoughts too. Hardware people shouldn't be allowed to design hardware that software should run in! :)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The C standard does not require null pointers to be at the machine's address zero. HOWEVER, casting a `0` constant to a pointer value must result in a `NULL` pointer (§6.3.2.3/3), and evaluating the null pointer as a boolean must be false. This can be a bit awkward if you really *do* want a zero address, and `NULL` is not the zero address.

Nevertheless, with (heavy) modifications to the compiler and standard library, it's not impossible to have `NULL` be represented with an alternate bit pattern while still remaining strictly conformant to the standard library. It is *not* sufficient to simply change the definition of `NULL` itself however, as then `NULL` would evaluate to true.

Specifically, you would need to:

- Arrange for literal zeros in assignments to pointers (or casts to pointers) to be converted into some other magic value such as `-1`.
- Arrange for equality tests between pointers and a constant integer `0` to check for the magic value instead (§6.5.9/6)
- Arrange for all contexts in which a pointer type is evaluated as a boolean to check for equality to the magic value instead of checking for zero. This follows from the equality testing semantics, but the compiler may implement it differently internally. See §6.5.13/3, §6.5.14/3, §6.5.15/4, §6.5.3.3/5, §6.8.4.1/2, §6.8.5/4
- As caf pointed out, update the semantics for initialization of static objects (§6.7.8/10) and partial compound initializers (§6.7.8/21) to reflect the new null pointer representation.
- Create an alternate way to access true address zero.

There are some things you do *not* have to handle. For example:

```
int x = 0;
void *p = (void*)x;
```

After this, `p` is NOT guaranteed to be a null pointer. Only constant assignments need be handled (this is a good approach for accessing true address zero). Likewise:

```
int x = 0;
assert(x == (void*)0); // CAN BE FALSE
```

Also:

```
void *p = NULL;
int x = (int)p;
```

`x` is not guaranteed to be `0`.

In short, this very condition was apparently considered by the C language committee, and considerations made for those who would choose an alternate representation for NULL. All you have to do now is make major changes to your compiler, and hey presto you're done :)

As a side note, it may be possible to implement these changes with a source code transformation stage before the compiler proper. That is, instead of the normal flow of preprocessor -> compiler -> assembler -> linker, you'd add a preprocessor -> NULL transformation -> compiler -> assembler -> linker. Then you could do transformations like:

```
p = 0;
if (p) { ... }
/* becomes */
p = (void*)-1;
if ((void*)(p) != (void*)(-1)) { ... }
```

This would require a full C parser, as well as a type parser and analysis of typedefs and variable declarations to determine which identifiers correspond to pointers. However, by doing this you could avoid having to make changes to the code generation portions of the compiler proper. [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) may be useful for implementing this - I understand it was designed with transformations like this in mind. You would still likely need to make changes to the standard library as well of course.

Comment: Ok I had not found the text in §6.3.2.3, but I suspected there would be such a statement *somewhere* :). I guess this answers my question, by the standard I'm not allowed to re-define NULL unless I fancy writing a new C compiler to back me up :)

Comment: A good trick is to hack the compiler so that pointer<->integer conversions XOR a specific value that is an invalid pointer and still trivial enough that the target architecture can do that cheaply (usually, that would be a value with a single bit set, such as 0x20000000).

Comment: Another thing you would need to change in the compiler is the initialisation of objects with compound type - if an object is partially initialised, then any pointers for which an explicit initaliser isn't present must be initialised to `NULL`.

Answer (score 20):

The standard states that an integer constant expression with value 0, or such an expression converted to the `void *` type, is a null pointer constant.  This means that `(void *)0` is always a null pointer, but given `int i = 0;`, `(void *)i` need not be.

The C implementation consists of the compiler together with its headers.  If you modify the headers to redefine `NULL`, but don't modify the compiler to fix static initialisations, then you have created a non-conforming implementation.  It is the entire implementation taken together that has incorrect behaviour, and if you broke it, you really have no-one else to blame ;)

You must fix more than just static initialisations, of course - given a pointer `p`, `if (p)` is equivalent to `if (p != NULL)`, due to the above rule.

Answer (score 7):

If you use the C std library, you'll run into problems with functions that can return NULL. For example the [malloc documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) states:

> If the function failed to allocate the
>   requested block of memory, a null
>   pointer is returned.

Because malloc and related functions are already compiled into binaries with a specific NULL value, if you redefine NULL, you won't be able to directly use the C std library unless you can rebuild your entire tool chain, including the C std libs.

Also because of the std library's use of NULL, if you redefine NULL before including std headers, you might overwrite a NULL define listed in the headers. Anything inlined would be inconsistent from the compiled objects.

I would instead define your own NULL, "MYPRODUCT_NULL", for your own uses and either avoid or translate from/to the C std library.

Answer (score 6):

Leave NULL alone and treat IO to port 0x0000 as a special case, maybe using a routine written in assembler, and thus not subject to standard C semantics. IOW, don't redefine NULL, redefine port 0x00000.

Note that if you're writing or modifying a C compiler, the work required to avoid dereferencing NULL (assuming that in your case the CPU isn't helping) is the same no matter how NULL is defined, so it's easier to leave NULL defined as zero, and make sure that zero can't ever be dereferenced from C.

Comment: The problem will only arise when NULL is accidentally accessed, not when the port is intentionally accessed. Why would I redefine port I/O for then? It is already working as it should.

Comment: @Lundin Accidentally or not, NULL can **only** be dereferenced in a C program using `*p`, `p[]` or `p()`, so the compiler only needs to care about those to protect IO port 0x0000.

Comment: @Lundin The second part of your question: Once you restrict access to address zero from within C, you need another way to reach port 0x0000. A function written in assembler can do that. From within C, the port could be mapped to 0xFFFF or whatever, but it's best to use a function and forget about the port number.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the extreme difficulty in redefining NULL as mentioned by others, maybe its easier to **redefine dereferencing** for well-known hardware addresses. When creating an address, add 1 to every well-known address, so that your well-known IO port would be:

```
  #define CREATE_HW_ADDR(x)(x+1)
  #define DEREFERENCE_HW_ADDR(x)(*(x-1))

  int* wellKnownIoPort = CREATE_HW_ADDR(0x00000000);

  printf("IoPortIs" DEREFERENCE_HW_ADDR(wellKnownIoPort));
```

If the addresses you're concerned with are grouped together and you can feel safe that adding 1 to the address won't conflict with anything (which it shouldn't in most cases), you might be able to do this safely. And then you don't need to worry about rebuilding your tool chain/std lib and expressions in the form:

```
  if (pointer)
  {
     ...
  }
```

still work

Crazy I know, but just thought I'd throw the idea out there :).

Comment: The problem will only arise when NULL is accidentally accessed, not when the port is intentionally accessed. Why would I redefine port I/O for then? It is already working as it should.

Comment: @LundIn I guess you have to choose which is more painful, tweaking rebuilding the whole toolchain or changing this one part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The bit pattern for the null pointer may not be the same as the bit pattern for the integer 0.  But the expansion of the NULL macro must be a null pointer constant, that is a constant integer of value 0 which may be casted to (void*).

To achieve the result you want while staying conformant, you'll have to modify (or perhaps configurate) your tool chain, but it is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for trouble.  Redefining `NULL` to a non-null value will break this code:

```
   if (myPointer)
   {
      // myPointer is not null
      ...
   }
```