# How to zero an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am allocating memory for a pointer array. The result has a fixed number of items and I want all of them initialised to `NULL`.

```
char **result = (char **)calloc(12, sizeof(char *));
```

Can I now be sure that elements `result[0]` to `result[11]` are `NULL`?

Comment: You may find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251499/calloc-pointers-and-all-bits-zero

Comment: And [this excerpt from the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) as well.

Comment: And, the rule [not to cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/296974) holds for `calloc()` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `0`-ing out a pointer `p`'s value  by doing

```
memset(p, 0, sizeof(p));
```

not necessary needs to be equal to doing

```
p = NULL;
```

on each and every platform, you'd be on the safe side doing:

```
SomeType ** result = malloc(12 * sizeof(*result));
if (NULL != result)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
  {
    result[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

You could wrap this in a macro like so:

```
#define ALLOCARRAY(result, size) \
  do { \
    result = malloc(size * sizeof(*result)); \
    if (NULL != result) \
    { \
      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) \
      { \
        result[i] = NULL; \
      } \
    } \
  } while (0)
```

Then use the macro like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

[...]

SomeType ** result = NULL;
ALLOCARRAY(result, 12);
if (NULL == result)
{
  /* Handle error here. */
}
else 
{
  /* Use array here. */

  /* Free array. */
  free(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`calloc()` sets the allocated space to all bits-zero, but a null pointer may not be bits-zero in some implementations. For a portable solution, you still need to set them to a null pointer manually.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    result[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `s/many/some/`. I don't think there are many implementations out there which act this way, just a handful.

Comment: @glglgl Done. Perhaps most time I heard examples for this issue, I focused on the exceptions :).

Comment: @glglgl You beat me to the comment! Other than the old 8086 memory models where the effective pointer value was the offset sum of a non-zero segment and a zero offset, I've never seen non-zero null pointers. What others are there?  Embedded systems?

Comment: As I commented below the answer, the [C FAQ mentions](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) some of these. Mostly historical things...

Comment: @glglgl I'd be unable to name even one. I'll need to read some of those links.

Comment: @MarkRansom Me as well. It is interesting to have read about this phaenomenon and to take care, but otherwise I'm not affected by this.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is, IMO, a bit overblown. Yes, it is absolutely true that some machines, somewhere, do not use the all-bits-zero pattern for null, just like there are machines that have (or had, historically,) oddball byte sizes of 9 or 11 bits for example.) And knowing that is occasionally useful in winning a free beer from another programmer who doesn't know that, but not much beyond that. (It is, of course, vitally useful to those who write the C standards or compilers.)

I'm willing to be that several of the readers/commenters in this thread *have* worked on, or run across machines like that; but you have to understand that the stackoverflow-answering population at large is somewhat skewed towards the guru-types who have seen and done it all. (I don't count myself in that group, by the way..) The vast majority of 'normal' C programmers in the world (who are writing C code to run under a common Windows/Mac/Linux/Unix/(**) platform, or writing embedded code to run on just about any of the common embedded architecture platforms out there) will never in their lifetimes work on a system where calloc doesn't give you *effectively* NULL pointers, and darned few will work on a machine where an unsigned char is not 8 bits wide -- and the odds are nearly as good that their code will never get ported to one of those systems.

So, while I wholeheartedly agree that it's a good thing to understand technical nuances of the standards -- knowing more never hurts -- I think you also have to apply some common sense in deciding which kinds of portability your code needs to worry about. Unless you actually have access to a machine with a weird byte size, or a non-zero-bit null pointer, you won't actually be able to test the portability of your code (let alone any libraries you depend on,) across those conditions, and unless you *know* you are writing code that needs to be that widely portable, your mental energy is better spent on finding and fixing more prosaic bugs in your system.

(**) Do I still need to mention VMS in this list or get pounced upon by zealots? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is explicitly stated in non-normative footnote 296 of the C 2011 standard: “Note that this [calloc’s initialization of all bits to zero] need not be the same as the representation of floating-point zero or a null pointer constant.”