# What's the best way for checking if any value is NULL or empty?

Tags: c, if-statement, null

I was wondering what was the best (I mean performance and proper) of checking an empty value ?

I know these 2 ways :

First (I think the best) :

For any pointer check:

```
if (value == NULL) ...
```

For an `int`:

```
if (value == 0) ...
```

---

Second:

```
if (value) ...
```

Comment: Do you want to check for _empty string_ also?

Comment: `value` is a very bad name for a pointer.

Comment: @DrKoch : char* is the same so yes ?

Comment: @Lundin : I never named pointer "value" don't worry ^^

Comment: A check fo **no string** OR **empty string** with `char *str;` would be: `if(str == null || str[0] == '\0')`

Comment: @DrKoch: Just for completeness, there is a typo in your comment, as there is no `null`, so I am sure you meant `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For an Int : if (value == 0)
```

For `int` if the value is `0`. it doesn't mean that the parameter is empty, it means that the parameter is holding the value `0`.

Performance-wise, there is no difference. You can check this by inspecting the compiled assembly code.

The assembly code is given below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;

    if(a==0)
            printf("hello");

}

main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jne     .L3
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
```

And for this one,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;

    if(a)
            printf("hello");
}

main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    je      .L3
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
```

You can see that both the codes are same, thus there is no difference performance-wise.

But, as others mentioned, the `FIRST` one is easier to understand and is more clear. That should be used

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, but I find the first one too verbose for a pointer. My reaction in a code review would be to say "you don't need to do this". For the `int`, I agree that is is good to be explicit, because we are comparing against a particular value, since there is no concept of null for an int.

Comment: @haris : Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `if(value == NULL)` since it is the most clear and unambiguous form.

`if(value == 0)` or `if(!value)` are common variants, but they are slightly less clear, as you can't tell if the intention was to check a pointer or a variable's value.

There is no performance difference between the 3 above forms and they will yield exactly the same machine code.

---

Stylistic details:

Stylistically, it is preferred to always treat `if` statements as if they expect a boolean type (like in C++). Unfortunately C still uses int, rather than a true boolean type, so there exist no type safety between integers and boolean expressions.

But you can write code as if there was a true boolean type, because then you can use external static analysers in order to get a stronger typing for boolean expressions. MISRA-C for example uses a term "essentially boolean" to enforce this.

It is a rather nice and effective way of weeding out obscure expressions and type-related bugs.

In such code `if(value)` or `if(!value)` wouldn't be allowed, because value in this example is a pointer, not a bool.

Sources: MISRA-C:2012 rules 10.1, 11.9, 14.4

Comment: Thank you for these details!

Comment: I don't agree about the ambiguity, the NULL macro is not guaranteed to be zero. Also, null pointer constant is always the literal 0 (in the source code, though may be translated to something else in machine code).

Comment: @Veriloud Not correct. The NULL macro is guaranteed to expand to a null pointer constant, which in turn is guaranteed to be either `0` or `(void*)0`. You are probably confusing the NULL macro with _null pointers_, which may be different from zero. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136092/how-to-write-c-c-code-correctly-when-null-pointer-is-not-all-bits-zero).

Comment: @Lundin, when you say "guaranteed to expand to a null pointer constant", yes,  the preprocessor will expand it to what the language already has direct support for representing a null pointer constant: a literal 0.   I meant this is an issue of style as you say, but one could argue that simply using 0 in the first place is less ambiguous.  Especially to those working on a machine that use nonzero null pointers.  The goal of both styles is the same, to remind us pointers are an abstraction.

Comment: @Lundin, your answer is best, +1, and thanks for the excellent link in your comment reply.  Note in the last sentence its preferred answer: "The standard says: A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;  So if (p==NULL) and if (!p) does the same thing."  That is another reason why some argue if (!p) is more natural to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "First" because it is easier to understand, maintain, ...

There is no noticeable difference performancewise.

Comment: There shouldn't be *any* performance difference (noticeable or otherwise).

Comment: @DrKoch I very much doubt you'll find any such compiler out there.

Answer (score 1):

Both will perform the same, and will most likely produce the exact same assembly code. Use whatever you see fit.

It's a good idea to consider how your code will be interpreted by other coders. From a readability standpoint `if (value == NULL)` may seem more clear than `if (!value)`. But it's a matter of style.