# Principle of different operand types adoption for ternary operator in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, null, ternary-operator

There are many kinds of typecasting to make sure assignment works such as implicit type conversion (promotion) and explicit type conversion (truncation), but I am not sure how it works on pointers type conversion for ternary operator.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    (void)((rand() ? (char*)NULL :        NULL) + 1);
    /*     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        -> expression A */

    /* GCC Warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic */
    (void)((rand() ? (char*)NULL : (void*)NULL) + 1);
    /*     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        -> expression B */

    return 0;
}
```

Apparently, the compiler regards expression A as type of `char*` but B as type of `void*`.

I have two questions:

- I've checked the preprocessed code, and `NULL` is exactly expanded to `((void*)0)`, so why are `((void*)0)` and `(void*)((void*)0)` different types?
- According to the expression B, why the compiler cast type of `char*` to type of `void*` but not vise versa?

Comment: A good answer needs, in my opinion a standard reference, but what's going on here is an implicit conversion of NULL to (char*)NULL in the first case, and an implicit conversion of (char*)NULL to (void*)NULL in the second case. Nice question though, plus one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applies:

> 6.5.15 Conditional operator
>
> The first operand shall have scalar type.
>   One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
>
> /--/
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
>   compatible types;
>   — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null
>   pointer constant; or
>   — one operand is a pointer to an object type and
>   the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void.

In the first case you have one operand `(char*)NULL` which is an (unqualified) pointer to type, and one operand `NULL` which is a null pointer constant.

Further down in §6 it says:

> If both the second and third operands are pointers or one is a null
>   pointer constant and the other is a pointer, the result type is a
>   pointer to a type qualified with all the type qualifiers of the types
>   referenced by both operands

In plain English: if one operand is of type `char*` and the other is a null pointer constant, the result is `char*`.

In the second case you have one pointer to type and one `void*`. Neither is a null pointer constant (I'll explain why further below). Further down in the same paragraph it says (emphasis mine):

> ... if one operand is a
>   null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand; **otherwise, one operand
>   is a pointer to void or a qualified version of void, in which case the result type is a
>   pointer to an appropriately qualified version of void.**

Meaning that the result of the second `?:` operation is of type `void*`. This should answer your second question.

---

To answer you first question, it has nothing to do with the `?:` operator as such, but is about the "ancient C mystery" of null pointer versus null pointer constants.

How the macro NULL is expanded is implementation-defined, it is either `0` or `(void*)`. It is guaranteed to be a null pointer constant.

[There is a difference between a *null pointer* and a *null pointer constant*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136092/how-to-write-c-c-code-correctly-when-null-pointer-is-not-all-bits-zero/32136460#32136460), namely that a null pointer may have any implementation-defined value, while a null pointer constant is always `0` or `(void*)0`.

6.3.2.2 says:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

So `(void*)NULL` is a null pointer, but it is not a null pointer constant. Therefore the conditional operator treats it as a void pointer.

To sum it up: null pointers are not a special case for the conditional operator, only null pointer constants are.

Comment: +one It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I will try an explanation:

`0` or `(void*)0` is a null pointer constant, which is appropriately handled by the ternary conditional operator:

> if one operand is a **null pointer constant**, the result has the type
>   of the other operand; (6.5.15 6)

but `(void*)((void *)0)` is a null pointer, but not the null pointer constant (`NULL`):

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *,is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function. (6.3.2.3 3)

Hence now, this paragraph applies:

> otherwise, one operand is a pointer to void or a qualified version of
>   void, in which case the result type is a pointer to an appropriately
>   qualified version of void.  (6.5.15 6)