# C - Why must NULL be compared to?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm curious as to why when say I traverse a linked list iteratively I must do `while (list != NULL)` instead of `while (!list)`. I thought NULL equated to zero or false.

From comments: My program seems to always crash when I attempt a `while (!list)` but never the former. Each node contains a void pointer to a piece of data and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: you'll get the same result from both of them

Comment: a matter of style. the first is more clear to the reader.

Comment: @nos my program seems to always crash when I attempt `!NULL`. It is a valid list where each node contains a void pointer to a piece of data and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: @nos All I'm doing is traversing the linked list. Each time doing `list = list -> next`. I'm so out of ideas then... especially because it works with one but not the other.

Comment: [NULL is **not** zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2597142/995714). `!NULL` is 1 so you are almost always receive segfault because 1 is not a valid address on most systems

Comment: @Pooya Disagree with "you'll get the same result from both of them"  `list != NULL` is not the same as `!list`.

Comment: @David Haim "..."a matter of style." --> `while (list != NULL)` and `while (!list)` has a different style and more importantly a different functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while (list != NULL)` is not the same as `while (!list)`. They are opposites! Of course your program crashes, it tries to de-reference a `NULL` pointer.

`while (list != NULL)` is the same as `while (list)`.

Comment: When you spend days in a dungeon trying to get the same function working you start to forget basic things. I hope this helps future comrades undertaking the same course I am. Thanks.

Comment: Impressed that OP, 2 commenters and 3 up-votes to those comments all missed that the 2 code fragments had opposite functionality.  (Maybe would have missed it myself had I not read this answer first.) Suggest that it was brought on by the confusion of comparing two  statements with `!` in them.  IMHO using `while (list)` is best.  Or using `while (list == NULL)` when code needs to do the opposite.  Both do not use `!`.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it's matter of style. Comparison to `NULL` is more explicit.

As mentioned above, `if(ptr != NULL)` is equivalent to `if(ptr)`.

Comment: This is not correct. You are mixing up the NULL macro with null pointers. NULL is _always_ `0` or `(void*)0`. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136092/how-to-write-c-c-code-correctly-when-null-pointer-is-not-all-bits-zero/32136460#32136460).

Comment: @Lundin I did some googling. Yes, that was a gap in my knowledge. I'll remove this part.

Comment: @Lundin Certainty `NULL` macro could be `0` or `(void*)0`.  Yet the C spec does not defined it as only those two.  Others are possible including `((void*)0)`, `(-0)`, `((intptr_t) 0)`.

Comment: @chux My bad, for some reason I thought you had written `(intptr_t*)`. You are right, I'll delete the comment.