# Why can void pointers be subtracted but not added?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Why does

```c
printf("%ld\n", (void *)0 - (void *)0);
```

compile, but

```c
printf("%ld\n", (void *)0 + (void *)0);
```

does not?

Comment: What would a sum of pointers mean?

Comment: [Checkthis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615981/c-what-type-is-the-difference-of-two-void-pointers#:~:text=Subtraction%20of%20pointers%20is%20only,an%20array%20with%20void%20elements.)

Comment: You can add an integer to a pointer. However, pointer arithmetic on `void *` is a GNU C extension that is not part of the C standard. The C standard only supports pointer arithmetic on pointers to *complete* object types, and `void` is an *incomplete* object type by definition.

Comment: @bereal Treat them as numbers, and add them.

Comment: As bereal said: `What would a sum of pointers mean?`  Specifically: 1) an "address" is the sum of a pointer and an offset. 2) An "offset" is computed by subtracting pointers. 3) "Adding" two pointers, however ... is nonsense.

Comment: @FredLarson I would expect that `(void *)p + NULL` would yield `(void *)p`, at the very least.

Comment: _Treat them as numbers_ What does this mean?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In the same way that `(int)1 + (int)2` =  `(int)3`, `(void *)1 + (void *)2` should yield `(void *)3`.

Comment: What if a pointer was not obtained by `(void*)#number`?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Why should other pointers be different? I mean, `p + (void *)1` should be equivalent to `p + 1` and `p + q` should be equivalent to `p + (size_t)q`.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick *`p + (void *)1` should be equivalent to `p + 1` and `p + q` should be equivalent to `p + (size_t)q`.*  Huh?  **Why** "should" they be equivalent to that?  An address plus an address is nonsense.  An address is **where something is**.  How do you even represent the arithmetic addition of two **locations**?  "When we add 123 Main St to 43 Third St, where are you?"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fair enough, but shouldn't `NULL` at least coerce to a `ptrdiff_t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful to find the difference between two pointers. This gives an integer (a `ptrdiff_t`).<sup>[1]</sup>

It is useful to add a difference to a pointer, so we can add an integer to a pointer (and vice-versa). The inverse operation of `ptrdiff = p2 - p1` is `p2 = p1 + ptrdiff`.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, there's no sensible meaning to adding two pointers together. So that's not allowed.

---

1. Note that this is undefined behaviour for `void *` pointers, and for pointers that aren't to parts of the same object.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this expression

```
(void *)0 - (void *)0
```

has undefined behavior because according to the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 3 For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
>
> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
> compatible **complete object types**;

The type `void` is an incomplete type.

You could write for example

```
(char *)0 - (char *)0
```

Some compilers for backward compatibility have their language extensions that allow such an operation for pointers of the type `cv void *`.

As for the operator `+` then it is just not defined for pointers. For this operator applied to pointers this shall be satisfied

> 2 For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or
> **one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type**.

Applying the operator + for pointers does not make a sense.