# NULL undeclared identifier

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

There are several questions and aswers about this question on this site. I tried the answers (including header-files) given, they don't solve my problem.

I migrated my project from VS2013 to VS2015. After compiling i'm getting the error : "C2065 'NULL': undeclared identifier". This didn't happen in VS2013. When I go to my code and 'hover' over "NULL", a window is shown "#define NULL 0". I can right-click on NULL and open "peek definition". The file vcruntime.h is opened and it shows the definition of NULL. (This file is marked as read-only.)

Why do I keep getting this error for every occurence of NULL (+200 times)?

Edit :

```
#ifndef NULL
   #ifdef __cplusplus
      #define NULL 0
   #else
      #define NULL ((void *)0)
   #endif
#endif
```

Comment: @Serhio It is perfectly valid C. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @Serhio IIRC `#define NULL 0` is standard for C. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Lundin [7.17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) "... which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant ..." . Doesn't it mean that such constant should have pointer type like `((void *)0)` ?

Comment: @Serhio 6.3.2.3/3: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*."

Comment: @melpomene Yes, my bad.

Comment: @Serhio You are confusing null pointers and the NULL macro. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32136460/584518)

Comment: "*a window is shown "#define NULL 0".*" so you seem be using the C++ compiler not the C one, right?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't include the `.h` files, or the compiler is not seeking the appropriate folder. Take a look at this [Microsoft docs article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d69tdh6e.aspx).

Comment: In de Directories i included (VC++ Directories : .../Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\)  is one of the header-files suggested in the MSDN article : CRTDBG.H . In this headerfile there is "#include <corecrt.h>" . This headerfile contains the definition of NULL. The problem is this header-file is already included in my project, i still get the error ... This definition however is grayed out (after ifndef NULL) which probably means it's already defined somewhere else.