# How to sum all command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, syntax-error, command-line-arguments, atoi

I have an assignment. The program is to print the sum of all command line arguments in C. I tried this code it compiles but throws an error after passed arguments in the console. Below is the code.

```
/* Printing sum of all command line arguments */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sum = 0, counter;

    for (counter = 1; counter <= argc; counter++) {
       sum = atoi(sum) + atoi(argv[counter]);
    }
    printf("Sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
}
```

After compiling it outputs a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. Your experience may solve my problem.

Below is my edited code:

```
/* Printing sum of all command line arguments*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // Added this library file

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sum = 0, counter;

    for (counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++) {
        // Changed the arithmetic condition
        sum = sum + atoi(argv[counter]);
        // Removed the atoi from sum variable
    }
    printf("Sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
}
```

Comment: `atoi` is one of those C library functions that should [never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563868/584518). Also, when including library functions the format `<stdio.h>` should be used, not `"stdio.h" (although it will work, even though incorrect). You need a better "guru".

Comment: @Mawg Please don't recommend people to post at Code Review when their question is entirely inappropriate for that site. You are not doing anyone a favour. CR requires complete, working code, not incomplete, broken snippets.

Comment: Ok thanks, @Lundin. My guru is not available now. So, I used stack overflow and till now I'm not aware of codereview.stackexchange.com. Next time I will use it. My guru has decades of experience in programming. He is always best.

Comment: @Lundin I just thought that I was helping a new guy; it is unlikely that he would find the site on his won (for a while anyway), and likely that he would benefit from it.  I did state clearly "when your code works, post it to our sister site ...", but feel free to delete me comment.

Comment: @AnudeepSyamPrasad Whoever taught you to use `"stdio.h"` and `atoi` is not "the best", but rather a charlatan.

Comment: @Mawg Incorrect recommendations to post at CR is a hot potato on meta, see for example this fresh discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362417/could-we-have-comments-stating-this-would-work-well-on-code-review-and-simila

Comment: I think that you are missing the part where I said "when your code works" and imagining a part where I said "post the code above to CR". I understand that blanket recommendations of just anything to CR are not on topic, but how do you recommend we do introduce new coders to that extremely helpful site?

Comment: I'm telling you @Lundin it's my thought, not his he always suggests syntax like this <stdio.h>. but I like to try new ways so, I tried this don't see it in a different way but I like the way you respond.

Comment: @Lundin I followed your link to the list of functions which never should be used, and read "atoi() family of functions. These have no error handling but invoke undefined behavior whenever errors occur." atoi() seems pretty well-defined to me. What's the UB?

Comment: @Lundin  *when your code works*, post it to our sister site codereview.stackexchange.com. A fine recomendation

Comment: @Bjorn I assume that [atoi(const char* str)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/atoi) assumes that it's getting a normal null-terminated string / char*. I don't think it has any precautions against getting something that's not null terminated. Just a guess. EDIT : Looks like this is why. "However, because of the ambiguity in returning 0 and lack of thread-safety and async-cancel safety on some operating systems, atoi is considered to be deprecated by strtol."

Comment: @Ian: I agree with your comments, but Lundin said that atoi() had UB. AFAICT it does not. The 0/error ambiguity is a pain in most situations, but a total ban is a bit harsh, isn't it?

Comment: I think that he believes that because we have alternatives (the strtol() family) and because of issues with multithreading, it shouldn't be used. There are downsides to using it and there are better alternatives specifically added to fix the problem. @Bjorn A.

Comment: @BjornA. C11 7.22.1 "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the
behavior is undefined." Basically if you give it anything that is not an ASCII digit, the function is guaranteed to bug out. Unlike `strtol` family of functions, that have 100% equivalent functionality, except they don't bug out.

Comment: @pm100 Not enough. Read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @Ian atoi assumes it gets spoon-fed a null-terminated string consisting of nothing but valid digits. If it gets anything else, it will bug out. There is no point in using it since the `strtol` family of functions have _identical_ functionality (and more), and also proper error handling. It has nothing to do with multi-threading.

Comment: @Lundin : Thanks for the C&V from the standard!

Comment: @Lundin Wicked, thanks!  I didn't know that it was guaranteed to bug out, but I knew it assumed null termination. Won't be using that again.

Comment: @Ian Rather, there are no guarantees what-so-ever since it invokes undefined behavior. The presence of UB in a program is always to be considered as a bug though.

Comment: @Lundin Definitely

Answer (score 12):

Because you are iterating until `counter == argc`, you are passign a `NULL` pointer to `atoi()`, It's simple, just rely on the fact that the `argv` array has a `NULL`sentinel, and do this

```
/* Printing sum of all command line arguments*/
#include <stdlib.h> /* For `atoi()' */
#include <stdio.h>  /* For `printf()' */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 1; argv[counter] != NULL; ++counter)     {
        sum += atoi(argv[counter]);
    }
    printf("Sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
}
```

Note that `atoi(sum)` is undefined behavior because `sum` is an `int` and is not a valid pointer. While `atoi()` will try to dereference it. Also `aoti()` stands for *ascii to integer* and `sum` is already an integer so the conversion doesn't make sense.

Finally, include *stdlib.h* for `atoi()`. I know you didn't include it because I have warnings enabled on my compiler and it warned me that `atoi()` was implicitly defined. It *might* work, but just because *undefined behavior* is that, UNDEFINED.

Also, note that there is no way to know whether the passed argument is an integer, because `atoi()` cannot perform error checking. You might want to use `strtol()` instead and check if all the values are integers.

So ... this is how you would write a more robust version of this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 1; argv[counter] != NULL; ++counter)     {
        char *endptr;
        sum += strtol(argv[counter], &endptr, 10);
        if (*endptr != '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: the `%d-th' argument `%s', is not a valid integer\n", counter, argv[counter]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    printf("sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT**: To address [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565205/how-to-sum-all-command-line-arguments-in-c/48565293#comment84141979_48565293)

There is a possibility that `argc == 0`, for instance if you execute the program through one of the `exec*()` functions. In that case you must check before starting the loop or `argv[counter]` will be one element after the last, i.e. out of bounds.

Comment: Nice, although I have a deep founded dislike for `argv[counter] != NULL`.

Comment: The only complete answer that addresses all of the bugs - nice one.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why? The C standard guarantees that the last pointer in the list is a null pointer.

Comment: @Lundin: I prefer `argv[counter]`, that's all: `!= NULL` is a tautology.

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought you were going to say you preferred to use `counter < argc`

Comment: If you wanted this to be *really* robust, you could check for potential `int` overflow (more potential for UB and such effects could manifest themselves at +/- 32767). But is this getting silly now?

Comment: @ChrisTurner: No that sucks.

Comment: @Bathsheba Pah. I bet you prefer that until someone writes `*argv[counter]` and gets an eternal loop, while `*argv[counter] == NULL` would give a compiler error for comparing incompatible types. It is not a tautology, it is rugged, professional code that reduces bugs. MISRA-C bans the former dangerous style for a reason.

Comment: @Lundin, Wading slightly off topic here, `*argv[counter] == NULL` would compile in standard C++ without warning, so, really, I think this is merely kicking the can down the road of increasing obfuscation. Much of MISRA is, in my opinion, pure unbridled dogmatism. I'll get me coat.

Comment: @Bathsheba As I hate `; argv[counter] ;` it doesn't let you know whether it's a pointer or an `int` or even a `bool`. Explicit comparison adds clarity to the code.

Comment: @Bathsheba And to respond to your second comment, yes. That's why I said "*more* robust" instead of "*really* robust".

Comment: @Bathsheba Sane C compilers implement NULL as `(void*)0` and then you get the best possible type safety as demonstrated by my example, since comparison between a integer type and a pointer is not allowed. C++ is not always safer than C - this would be a perfect example of C++ "blowing your whole leg off".

Comment: @Lundin Real C programmers use bare 0 for the null pointer anyway, rendering the expansion of NULL moot.  I'm with Bathsheba: explicit comparisons of pointers to NULL/0 are tautological, add visual clutter, and don't actually prevent bugs.

Comment: Nit: Maybe not return -1 from main()?

Comment: @BjornA. And that is because...?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Well, the main() function in a C program should  return either EXIT_SUCCESS(0) or EXIT_FAILURE.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesnt actually explain what was wrong with the original code. OP will ikely commit the same error again later

Comment: @pm100 I disagree, I explained every mistake. Even the missing include. I can clarify something though

Comment: If `argc == 0` (and `argv[0] == NULL`), this has an out of bounds array access.

Comment: @hvd Under normal cirmcumstances this will not happen at all. But to be strict, I added a comment in the answer.

Comment: @zwol I just proved black on white how it prevents bugs. "No" is not a valid counter-argument. Now, real C programmers actually know the difference between a null pointer, a null pointer constant and the NULL macro. [Study this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32136460/584518).

Comment: @BjornA. You are right, that's strictly true and correct. So I am accepting your suggestion and changing it in my code, and will keep using the macros form now on. Although note, [that sometimes you might want to return a value that indicates which error it was](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html), to use it in a shell script for example.

Comment: @Lundin I cannot be bothered to refute you, but you're still wrong.

Comment: @zowl I only do it for readability, I understand that you have a preferred style but you haven't said why is *my* style bad. You say it's tautological and adds visual clutter but, in fact I think it adds clarity since you immediately know that it's a pointer comparison without having seen the variable declaration which I too like it to be at the begining if the scope where it's declared, precisely for that, to know it's scope. Also, C programmers are allowed to have their own style, and you can't say it as if anyone that doesn't follow your style is not a C programmer.

Answer (score 7):

It is specified that `argv[argc]` will *always* be a null pointer. You loop once too many, and pass this null pointer to `atoi`, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Change your loop conditions to be `counter < argc`.

And `sum` already *is* an integer, you do not need to convert it to an integer with `atoi`. That `atoi(sum)` will *also* lead to *undefined behavior* as the very first iteration will pass zero to `atoi`, which could be seen as a null pointer as well.

Answer (score 6):

The last element of `argv` is *defined* to be `NULL`, and the first one is always the program name. Therefore you can reduce your code to

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i){
        sum += atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    printf("Sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
}
```

In your code, the behaviour of `atoi(sum)` and what boils down to `argv[argc]` on the final iteration will be undefined.

Answer (score -2):

A recursive version, just for the heck of it :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    static int sum;

    if (*++argv == NULL)
        return !printf("sum: %d argc %d\n", sum, argc - 1);

    sum += atoi(*argv);
    return main(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, the static int sum keeps it's value through all iterations? Also, nice :)

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, the static is used to keep adding to the same variable.

Comment: You can't call `main()` from within `main()`. The `main()` is special.

Comment: Aw shit, I missed that, you're right. Throw it in it's own method and pass it the arguments and you'll be good.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Of course one can call main() from main(). I just did, didn't I? ;)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi You're thinking of C++. C has no such restriction.

Comment: @hvd: Even if ISO Standard C++ has the restriction, there are C++ compilers that allow recursive `main` anyway.

Comment: @dan04 That feels like a comment that should be directed at Iharob Al Asimi, not at me, but what the C++ standard says and what C++ implementations do have almost equally little relevance to a C question.

Answer (score -2):

```
/* My example. Should work, though untested. */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum, index;    // Generally considered better form to put them on separate lines.
    sum = 0;

    if(argc > 1) {    
        for(index = 1; index < argc; index++) {
            sum += atoi(argv[index]);
        }
        printf("%d Command-line args\nSum = %d\n", argc, sum);
    } 
    else {
        printf("Not enough command-line args\n");
    }
}
```

Make sure to try you hardest to adhere to a specific formatting style for your code. Search for style guides if you want to define yours by name. [GNU C is a good starting point](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Writing-C.html). They'll make your code more readable for you, easier to debug, and help others understand what's going on in it.

Couple of corrections for your aforementioned code..

```
/* Your code with corrections */
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sum=0,counter; 
   // 1. Normally you want to give each variable it's own line. Readability is important.
   // 2. Don't initialize on declaration either. Refer to my example.
   // 3. Always add spaces between operators and at the end of statements for better readability.
    for(counter=1;counter<=argc;counter++)
    {
       // 4. atoi(sum) is unneccessary as it interprets your int sum as a const char*, 
       // which as far as I can tell should just give you back it's ascii value. 
       // It might be undefined however, so I would remove it regardless.
       // 5. Your segfault issue is because you iterate over the end of the array.
       // You try to access the [argc] value of the array (remember 0-based
       // indexing means a size val is always 1 greater than the greatest index).
       // Make 'counter<=argc' into 'counter < argc'

       sum = atoi(sum) + atoi(argv[counter]);
    }
  printf("Sum of %d command line arguments is: %d\n", argc, sum);
}
```

[atoi() documentation of a form.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

Be forewarned, your code will still function if you input chars or strings into the command line, but the behavior will be odd. atoi() will convert the char to it's corresponding [ASCII decimal character index/value.](https://ascii.cl/)

You can also use a null value (argv[] is always terminated with a NULL value at argv[argc]) to end iteration. I prefer using the provided argc though.

Hopefully this helps you a little bit. If you don't understand anything I threw up here, comment or search it online.

Cheers!

Comment: You never actually explain the cause of the bug.

Comment: @John3136 Yes I did. Read the comments in his code. I explain it in #5.