# Why cant we add two pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{
  int x=10;
  cout<<"value of x: "<<x<<endl;
  cout<<"address of x: "<<&x<<endl;

  int *p;
  p=&x;
  cout<<"value of p: "<<p<<endl;
  cout<<"address of p: "<<&p<<endl;
  cout<<"pointer of p: "<<*p<<endl;

  cout<<"\n"<<"ADDING"<<"\n\n";
  p=p+2;
  cout<<"value of p: "<<p<<endl;
  cout<<"address of p: "<<&p<<endl;
  cout<<"pointer of p: "<<*p<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In the above code i am adding a constant number to a pointer **p**,but if i try to add 2 pointers then i get an error that it is not allowed.

The reason that i understood of not adding 2 pointers is that it could result in a overflow and crash the code.

But if i wanted to crash the code then i could have added a larger number to the pointer like below:

```
int main()
{
  int x=10;
  cout<<"value of x: "<<x<<endl;
  cout<<"address of x: "<<&x<<endl;

  int *p;
  p=&x;
  cout<<"value of p: "<<p<<endl;
  cout<<"address of p: "<<&p<<endl;
  cout<<"pointer of p: "<<*p<<endl;

  cout<<"\n"<<"ADDING"<<"\n\n";
  p=p+10000000000000000;
  cout<<"value of p: "<<p<<endl;
  cout<<"address of p: "<<&p<<endl;
  cout<<"pointer of p: "<<*p<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Thus the above code would crash, if crashing was the reason then why are we allowed to even add a constant to a pointer.

Comment: what sense are you trying to make when you add a `int*` to a `char*`?

Comment: [Addition of two pointers in c or c++ not supported. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25667580/995714)

Answer (score 2):

*The reason that i understood of not adding 2 pointers is that it could result in a overflow and crash the code.*

---

That is not the only reason. The main reason is that it does not make any sense in a pointers perspective.

Think when you are adding a constant number like `2` to `p`. That would mean that you want `p` to skip and element and start pointing to the 2nd element in the linear memory block.

But since adding 2 pointers makes no sense, it is not useful at all.

---

Quoting K&R,

> The valid pointer operations are assignment of pointers of the same type, adding and subtracting a pointer and an integer, subtracting or comparing two pointers to the members of the same array, and assigning or comparing to zero. All other pointer arithmetic is illegal. **It is not legal to add two pointers...**

Answer (score 1):

> The reason that i understood of not adding 2 pointers is that it could result in a overflow and crash the code.

That is not correct.

The binary `+` operation, and its meaning, is defined by the standard for a pointer and an integral type.

The standard simply does not define the binary `+` operation between two pointers.

This is not the right place to discuss why the standard does not define that operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding two pointers.  p holds the address of x. So once you add P+2 then pointer is pointing to +2 address location
Example if your x is at 0x1000 address location then after adding, your pointer will point to (0x1000+(2*sizeof(int))) address location

Comment: This isn't correct. Pointer arithmetic knows the size of the type that is pointed to. Since `p` is a pointer to `int` adding `2` would add `2 * sizeof(int)` to the address.

Comment: thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Adding constants to pointers can be useful, such as for traversing a data structure where elements are contiguous in memory.

However, it is harder to find a use case for adding two pointers, as that would give an essentially irrelevant address which, as you say, could be illegal.