# Why does pointer arithmetic work between int* & int* only for minus and not plus?

Tags: c, pointers

I can't seem to understand why I am getting this error. It seems bizarre to me that subtraction works just fine (producing -3) while addition gives me an error.

Why is this the case?, Shouldn't addition return (0x00000001 + 0x00000002 = 0x00000003)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int* x = NULL;
    int* y = NULL;

    // error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)
    int z = &x[0] + &x[3];

    // but this works fine
    int z = &x[0] - &x[3];

    printf("0x%08x\n", x);
    printf("0x%08x\n", &x[0]);
    printf("%d", z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think addition would give you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667580/addition-of-two-pointers-in-c-or-c-not-supported-why

Comment: if you absolutely need this, you can cast them to `int` and then do the addition. `(int)&x[0] + (int)&x[3]`. But agreed with iBug, I cannot see a situation where this would be useful.

Comment: Subtraction of pointers is only specified for pointers in (or 1 after) the same _valid_ array.    `&x[0] - &x[3];` is not a valid subtraction.  As it gave the hoped for result is bad luck.