# Is NULL guaranteed to be 0?

Tags: c++, null

I was wondering if `NULL` is guaranteed to be `0` in C++, so I searched and came across these:

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509805/10147399) answer states that:

> Here is Bjarne Stroustrup's wordings,
>
> > In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there is only an aesthetic
> >     difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0. Another problem with
> >     NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe that it is different
> >     from 0 and/or not an integer.

Which seems to confirm that `NULL` is always 0.

---

But according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL):

> ```
> #define NULL /*implementation-defined*/
> ```
>
> The macro NULL is an implementation-defined null pointer constant,
>   which may be:
>
> -> an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates
>   to zero (until C++11)
>
> -> an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t (since C++11)

And that clearly says `NULL` is implementation dependent.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509811/10147399) answer says:

> 0 (aka. C's NULL bridged over into C++) could cause ambiguity in
>   overloaded function resolution, among other things:
>
> ```
> f(int); 
> f(foo *);
> ```

Which again implies that `NULL` is the integer `0` and that might cause ambiguity

---

There are other questions and answers I encountered, but they are mostly about the C language, not C++. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0/1296868#comment1127790_1296868) comment says:

> And NULL is guaranteed to be 0

But again, that's about C.

---

To sum it all up, is `NULL` always `0` in C++? What about C? Is it (for every standard implementation) the same as:

```
#define NULL 0
```

Note: this question is not about the null pointer, the question is if `NULL` in C++ is guaranteed to be `0` the integer. Is it implementation dependent?

Comment: I recommend searching StackOverflow, then removing this question if it is a duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added everything relevant I found on SO. Can you share some of the relevant questions you came across?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking. Are you asking if `0` and `NULL` must behave the same in all contexts if those literals appear in code? Are you asking if `NULL`, if converted to type `int` must have the value zero? You say things like "is NULL always 0" as if that had an unambiguous meaning and I don't think it does.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if it's exactly the same as `#define NULL 0`

Comment: That first quote from Stroustrup is **really, really old**. It is no longer accurate.

Comment: @George -- `(void*)0` is not a valid null pointer constant in C++; there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to any other pointer type. It's okay in C.

Comment: By your request, seach keys: [stackoverflow c++ null pointer guranteed 0](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+null+pointer+guranteed+0&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS830US830&oq=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+null+pointer+guranteed+0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.15086j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews almost everything from that Google search is either about C, or "Is NULL the same as null pointer"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is NULL guaranteed to be 0?

According to the standard, `NULL` is a null pointer constant (i.e. literal). Exactly which one, is implementation defined.

Prior to C++11, null pointer constants were integral constants whose integral value is equal to 0, so `0` or `0l` etc.

Since C++11, there is a new null pointer literal `nullptr` and `NULL` may be defined as being `nullptr`. (And thus literal interpretation of Bjarne's quote has become obsolete).

Prior to standardisation: `NULL` may be defined as `(void*)0` in C. Since C++ was based on C, it is likely that some C++ dialects pre-dating the standard might have used that definition, but such definition is not conformant with standard C++.

---

And for completeness: As explained in more detail in SO post linked in a comment below, null pointer constant being 0 does not necessarily mean that the value of the null pointer address is 0 (although the address being 0 is quite typical).

What can be concluded about this:

- Don't use `NULL` to represent the number zero (use `0` with appropriate type suffix if appropriate), nor to represent a null-terminator character (use `'\0'`).
- Don't assume that `NULL` resolves to a pointer overload.
- To represent a null pointer, don't use `NULL` but instead use `nullptr` if your standard is >= C++11. In older standard you can use `(T*)NULL` or `(T*)0` if you need it for overload resolution... that said there are probably very few cases where overloading integers with pointers makes any sense.
- Consider that the definition may differ when converting from C to C++ and vice versa.
- Don't memset (or type pun) zero bits into a pointer. That's not guaranteed to be the null pointer.

Comment: "*Prior to C++11, null pointer constants were integral constants whose value is equal to 0, so 0 or 0l etc.*" But even then it was implementation dependent, am I right?

Comment: It was as it still is implementation defined which one of the null pointer constants would be used to define `NULL`. One implementation might use `0`, another might use `0l` - and now it may be `nullptr`.

Comment: [What if you have a machine with nonzero bit pattern for nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761408/2466431)

Comment: Don't assume memset(struct,0,) initialized your pointers to nullptr either. Good luck tracking that bug down 10 years from now when you port to ARM. It won't be fun.

Answer (score 0):

I think its fine practice to assume so. Having said that, it would be horrible practice to #undef NULL and or redefine it as something else. So long story short, it's not a 100% guarentee because it is possible to be something else, but it NEVER should be.

Comment: If you have the choice, it should probably be `nullptr`, not `0`, or some other zero integer-literal.

Comment: Depending on my user defined functions and how they return, sometimes i.check against NULL in conditionals. Maybe its bad practice, but Ive never had an issue.