# Is it safe to assume that the NULL constant is zero?

Tags: c, pointers, null, null-pointer

The book **Understanding and Using C Pointers**, by Richard Reese says:

> The null concept is an abstraction supported by the null pointer
>   constant. This constant may or may not be a constant zero. A C
>   programmer need not be concerned with their actual internal
>   representation.

My question is, since "this constant may or may not be a constant zero," is it safe for me to do things like the below in my code:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
// Some code which probably sets ptr to a valid memory address

if(!ptr)
{
   ERROR();
}
```

If NULL is not 0, there is a chance that the if clause will evaluate to true.

Comment: The result of `!ptr` has nothing to do with whether null pointers are represented as 0 in the hardware. `!` isn't defined that way.

Comment: (Also, it doesn't matter what the `NULL` macro expands to - even if `NULL` expands to `0`, the underlying representation of a null pointer is not required to be 0.)

Comment: [comp.lang.c FAQ: This is strange. NULL is guaranteed to be 0, but the null pointer is not?](http://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html), [Is NULL guaranteed to be 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54098794/995714)

Comment: Don't mix up all the different terms: null pointer, null pointer constant, the NULL macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that the NULL constant is zero?

`NULL` will compare equal to `0`.
`NULL` is *very* commonly a zero bit pattern.  It is possible for `NULL` to be a non-zero bit pattern - but not seen these days.

---

OP is mixing as least 4 things: `NULL`, *null pointer constant*,  *null pointer*, comparing a *null pointer* to 0.  C does not define a *NULL constant*.

**`NULL`**

> `NULL` is a macro "which expands to an implementation-defined null
> pointer constant" C17dr § 7.19 3

***null pointer constant***

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
> cast to type `void` *, is called a *null pointer constant*. C17dr § §
> 6.3.2.3 3

Thus the *type* of a *null pointer constant* may be `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, ... or `void *` .

When an integer constant expression<sup>1</sup>, the *null pointer constant* *value* is 0.   As a pointer like `((void *)0)`, its value/encoding is not specified.  It ubiquitously does have the bit pattern of zeros, but is not specified so.

There may be many *null pointer constants*.  They all compare equal to each other.

Note: the *size* of a *null pointer constant*, when it is an integer, may differ from the size of an object pointer.  This size difference is often avoided by appending a `L` or two suffix as needed.

***null pointer***

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
> resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare
> unequal to a pointer to any object or function.  C17dr § § 6.3.2.3 3
>
> Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null
> pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal. C17dr
> § § 6.3.2.3 4

The type of *null pointer* is some pointer, either an object pointer like `int *, char *` or function pointer like `int (*)(int, int)` or `void *`.

The *value* of a *null pointer* is not specified.  It ubiquitously does have the bit pattern of zeros, but is not specified so.

All *null pointer* compare as equal, regardless of their encoding.

**comparing a *null pointer* to 0**

`if(!ptr)` is the same as `if(!(ptr != 0))`.  When the pointer `ptr`, which is a *null pointer*, is compared to 0, the zero is converted to a pointer, a *null pointer* of the same type: `int *`.  These 2 *null pointers*, which *could* have different bit patterns, compare as equal.

---

**So when it is not safe to assume that the NULL constant is zero?**

`NULL` may be a `((void*)0)` and its bit pattern may differ from zeros.  It does compare equal to 0 as above regardless of its encoding.  Recall pointer compares have been discussed, not integer compares. Converting `NULL` to an integer may not result in an integer value of 0 even if `((void*)0)` was all zero bits.

```
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)(uintptr_t)NULL); // Possible not 0
```

Notice this is converting a pointer to an integer, not the case of `if(!ptr)` where a 0 was converted to a pointer.

The C spec embraces many old ways of doing things and is open to novel new ones.  I have never came across an implementation where `NULL` was not an all zeros bit pattern.  Given much code exist that assumes `NULL` is all zero bits, I suspect only old obscure implementations ever used a non-zero bit-pattern `NULL` and that `NULL` can be all but certain to be an all zero bit pattern.

---

<sup>1</sup> The *null pointer constant* is 1) an integer or 2) a `void*`.  "When an integer ..." refers to the first case, not a cast or conversion of the second case as in `(int)((void*)0)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: Not positive about that, "An integer constant expression with the value 0, ..., is called a null pointer constant" --> Slightly re-worded my answer to the case when null pointer constant is an integer.  Looks clear to me that when an integer the value is zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "(int) NULL is not necessarily zero" --> Agree as the answer has "NULL may be a ((void*)0) and its bit pattern may differ from zeros".

Comment: "When an integer, *the null pointer constant value* is 0": this is still problematic.  The standard provides no reason to suppose that when an integer constant with value 0 is used in a source-code context that requires it to be interpreted in its role as a null pointer constant, that it will be translated to a pointer value whose representation has all bits zero.  It's not clear to me that that's what you're trying to assert, but that also is a reason why the statement is problematic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agree about "no reason to suppose  ... integer constant with value 0 ... requires it to be interpreted in its role as a null pointer constant".  My assertion is the other way around, when the _null pointer constant_ is some integer, its value is 0.  Not an integer  zero is a _null pointer constant_.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Note added to answer to address the first part about interpretation.  [implementation might use 0xffffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768339/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-the-null-constant-is-zero/60769734#comment107531321_60769734) is covered in the "So when it is not safe to assume .." part of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`if(!ptr)` is a safe way to check for a NULL pointer.

The expression `!x` is exactly equivalent to `0 == x`.  The constant `0` is a *NULL pointer constant*, and any pointer may be compared for equality against a NULL pointer constant.

This holds true even if the representation of a null pointer is not "all bits 0".

Section 6.5.3.3p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `!` operator states:

> The  result  of  the  logical  negation  operator `!` is  0  if  the 
>   value  of  its  operand  compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its
>   operand compares equal to 0.  The result has type `int`. The
>   expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

And section 6.3.2.3p3 regarding pointer conversions states:

> An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an 
>   expression  cast  to  type `void *`, is called a *null pointer
>   constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type,
>   the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Answer (score 2):

chux has written a good, detailed answer, but regarding that book specifically, I'd be sceptic about its quality:

- > This constant may or may not be a constant zero

  This is wrong, it must always be a zero or a zero cast to a `void*`. The definition of a null pointer constant is found in C17 6.3.2.3/3:

  > An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
  >   void *, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
  >   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
  >   to a pointer to any object or function.

  This means that all integer constant expressions like `0`, `0L`, `0u`, `0x0`, `'\0'` etc are null pointer constant. If any of them is cast to a `void*`, it is also a null pointer constant.
- > A C programmer need not be concerned with their actual internal representation.

  The author is obviously mixing up the two formal terms *null pointer constant* and *null pointer*. A programmer do not need to concern themselves with the internal representation of a null pointer. They do need to know what makes a valid null pointer constant though. The safest, most readable way being to use the `NULL` macro, which is guaranteed to be a null pointer constant.

So regarding your question "is it safe for me to do things like the below in my code" - yes it is perfectly safe to do `!ptr` to check for a null pointer, even though `ptr==NULL` is more readable code.

Comment: A subtle weakness with asserting wrong-ness with "constant may or may not be a constant zero" is that _zero_ is a number whereas `(void*)0` is a pointer - and as a pointer can have different size and encoding than a `0`.  - .  As an integer, a zero must be all 0 bits. (setting aside archaic non-2's-complement 
 with its -0 for now).  The pointer `(void*)0` may have a non-zero bit pattern.  IAC, the _null pointer constant_, as an integer or pointer, compares equal to `0`, regardless of encoding/size.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `(void*)0` is not a _constant_ though, `0` is.

Comment: Agree that  `0` is an _constant_, an _integer constant_. I'd say `(void*)0` is at best a  "constant address". IAC, the _null pointer constant_ can be `(void*)0`.