# Is assigning '\0' to a pointer is same as assigning NULL to it?

Tags: c, pointers

Are the below statements same?

```
char *PTR='\0';
```

&

```
char *PTR=NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Accidentally, yes.

`'\0'` is a character with ASCII code 0; as such, it is an integer with value 0. `NULL` is usually also an integer with value 0. They are typically of different sizes, but the compiler will recognise that in this case, so in both cases `PTR` ends up as a null-pointer (i.e. pointer with value 0).

If you had written `char *PTR="\0";` with double-quotes, that's a very different situation: `"\0"` would be allocated as a two-character array, with both characters being ASCII 0. `PTR` would be initialised to point at the first of the two zeroes.

Comment: (a) `'\0'` is a character constant with value zero. Whether it is ASCII or not is implementation-dependent. (b) `NULL` is not “usually” an integer with value zero. Per the C standard, it may be either an integer constant expression with value zero or such an expression cast to `void *`. (c) Reasoning about the expressions in terms of being different sizes is a mistake. The semantics of C are defined in terms of types, and there are issues of type compatibility and rules even if sizes are the same.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: a) I said ASCII 0 to differentiate it from ASCII 48, as saying "zero" is confusing. b) yes, it should be. c) you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not, although they will produce the same result. '\0' is a single byte character which we use as a null terminating character on the string. NULL is (void*)0, which is a pointer, and is a 64bit value (or 32bit depending on architecture). You'd be better off using NULL (or nullptr) for pointer values, and keep '\0' as a way to terminate a string. Having said that though, converting '\0' to a pointer should be fine. Going the other way may produce a warning (converting 64bit value to an 8bit one).

```
char *PTR = '\0';
char CHAR = '\0';

char *PTR = NULL;
char CHAR = NULL;  ///< will generate a warning
```

Comment: Re "*NULL is (void*)0*", According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2599766/589924), `NULL` can be either `0` or `(void*)0`.

Comment: In C, `\0` is an `int`, the same as any other character literal. So it is just another way to write `0`.

Comment: `NULL`. or a pointer in general, is not restricted to being a 64-bit or 32-bit value. It is better to convey type semantics to a student than to distinguish values based on widths. The conversion from a pointer to a `char` would be a problem due to the rules about converting types, not due to any rule about converting a 64-bit value to an 8-bit value. `nullptr` is C++, not C.

Answer (score -1):

NULL is a macro. So it depends on what its definition is. Usually NULL is just 0.

Here is already a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/8272795)

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2599766/589924), `NULL` must be either `0` or `(void*)0`.

Comment: @ikegami: `#define NULL ((void*)42)` will throw a warning, but will work (until something bad happens).

Comment: @Amadan, Yes, it would be illegal for the compiler to provide that. Did you not visit the link I provided?

Comment: @ikegami I did not mean for the compiler to provide that. A silly programmer can. The _compiler's_ `NULL` will always be 0, but it does not mean any `NULL` you encounter is guaranteed to be (though it's either malice, obfuscated C code contest or extreme idiocy that would cause it to happen).

Comment: @ikegami yes, thanks for that clarification

Comment: @Amadan, They could also redefine `char`. That's all quite irrelevant.