# what would the string equivalent of a NULL be?

Tags: c, string, if-statement, null

I'm using an if function that needs to check if the string is a NULL but i don't know how to ask for that.

I know that
`if(a == 'NULL') \\int a` should check to see if the int is NULL but how do I ask if a string is empty or null.  I want to say `if(s1[0] == NULL) \\char s1[]` or something similar to this?

I want to make a code like this?

```
char s2[10];
int a;

(...)

if(s2[0] == NULL) \\what I am asking about
  printf("null or empty string\n");
else
  printf("string with items\n");
```

I would like to know what I should put for the if statement to ask if the string is NULL.

Comment: Seeing as how my last 2 questions did not go well (I blame myself), I would like to start asking shorter and more specific questions in hopes that others will easily understand my problems and provide me a better answer.

Comment: **What?** Are you sure you're talking about C?

Comment: if(int a == 'NULL') will not work. Please learn how to use the debugger and look at the contents of a variable. What is a string internally?

Comment: Neither of your expressions makes much sense. Can you please provide a greater context? Are you referring to a `NULL` string pointer, or to a 'nul' string terminator?

Comment: The examples you're showing are definitely not valid C.

Comment: Sorry that my question came out wrong. I wanted to show what variables these are but I didn't think to use the double slashes.  Also, these are just regular string pointers

Comment: The question still doesn't make sense. Show a [MCVE] containing code that compiles.

Comment: Does `int a = 'NULL';` do what you think it does? Output of `printf("%d %X\n", a, a);` is `1314212940 4E554C4C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is defined as zero or 0.

`if(  a == 'NULL' )`

`a` is integer. `'NULL'` is constant `char` value of `'NULL'`. this is differ from `NULL`. be careful.

So, You are comparing `int` with `char`.

`if( s1 == NULL )`
Maybe `s1` is `char *` or `char[]`.

`string s1` This is not C. `string` is C++ STL class as I know.
it can't be null because it is a class instance itself.

`string *s1` can be `NULL`, because it is a pointer to class instance.

Most case pointer inited as `NULL` when the pointer is not allocated or nowhere.
So, this test if `s1` is allocated or not.

`if( s1[0] == NULL )`

You check if `s1` has some string data or empty string `""`, because C string terminated with `char` value 0.

Comment: What is this: `'NULL' `

Comment: `if( s1[0] == NULL )` NO NO NO. If si is NULL it is undefined behavior

Comment: there are no classes and instances in C

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `NULL` is always equal to `0` according to the C standard.

Comment: ok so I know that String s1 does not work in C, and I know that NULL is for int variables and 'NULL' is for characters so would my answer be `if(s1[0] == 'NULL')` with s1 being a char array?

Comment: @mariosegale a character constant of more than one character does not make saense in the first place. `'NULL'` does not make sense. `'x'` does. `'\0'` does.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli so it would be `if(s1[0] == '\0')`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli So I've tested '\0' and it works.  Thank you for answering my question and thank you everyone else for helping as well.  I apologize for making this more confusing than it should have been

Comment: The Question is modified significantly after answer was written..

Comment: @MarcoBonelli both the C99 and C11 standards say that `NULL` is an implementation defined null-pointer constant, so it's not *guaranteed* to be 0.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no they don't, see [C99 6.3.2.3 point 3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C11 6.3.2.3 point 3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). In particular the two footnotes (55 and 66 respectively), which clearly state that **`NULL` is `0`**.  — Quoting: *"An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  `0`,  or  such  an  expression  cast  to  type `void *`,is called a null pointer constant [...] The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant"*.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, but then the referenced note (7.17 in c99 and 7.19 for c11) says that `NULL` is implementation-defined. So which is which? I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying I'm confused.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca 7.17 just means that a particular implementation gets to choose which form of `0` to use and whether to use a `void *` cast or not. The value is still `0`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2599766/3889449).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "regardless of whether or not the machine's internal representation of that has a value of zero" I'm afraid I was thinking of this when I made that first comment. Thanks for setting it straight.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int checkIfNullOrEmpty(const char *str)
{
    return !str || !str[0];
}
```