# is there a difference between x==NULL and !x in c++

Tags: c++, null, c++14

This came to me while traversing a tree
i wrote this:

```
if( node==NULL || node->left==NULL && node->left==NULL) return 1;
```

and the given solution had:

```
if(!node || !node->left && !node->right) return 1;
```

is there a difference between the two i know it might be something stupid but it just click right now.

On this question 
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/children-sum-parent/1/?track=PC-W6-T&batchId=154

this code gives error

```
int isSumProperty(Node *node){
int l=0,r=0;
if( node==NULL || node->left==NULL && node->left==NULL) return 1;

if(node->left) l=node->left->data; else l=0;
if(node->right) r=node->right->data; else r=0;

return ( node->data == l+r && isSumProperty(node->left) && isSumProperty(node->right) );
}
```

but replace the first if statement with the other statement works can you guys explain.

the error comes with the test case:
     2 N 1 N 2 N 1 N 1 N 2 N 1

Comment: Tip: In C++ you should actually use `nullptr`.

Comment: No functional difference at all.

Comment: ok but is there a difference in these?? .. i will take your point into consideration that's what a friend told me as well.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer can, obviously, point at an object:

```
int i;
int *ip = &i;
```

A pointer can also be set to a "null pointer value":

```
int *ip = nullptr;
```

C and C++ also have the notion of a "null pointer constant", which is `0` used in the context of a pointer:

```
int *ip = 0; // null pointer constant, sets ip to hold a null pointer value
```

That constant is also wrapped inside a macro, for better readability:

```
int *ip = NULL; //null pointer constant, sets ip to hold a null pointer value
```

Any pointer can be tested for whether it holds a null pointer value:

```
int *ip = 0;
if (ip) { std::cout << "null pointer"; }
```

When a pointer is used in a place where a boolean value is expected, formally, it gets "contextually converted to `bool`". That's what happens in that `if` statement. The result of contextually converting a pointer to `bool` is `false` if the pointer holds a null pointer value, and true otherwise.

In the question, there are two forms of testing for a null pointer value:

```
if (node == NULL) // explicit test for null pointer value

if (!node) // `node` contextually converted to `bool`, result is negated
```

Some of the comments recommend another form:

```
if (node == nullptr) // explicit test for null pointer value
```

All three of those do the same thing. Those of us who grew up before the days of `nullptr` typically use `if (!node)`. Some folks prefer to make the comparison explicit.

Answer (score -1):

On platforms where `NULL` can be assumed to be equivalent to `0` the `!node` approach can work. In most cases C++ will behave the same way, but this presumed to be platform dependent and there's no reason why `NULL` must be that particular value, as it could [*theoretically* be anything you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky).

In modern C++ you're encouraged to express this as `if (node != nullptr)` to account for this technicality and also to deal with type safety.

C programmers often use the short-hand version of `!node` out of habit but it is making an assumption about now `NULL` works. Should this assumption change in the future it's liable to break a whole lot of code like this.

Comment: Not sure what that link is about in reference to this question.

Comment: i added the whole thing will totally appreciate the help man if you looked through it i have had this problem at a few other places if you could point me to some refrence where i can read about it that would help out a lot

Comment: That looks like another question, which is fine, but do post it as a question and not as an answer, which it isn't. Also be sure to include the error *you* are getting so we know where to start.

Comment: If `node` is a pointer, `!node` is true whenever `node` holds a null pointer vale and false otherwise. That is not platform dependent. The language definition distinguishes between a **null pointer constant** (i.e., `0` in an appropriate context) and a **null pointer value**, which is what gets stored in a pointer when you assign a null pointer constant to it. When a pointer is contextually converted to `bool`, a null pointer value gives `false` and any other value gives `true`.

Comment: The key here is that, while `NULL` can be defined as anything that makes sense to the compiler, a null pointer **value** has well defined properties, regardless of the details of how it's implemented.