# If you use NULL as parameter of malloc(sizeof()), does it return NULL?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I hope not to sound very foolish here, but does the NULL module actually require memory allocation or not when doing this:

```
TheNull = malloc(sizeof(NULL));
```

If true, how can something that has no memory allocated actually exist in the ram?

Comment: isn't `NULL` typically defined as `0` in the architectures WORD size?

Comment: `NULL` is guaranteed to be an integer constant with value `0`, or `(void *)0`. I wouldn't count on all of those being the same as `sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: @ikegami: `NULL` may be any integer constant expression with value zero, including one that is not an integer constant, although I do not know why anybody would do that.

Comment: `TheNull = malloc(sizeof(NULL));` Is that something you wrote, or something you found in someone's code?  Or is it a hypothetical example you invented just to ask about?  In any case, it's either wrong or meaningless.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I didn't say it had to be a numeric literal. Just a constant.

Comment: @ikegami: In the C standard, an “integer constant” is a literal (C 2018 6.4.4.1).  `NULL` is a null pointer constant, which may be an integer constant expression (C 2018 6.6 6), which is different in the C standard’s terminology from an integer constant.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, So what does the spec call the constant value with type integer that results from a "integer constant expression"?

Comment: Re "*If true, how can something that has no memory allocated actually exist in the ram?*", The pointer still takes memory, even if it points to nothing. Or put differently, the address still takes memory to store, even if it's a special address that's guaranteed never to be used.

Comment: @ikegami *`NULL` is guaranteed to be an integer constant with value `0`, or `(void *)0`*  [No it doesn't have to have a value of `0` or `(void*)0`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3): "The macros are

        `NULL`
which expands to **an implementation-defined null pointer constant**"  NB the value zero is never mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Per C 2018 6.3.2.3 3, a *null pointer constant* is “An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`”. The “implementation-defined” part means the implementation could define `NULL` to be `(3*4 - 12)` or `(void *) (3*4 - 12)`; the particular expression is flexible, but the fact that it has to be an integer constant expression with the value 0 or such an expression cast to `void *` is not flexible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The question doesn't specify C18.  In a world where a huge compiler vendor still isn't compliant with last century's C standard, it's a bit strong to say that `NULL` is guaranteed to be some form of zero.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It is the same in previous standards, going back to C 1990. I cite the 2018 standard because the C tag says to use the latest standard by default.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, My comment was directly sourced from the spec. "*An integer  constant  expression with the value 0,  or  such  an  expression  cast to type
void *, is called a null pointer constant.) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.*" Final draft for C11, 6.3.2.3.3.  C18 says something similar. You appear to be using some ancient version of the spec, without any such requirement from the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is not in any other way related to any *NULL module* or *NULL object*. There are no such things anyway.

`NULL` is just a useful definition for a null pointer constant.

The C Standard specifies the `NULL` macro defined in `<stddef.h>` and some other standard headers this way:

> **7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>**
> [...]
> The macros are [...]
> `NULL`
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant [...]

*null pointer constant* is defined in 6.3.2.3:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> [...]
> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.<sup>67)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

---

> <sup>67) The macro `NULL` is defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.</sup>

Many targets define `NULL` is defined as `#define NULL ((void *)0)`, while other targets just use `#define NULL 0`, or possibly some other zero integer constant expression (eg: `0L`, `0UL`...).

Hence `malloc(sizeof(NULL))` attempts to allocate the number of bytes corresponding to the type of the expression in the definition of `NULL`, probably the size of `void` pointer, but never `0` bytes.

Whether it succeeds or not depends on available memory:

- if successful, the return value will be a valid pointer, different from `NULL`.
- if `malloc(sizeof(NULL));` does return `NULL`, it means no memory is available to allocate a very small size, a critical situation that should be reported to the user and handled with care.

Comment: A null pointer constant may be any integer constant expression, not just an `int` integer constant expression.

Comment: And it doesn't have to be zero...

Comment: Re "*And it doesn't have to be zero*", yeah it does. "An integer constant expression  with the value 0, or such an expression  cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function." So sayeth C18, with something identical or similar in C11 and C99. I didn't look any further back. Once you cast it to a pointer, it might not longer be zero (though still equal `0`), but there's no cast (implicit or not) here.

Comment: @chqrlie, oh, you're talking about that. That's irrelevant. The size of the pointer is the same whether it's NULL or not. We don't care about that here. It's the other possibility --when it's not cast to a pointer-- that's worth mentioning.

Comment: @chqrlie I would interpret the standard's definition of a null pointer constant as exhaustive, i.e., if it could be something other than a zero integer expression or such an expression cast to a pointer, then the standard would say it. So the implementation-defined part, IMO, just allows the implementation to choose the integer expression / type and whether to cast it, but not to make the integer value something other than zero. Anyway, there is a separate question about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599207/can-a-conforming-c-implementation-define-null-to-be-something-wacky/2599766

Comment: @ikegami: I agree with you, the wording of the Standard is clear: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, **is called** a null pointer constant." constitutes a definition of "a null pointer constant".  Hence `NULL` must fit this definition in an implementation defined manner.

Comment: @Arkku: agreed. Answer updated.

Answer (score 6):

> If you use NULL as parameter of `malloc(sizeof())`, does it return `NULL`?

No, unless out-of-memory, like any other allocation.

`NULL`, the *null pointer constant*, does not have a particular type.  It may be `void *`, `int`, `long`, or some integer type.

Avoid `sizeof(NULL)` as its size/type may differ from system to system.

Answer (score 2):

> `TheNull = malloc(sizeof(NULL));`

That doesn't allocate 0 bytes (because `sizeof(NULL)` isn't zero), but `malloc(0)` *might*. The standard says:

> If size is zero, the behavior of malloc is implementation-defined. For
> example, a null pointer may be returned. Alternatively, a non-null
> pointer may be returned; but such a pointer should not be
> dereferenced, and should be passed to free to avoid memory leaks.

So, maybe a null pointer, maybe not.

> If true, how can something that has no memory allocated actually exist in the ram?

The pointer returned from `malloc` might point to a piece of memory slightly larger than what you asked for. For example, if you ask for 1 or 2 bytes, you might get 8 (or even 16) bytes instead. A memory manager often only provides certain size memory blocks (for efficiency), and might require a minimum size so its own bookkeping can fit in a `free`'d block.

And if it returns an oversized block for 1 or 2 bytes, it could do that for 0 bytes as well.