# ! vs == nil in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

If you have an object like NSString *someString, what is the difference, if any, between

```
if (!someString)
```

vs

```
if (someString == nil)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first syntax you use:

```
 if (!someString)
```

exploits a sort of "ambiguity" of C deriving from the fact that the original standard of C lacked a proper boolean type. Therefore, any integer value equalling 0 was interpreted as "false", and any integer value different from "0" was taken as "true". The meaning of `!` is therefore defined based on this convention and current versions of the C standard have kept the original definition for compatibility.

In your specific case, `someString` is a pointer, so it is first converted to an integer, then `! someString` is interpreted as a bool value of `true` when `someString` points at the location `0x000000`, otherwise it evals to "true".

This is fine in most conditions (I would say always), but in theory, `NULL/nil` [could be different from `0x000000`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Null_pointer) under certain compilers, so (in very theory) it would be better to use the second syntax, which is more explicit:

```
 if (someString == nil)
```

It is anyway more readable and since `someString` is not an integer (rather a pointer), IMO, better practice in general.

EDIT: about the definition of NULL...

Whether the C standard defines NULL to be 0 is an interesting topic for me...

According to [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 7.17, "Common definitions ":

> NULL [which] expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;

So, NULL is defined in stddef.h to an *implementation-defined null pointer constant*...
The same document on page 47 states:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.55)  If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

So, the null pointer constant (which is `(void*)0`) can be *converted* to a null pointer and this is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

So, I think that basically it depends on whether the implementation decides that the result of converting a *null pointer constant* to a *null pointer* produces a pointer which converted back to an integer gives 0. It is not clear that a *null pointer* interpreted as an integer equals 0.

I would say that the standard really try and enforce the null pointer being 0, but leaves the door open to [systems where the null pointer was not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0).

Comment: I gave +1, but there is no ambiguity in C on the idea of a boolean value - it simply does not exist.

Comment: NULL is defined to be `0` or `(void *)0` by the C standard. Even if the underlying bit-pattern used for the null pointer value is different, it does not change the fact that the null pointer constant in C is represented as `0` or `(void *)0`.

Comment: @Perception: It does in C99. Check out `_Bool`.

Comment: @Perception: thanks, I improved my wording...

Comment: @dreamlax: thanks also for your comment, it prompted me to read about the NULL topic a bit; it all comes down to whether `(void*)0` is the same as the *null pointer* or not, and it seems to me that it is not, since the standard calls it null pointer constant and speaks about *conversion* to null pointer...

Comment: @JAB - I guess I should have specified the version of C on which Objective-C was originally built as opposed to the new C99. But seeing as c99 still needs to be built in LLVM with a switch, is it fair to consider it the default behaviour of Objective-C?

Comment: @Perception: It's more a matter of recognizing that the behavior can exist rather than considering it the default.

Comment: @JAB - Yes it does exist. The real irony though is that _Bool is for all intents, just an unsigned int capable of storing 0 or 1! stdbool.h has largely been designed for backwards compatibility and all conditional logic actually remains unchanged, even in c99.

Comment: It's about `nil` here, not about `NULL`, and `nil` is defined as `(id)0`!

Answer (score 9):

For most pointers, they're equivalent, though most coders I know prefer the former as it's more concise.

For weakly linked symbols, the former resolves the symbol (and will cause a crash if it's missing) while an explicit comparison against `nil` or `NULL` will not.

Answer (score 3):

The bang, exclamation, `!` prefix operator in C is a *logical not*. At least, its a version of it. If you looked at a typical logical not truth table you would see something like this:

```
Input       Result
  1            0
  0            1
```

However in C the logical not operator does something more like this:

```
Input       Result
non-zero      0
   0          1
```

So when you consider that both NULL and nil in Objective-C evaluate to 0, you know that the logical not operator applied to them will result in a 1.

Now, consider the *equality* `==` operator. It compares the value of two items and returns 1 if they are equal, 0 if they are not. If you mapped its results to a truth table then it would look exactly like the results for logical not.

*In C and Objective-C programs, conditionality is actually determined by int's, as opposed to real booleans. This is because there is no such thing as a boolean data type in C. So writing something like this works perfectly fine in C:*

```
if(5) printf("hello\n"); // prints hello
```

and in addition

```
if(2029) printf("hello\n"); // also prints hello
```

Basically, any non-zero int will evaluate as 'true' in C. You combine that with the truth tables for logical negation and equality, and you quickly realize that:

```
(! someString) and (someString == nil)
```

are for all intents identical!

So the next logical question is, why prefer one form over another? From a pure C view-point it would be mostly a point of style, but most (good) developers would choose the equality test for a number of reasons:

1. It's closer to what you are trying to express in code. You ***are***
   trying to check if the someString variable is nil.
2. It's more portable. Languages like Java have a real boolean type.
   You cannot use bang notation on their variables or their NULL
   definition. Using equality where its needed makes it easier to port
   C to such languages later on.
3. Apple may change the definition of nil. Ok, no they won't! But it
   never hurts to be safe!

Comment: "any non-zero int will evaluate as 'true' in C"
Could you, please, be more specific explaining how are logical expressions evaluated to (int)0 or (int)1? Say, [if(pointer)...], pointer is at first converted to int [(int)pointer] and then [if((int)pointer != 0)] it evaluates to (int)1. Could it be so that pointer is 64bit while int is 32bit and, when it's casted to int, higher bytes are truncated (if(0xffffffff00000000) => if((int)0x00000000))? I'll be glad to see where I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it means the same thing. Any pointer that does not point to `nil` will return `YES` (true).

Normally the exclamation mark operator negates a `BOOL` value.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to test the condition "foo is nil" you should say that: `foo == nil`.

If you mean to test a boolean value for falsehood, `!foo` is okay, but personally I think that a skinny little exclamation point is easy to miss, so I prefer `foo == NO`.

Writing good code is about clearly conveying your intention not just to the compiler, but to the next programmer that comes along (possibly a future you). In both cases, the more explicit you can be about what you're trying to do, the better.

All that aside, `!` and `==nil` have the same effect in all the cases I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a negation operator. If your object isn't allocated, you will reach the same result from a truth table as you would with an `== nil` operation.

But, ! is usually more used for boolean operations.

```
if(!isFalse) {
     //if isFalse == NO, then this operation evaluates to YES (true)
     [self doStuff];
}
```

When you use `!` on an object like `!something` it just checks to see if the pointer is pointing to `nil`, if it doesn't, it returns true, and the if statement fires.