# Why does my if statement work, but my else doesn't?

Tags: c, if-statement, string-literals

Sorry if this has been asked before or is a stupid question, but I'm new to both the site and C. So, when I run this code, when I type an answer, any answer, be it right or wrong, it says what it's supposed to say when for the if statement.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("1+1=");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if("x==2"){
        printf("Watch out, we got a genius over here!");
    }
    else {
        printf("I don't even know what to say to this...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(x==2){` ...

Comment: "Watch out, we got a genius over here!" - a rather unfortunate output statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. The `if` condition as written tests whether the pointer to the string `"x==2"` is a null pointer, and it isn't, so the `if` always evaluates to true.  Hence, as everyone else said, you need to remove the quotes around `x == 2`. Also, it is a good idea to print a newline at the end of each line of output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need

```
if(x==2)
```

without the quotes

Comment: And perhaps with more breathing room: `if (x == 2) {`. White space is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x;
printf("1+1=");
scanf("%d", &x);
if(x==2){
    printf("Watch out, we got a genius over here!");
}
else {
    printf("I don't even know what to say to this...");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("1+1=");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //modify this line if("x==2"){
    if(x==2){
        printf("Watch out, we got a genius over here!");
    }
    else {
        printf("I don't even know what to say to this...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"x==2"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) of type `const char*` that lies in memory and has an address. Addresses to real objects in C are never 0<sup>§</sup> so the expression is *always* **true** and the else branch will never be taken

---

<sup>§</sup>Although some architecture (most notably embedded systems) may have a non-zero *bit pattern* for NULL pointer, but C requires them to compare equal to zero constant. See [When was the NULL macro not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2597142/995714)