# Difference between return values NULL and zero

Tags: c

What is the difference between `return NULL` and `return 0` in C?

Yes, I know that `0` is a number and `NULL` is a void. But I don't understand the purpose of the two in context of programming.

Also I believe `return 0` doesn't return the number `0` to calling function, but returns `void`. So what difference would it make if the statements `return NULL` and `return 0` are interchanged?

Comment: NULL is *not* a `void`. Void has no value, it's nonexistent!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0?rq=1

Comment: void it a type. Null is a valid value for a void pointer

Comment: Besides the technical answer, even if there were no difference, it would still be correct to use NULL to refer to a canonical invalid pointer, and never to an integer value, and incorrect to ever do anything else. Semantic development often follows statement of intent, so it's worthwhile to say what you mean just for its own sake.

Answer (score 1):

In C

```
#define NULL  ((void*) 0)
```

That means `NULL` is of type `void*` (a pointer without a type). And the value for it is 0.

There is no difference in assigning zero or `NULL` to a pointer variable. `NULL` may be just more readable.

See: http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html

When you are returning zero, you are really returning zero. If a function signature has void specified as a return value, it means that the function does not return a value. In some other languages this is known as a "procedure".

Comment: Mostly, but not always, see [Question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) of the same FAQ, see also: [When was the NULL macro not 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2597142/1606345)

Comment: Quite right. There are some esoteric exceptions to the rule.