# Initializing an array of pointers to NULL

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I got a struct defining a node for a tree data structure:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *children[10];
}
```

Given that `children` is NOT a dynamic array, I would like to initialize each pointer of `children` to NULL,  but what follows doesn't work:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *children[10]={NULL};
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question. `struct *Node children[10];` is a syntax error. (Struct members cannot have initializers.)

Comment: If by some chance you are working with a C++ compiler, you can add a constructor to your `struct` which initializes all the member fields.

Comment: Ok my syntax error was actually a typo. Corrected. And no, I cannot use a C++ compiler.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, after my last comment I was left without internet connection. All useful answers, I upvoted them all. Probably I should go with designated initializers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
 struct *Node children[10];
```

is wrong. I would not even compile. It should be

```
 struct Node *children[10];
```

To initialize all elements of member `children` to `NULL` you can use designated initializers.

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *children[10];
} node = {.children = {NULL}};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *children[10];
} a = {.children = {0}};
```

`a` is a `struct Node` object with all element of `children` member initialized to a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize data in the description of the `struct` because no memory has been allocated yet.

Let's look at the two styles of allocation you'll see:

#### The Stack

```
struct Node my_node = {
    0,
    {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

Or, because unlisted values will default to `0`...

```
struct Node my_node = {};
```

#### The Heap:

Here, are only option is to null out the memory. We could use `calloc()` to do this since the memory it returns is zeroed out.

```
struct Node *my_node = calloc(1, sizeof(*my_node));
```

Or, we can explicitly use `memset()`:

```
struct Node *my_node = malloc(sizeof(*my_node));
memset(my_node, 0, sizeof(*my_node));
```

#### Notes:

I'm generally assuming that `NULL == 0`. This isn't necessarily true. If you'd like to read more about these (mostly) historical systems: [When was the NULL macro not 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0)

If you're on one of those systems, or you're concerned about your code working on those platforms, then I would recommend using the first method (and most explicit) method that I described. It will work on **all** platforms.

Comment: `memset` is not guaranteed to set pointers to `NULL`; a null pointer can legally have a non-zero representation. It's likely to work on most systems.

Comment: `struct Node my_node = {};` is not C.