# C compare two pointers greater than if one is null

Tags: c, pointers, c89

If I compare two pointers in C I am aware of C 6.5.8/5 which says:

> pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure

That is fine but what if one of the pointers is `NULL`? I know I can do `foo != NULL` but for example is this against the standard:

```
char *bar = NULL;
char *foo = "foo";
if(foo > bar) { function(); }
```

The section doesn't specifically address `NULL` in the case of greater than which is why I'm confused. Also if you could tell me if it applies to C89 as well as C99.

To clarify, this has nothing to do with structures that is just the part of the standard I was quoting. The code is very similar to what I describe above. I have some pointers to an array and one of those pointers may be null therefore I'd like to know if it's ok to compare using greater than.

Comment: In tour example there isn't any "pointer to structure member". Also pointer to &s.m and s.m are different things

Comment: You may be confusing the *address of* a pointer and the *contents of* a pointer. It is a general statement consistent with the standard that pointers to struct declared later will have lager *addresses*. When you compare `(foo > bar)`, you are comparing *contents*.

Comment: Those two variables are not structure members as far as I can see.

Comment: You might as well have quoted the section on trigraphs.  The ONLY valid comparisons with a NULL pointer are `== NULL` and `!= NULL`.

Comment: Why add a quote from the standard if it's not really related to the question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's the only part I could find that I thought was relevant.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2597232/509868) for practical examples of `NULL` comparing greater than normal pointer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is indeed undefined. As explained in *C11, 6.5.8., p5*, every rule mandates that pointers point to the same object
or one past that object.

So, two pointers may be compared using relational operators: `<, >, <=, >=`, only if *they point to the same object* or one past that object. In *all other cases:*

> 6.5.8. Relational operators,
>
> 5. . In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

Pointer with the value NULL, a null pointer, doesn't point to an object. This is explained in:

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 3. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>    pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>    to a pointer to any object or function.

Comment: finally an answer that deals with comparing with NULL, not getting hung on that "structure members".

Comment: so just to be clear: `NULL` can only be '==' and `!=` compared. Any other comparison `<` etc. is undefined.

Comment: @bolov That bothered me too, so I gave an answer.

Comment: @bolov Yes, for NULL only ==, !=.

Answer (score 3):

The C99 standard says:

> If the objects pointed to are members of the *same aggregate object*,
>   pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
>   declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript
>   values.

The key here is in *same object*:

```
struct {
  int a; // structrure members
  int b;
} some_struct;

// so pointers to structure members:
&(some_struct.b) > &(some_struct.a)
```

The same applies for arrays:

```
char arr[128];
&(arr[100]) > &(arr[1])
```

If a pointer is `NULL` then it is most probably not pointing to a member of the same data structure, unless you're programming the BIOS (and even then it's against the standard, since the null pointer is guaranteed to not point inside any object), so the comparison becomes kinda useless

Answer (score 0):

> pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure

The quote only describes member variables inside a struct.  For example:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

Then any instance of A has it's address of a smaller than b.

In other words,  if someone write a statement like the followings:

```
 A instanceA;
 int* aa = &(instanceA.a);
 int* ab = &(instanceA.b);
```

then it is guaranteed that ab > aa as member variable b is defined later than a.

Answer (score 0):

That section of code is talking about:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct things {
    int blah;
    int laterz;
};   

struct things t;

int main ( void ) {

    int * a = &t.blah;
    int * b = &t.laterz;

    printf("%p < %p\n", (void *)a, (void *)b);
    return 0;
}
```

A pointer to laterz is greater than one to blah.

Answer (score 0):

The specification also says that you can only compare two *related* pointers using anything else than equality or inequality.

So if you have two pointers that both point to different places in the same buffer then you can compare them using the greater or lesser than operators., not other wise.

Example

```
char buffer1[] = "foobar";
char buffer2[] = "some other text";
char *ptr1 = buffer1 + 3;
char *ptr2 = buffer2;
```

With the above, you can compare `buffer1` and `ptr1` using `<` and `>`. You *can't* do that with `ptr1` and `ptr2`, only use the `==` or `!=` operators.

Comment: what about comparing (`<`, `>`) with NULL

Comment: @bolov I'm not actually sure, but then you have to make sure that one of the pointers actually *is* `NULL` first, which makes the whole comparison kind of pointless.

Comment: @bolov In practice, I can't see how it would fail unless the compiler explicitly did something to disallow it, however the standard does not seem to allow for it so relying on it would probably be unwise.

Comment: This section of the Standard the OP quoted is concerning pointers to structure fields.  Your answer isn't about that.

Comment: @JohnHascall True, but then the code or the rest of the question doesn't seem to be about structure members at all. Also: "To clarify, this has nothing to do with structures that is just the part of the standard I was quoting."

Comment: The "clarification edit" (made by somebody else?) just muddied the waters.  The question is stupid.  Your answer is as good as any other answer.