# Reading text-file until EOF using fgets in C

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets

what is the correct way to read a text file until EOF using fgets in C? Now I have this (simplified):

```
char line[100 + 1];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), tsin) != NULL) { // tsin is FILE* input
   ... //doing stuff with line
}
```

Specifically I'm wondering if there should be something else as the while-condition? Does the parsing from the text-file to "line" have to be carried out in the while-condition?

Comment: The parsing should be done in the while loop or I guess you could store each line into an array or something and then do your parsing after the while loop. Close the file when you're done with it too

Comment: That's 100% OK, you could even just do `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), tsin)) {...}` and let the return of `fgets` serve as the test in and of itself. (a valid pointer will test `true` and `NULL` will test `false`)

Comment: I think you are doing right, the answer about leaving out != NULL does not add value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

> **On success, the function returns str**.
>   If the end-of-file is encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is
>   set (feof). **If this happens before any characters could be read, the
>   pointer returned is a null pointer** (and the contents of str remain
>   unchanged). If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is
>   set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by
>   str may have changed).

So checking the returned value whether it is `NULL` is enough. Also the parsing goes into the while-body.

Answer (score 4):

What you have done is 100% OK, but you can also simply rely on the return of `fgets` as the test itself, e.g.

```
char line[100 + 1] = "";  /* initialize all to 0 ('\0') */

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), tsin)) { /* tsin is FILE* input */
    /* ... doing stuff with line */
}
```

Why? `fgets` will return a pointer to `line` on success, or `NULL` on failure (for whatever reason). A valid pointer will test `true` and, of course, `NULL` will test `false`.

(*note:* you must insure that `line` is a *character array* declared *in scope* to use `sizeof line` as the length. If `line` is simply a pointer to an array, then you are only reading `sizeof (char *)` characters)

Comment: I see little value to initialize all `line[]` other than style/debug. Do you see other value?

Comment: Nope, other than always trying to impress upon new C programmers that the cost of initializing all variables is quite small compared to the time spent debugging when you don't. In this case, that's the only point.

Comment: your code implies that NULL is 0, but that is not the case on all platforms.

Comment: @AndersK., That's true according to the C standard, but [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stddef.h.html) is stricter.

Comment: @AndersK. do you have an example of a platform where `while (fgets(...))` would fail? I'm curious, I haven't run across one.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597142/when-was-the-null-macro-not-0 but true, maybe it is irrelevant nowadays (I'm old)

Comment: Considering I've got 2 in high school and 1 in middle-school and I've been around since the mid 60's, you can't be that much older...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i solved it in this way

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), tsin) != 0) { //get an int value
   ... //doing stuff with line
}
```