# Using nullptr in API function calls?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, null, nullptr

Using C++ with Visual Studio 2010.  I'm in the process of converting my `NULL`'s to `nullptr`'s.  With my code this is fine.  However if I make a call to WINAPI such as:

```
__checkReturn WINOLEAPI OleInitialize(IN LPVOID pvReserved);
```

normally I would have called this like:

```
::OleInitialize(NULL);
```

Can I safely use `nullptr` where I would have used `NULL` in a call such as this?

That is, can I do this:

```
::OleInitialize(nullptr);
```

Also same with MFC api:

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, ".txt", NULL, 0, strFilter);
```

Can I replace

```
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, ".txt", nullptr, 0, strFilter);
```

I'm guessing I can but I just want to make sure there are no gotchas.

**UPDATE**

So I went through and replaces all my NULL's with nullptr and it seems to work most everywhere however I am getting the below error on the following line:

```
propertyItem = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("SomeName"),
"SomeValue", "SomeDescription", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

> 8>c:\something\something.cpp(118): error C2664: 
>   'CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CMFCPropertyGridProperty(const CString
>   &,const COleVariant  &,LPCTSTR,DWORD_PTR,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR)' : 
>   cannot convert parameter 4 from 'nullptr' to 'DWORD_PTR' 8>          A
>   native nullptr can only be converted to bool or, using 
>   reinterpret_cast, to an integral type

(Note CMFCPropertyGridProperty is a Microsoft MFC class) So what does that mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use `nullptr` anywhere you use `NULL`.

`NULL` expanded to an integer constant expression with the value zero, which could then be converted to a null pointer value of any type. `nullptr` is "pointer literal" that does the exact same thing: it converts to a null pointer value of any type.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr-in-c0x).

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly true from reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr-in-c0x). If a NULL was placed somewhere it should of been 0 before than just replacing all of NULL with nullptr would break code.  I see tutorials everywhere that set handles and kinds of variable types to NULL. Types that shouldn't be assigned as nullptr.

Comment: @Joe: The premise of my answer is that NULL was being used correctly, in the context of pointers.

Comment: @User: this might be confusing, but `DWORD_PTR` is not a pointer type, but an integer.  This means that, as @JoeMcGrath pointed out, you will need to use `0` in that context, not `nullptr`.