# c++ pointer casting help, void* to boolean

Tags: c++, pointers, plugins, casting

Im learning C++ at the moment, and am having some issues with casting pointers. In the first place I am not sure that what I am trying to do is what I want to do..

I am trying to take a function that can return the appropriate pointer to various method pointers based on string parameters, and to then use the method pointer.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef void* (*plugin_function)(void*);

static class Plugin
{
public:
    static bool doBoolStuff(){
        return true;// A Simple function that returns true
    }
};

void* getFunction(string pluginName, string functionName)
{
    if(pluginName =="Bool"){
        return &Plugin::doBoolStuff;
            //If the string is right it should return a method pointer.
            //I think that void* has the ability to point to anything, I am trying
            //to use that functionality to create a system where I am able to set 
            //some parameters and get the appropriate method pointer.
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* pluginFunction;
    pluginFunction = getFunction("Bool","");

    if(pluginFunction == &Plugin::doBoolStuff)cout<<"CastSuccesful!"<<endl;

    //This section right here is where my code is breaking.
    //
    // IntelliSense: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have              
    //(pointer-to-) function type   
    //c:\Users\Walter\Dropbox\Inscription\MethodCasting\MethodCasting\MethodCasting.cpp 
    //MethodCasting

    cout << "Bool function ->"<< pluginFunction()<<endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------"<<endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Does `static class` compile?

Comment: why not change the prototype of function void* getFunction(string pluginName, string functionName) to plugin_function getFunction(string pluginName, string functionName)

Comment: Some possibly beneficial side reading on [nullptr.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: `void*` is not guaranteed to be able to point to anything. Formally it is limited to store pointers to data, not functions or  member functions. It *does* work on many common systems, where all pointers *happen* to have the same size.

Comment: @BoPersson Also, POSIX **requires** that `void *` be able to hold any pointer type (not sure if that applies to C++ too or C only, though.)

Comment: That's an additional requirement by the Posix standard. The language standards do not require this.

Comment: @BoPersson pointers to member functions almost never have the same size as `void *` actually. this is a static function, though, so it's a normal function pointer.

Comment: My guess is that what you really should try is inheritance, with a virtual member function.. you can send what string you like to the factory function, and it can return a propeely typed pointer to the base class, which you can invoke the virtual member function from..

Comment: What you really want is to learn proper C++ idioms. Save low-level hacks such as pointer casting for much, much later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Not true, sorry. As @Stephen Lin pointed out, I failed to read the `static` modifier... So while what you want doesn't work for non-static member functions, it usually does work for static members using `reinterpret_cast` (this behavior is implementation-defined):

```
class Plugin {
    public:
    static bool foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo called!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

void *get_func()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(&Plugin::foo);
}

int main()
{
    void *pluginFunction = get_func();
    (reinterpret_cast<bool (*)()>(pluginFunction))();
    return 0;
}
```

*Original post:*

---

You can't. According to [this article](http://sphaleron.blogspot.hu/2012/01/evil-c-5-member-function-pointer.html):

> However, there is no way to cast the `void *` back to a member function pointer that you could actually use.

I've tried it myself. Actually, all of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and even old C-style casts refused to work - neither with `void *`, nor with `bool (*)()` (yes, I've even tried to cast from a non-member function pointer type to a member function type)...

Sorry, C++ doesn't seem to allow us to do this.

Comment: This is a static function, so it's a normal function pointer, actually.

Comment: @StephenLin No, it's a class member function, so its address is a pointer to member function.

Comment: It is implementation defined in C++11: `Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cvqualification,
shall yield the original pointer value.`

Comment: @JesseGood Do you have some code? I'd be curious to see how it's possible (actually I'm quite disappointed because it seems to be impossible/disallowed).

Comment: @H2CO3 it's not a pointer to member function, there's no implicit `this` argument

Comment: @H2CO3, i think it's still implementation-defined if you can convert normal function pointers to `void *` [(cppreference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)...it'll work on POSIX though, and probably Windows.

Comment: @StephenLin Yes, that was already mentioned in the comments on the question by BoPersson.

Comment: @H2CO3, well, okay, but I think you should mention it in the answer. (it **will** usually work, though)

Comment: @StephenLin Done that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation, if you can do this. In portable C++ you can't. And even if you can, you need explicit casts (in this case `reinterpret_cast<>`) to convert between different pointer types.

Note that this does not extend to real "method" pointers, that is to **non-static** member function pointers. You cannot convert between member function pointers and either object pointers or ordinary function pointers. The approach I present at the end can be used, if you **only** have non-static member function pointers.

Portably `reinterpret_cast<>` can freely convert between function pointer types and object pointer types - although any use of the result except conversion back to the original type is undefined in almost all cases.

For conversions between object pointer types and function pointer types, the C++11 standard says (§5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast]/8):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa
>   is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
>   implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
>   conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to
>   the other type and back, possibly with different cv- qualification,
>   shall yield the original pointer value.

So, it depends on your implementation (and should be documented in its documentation), if casting a function pointer to a `void *` compiles and back compiles at all. Alas, if it does, you should get the expected behavior.

In your code the casts are missing. You need a cast to the generic type (in your case `void*`) in `getFunction` and you need to cast back to the original type in order to call the function. So you will need to know the original type in `main()`:

```
void* pluginFunction = getFunction("Bool","");
// ....
cout << "Bool function ->"<< (reinterpret_cast<bool (*)()>(pluginFunction))()<<endl;
```

A more portable solution would be to use an arbitrary function pointer type, for example `void (*)()` to pass plugin function pointers around, so that you have:

```
typedef void (*any_func_ptr)();

// If you wanted to use this for non-static member functions, you could do
//   struct AnyClass;
//   typedef void (AnyClass::*any_memfun_ptr)();

any_func_ptr getFunction(string pluginName, string functionName)
{
    if(pluginName =="Bool"){
        return reinterpret_cast<any_func_ptr>(&Plugin::doBoolStuff);
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    any_func_ptr pluginFunction = getFunction("Bool","");

    if(reinterpret_cast<bool (*)()>(pluginFunction) == 
         &Plugin::doBoolStuff)
             cout<<"CastSuccesful!"<<endl;

    cout << "Bool function ->"<< (reinterpret_cast<bool (*)()>(pluginFunction))()<<endl;

}
```