# Parent-Less Button

Tags: c++, winapi

Can I create a button without a parent in WINAPI?

I tried doing:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "Button", "BTN", WS_POPUP | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 15, 15, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

then setting the parent to a specified window later on and also showing the button using ShowWindow. This indeed created a fine looking button.

However, the button has no ID and cannot be Identified in WM_COMMAND because the ID is 0.. If two buttons were parentless, there'd be no way to tell them apart. Now if I give it an ID through the HMENU parameter:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, "Button", "BTN", WS_POPUP | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 15, 15, nullptr, 15, nullptr, nullptr);
```

GetLastError() prints "Invalid Menu Handle" and the button will not be created.

If I give it no parent and WS_CHILD, it will say cannot create a top level child window which is understandable.

So what I did was I set the Parent to GetDesktopWindow() and give the button an ID. That works but the button isn't parentless..

So is there a way to give a button an ID (So as to identify it in WM_COMMAND) and at the same time, have its parent NULL so that I can set the parent later? How does Windows Forms do it? The buttons can be parentless until you do Form.add(ButtonName);

Can the same effect be achieved in WINAPI?

Comment: You could distinguish between buttons via `WM_COMMAND`'s `lParam`, which is the control's `HWND`. (It still might not be a good idea, though. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/19/10321772.aspx)

Comment: Calling Windows APIs, I'm not sure passing `nullptr` instead if `NULL`.

Comment: I solved it. I had to pass HWND_MESSAGE as the Parent Parameter. When you call SetParent, that parameter gets changed to the Parent's handle and all is well.

Comment: By the way, @MM. it is perfectly valid to call Windows API functions using `nullptr`. Remember that `NULL` is a preprocessor macro that, in C++, expands to the integer literal `0`. The `nullptr` keyword will do the exact same thing. More information on the behavior of `nullptr` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr). I highly recommend using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in all new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is appears on its face to be a very silly sort of question.

Button controls are by definition child controls, so the call to the `CreateWindowEx` function you use to create the button should also be specifying the `WS_CHILD` style.

Of course, as you mention, you cannot create a child control with no parent; you'll get an error. There is no such thing as a top-level child window.

So then, the answer to the initial question

> Can I create a button without a parent in WINAPI?

is clearly no. Buttons are child controls, and all child controls must have a parent.

Just because Windows let you get away with specifying the `WS_POPUP` flag when you create a button control doesn't mean that it's a valid combination.

I strongly recommend re-reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) for the `CreateWindowEx` function. In particular, note that the `hMenu` parameter is overloaded with respect to its meaning. If you are creating an overlapped or pop-up window (`WS_OVERLAPPED` or `WS_POPUP`), it specifies a handle to a menu. If you're creating a child window (`WS_CHILD`), it specifies the identifier of the child window. The fact that the same parameter is used for both things, depending on the style of the window, should tell you something.

> How does Windows Forms do it? The buttons can be parentless until you do Form.add(ButtonName);

They most certainly cannot. The button controls are not created until you add them to a form or other parent control. The `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class constructor does not create a Win32 window. It just holds a collection of necessary styles used to create the underlying Win32 window when appropriate.

You could, of course, do the same thing by writing a C++ `Button` class. A simple implementation would just have member variables corresponding to the parameters of `CreateWindowEx` and a `Create` member function that would actually call `CreateWindowEx` to create the Win32 window once all of the members had been set. The `Create` method could throw an exception if one of the necessary members had not yet been set to a valid value.

> I solved it. I had to pass HWND_MESSAGE as the Parent Parameter. When you call SetParent, that parameter gets changed to the Parent's handle and all is well.

No, this really is not a "solution" to the problem. As [kero points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317139/366904), you've simply set the button control's parent to the [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only). Again, this might appear to work, but it's a rather strange thing to do and I hardly recommend it as a solution.

If you really want to hack it, I recommend creating your own hidden top-level window to use as a parent for your "unparented" child controls. Then you could use the same trick of calling `SetParent` to reparent them.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it explains a lot and I ended up following your advice. I made a button class with a variable to track whether or not the button has been added to a form (another class I created). Works fine. It does not create a button until a valid parent is supplied.

Answer (score 1):

> I solved it. I had to pass HWND_MESSAGE as the Parent Parameter.  When
>   you call SetParent, that parameter gets changed to the Parent's handle
>   and all is well.

No, you didn't get "Parent-Less Button": the parent window of your message-only button is the "main" message-only window (class "Message").

Comment: This is entirely correct, but it's also not an answer to the question. Not sure whether to upvote or downvote...

Comment: @Cody Gray, to your comment above about "rather strange thing": 
I think it isn't dangerous :) Any window had once been messages-only: at the time of its creation.
// HCBT_CREATEWND + GetAncestor(wParam,GA_PARENT)

Comment: It isn't the *characteristics* of the window that you're parenting to that I find strange. You're right, of course, that all windows are ultimately processing messages. The issue is with parenting a child to a window that *doesn't belong to you*. The root message-only window is a part of Windows, not part of your application. It might work okay to create a child of someone else's parent window (just like you could create a child window of the Notepad window), but it's not behavior I would recommend.