# WM_NOTIFY isn't posted to winProc function (parrent of child is correct, WM_COMMAND works excelent)

Tags: winapi, tabs

I am writing some library with using WIN API. I have a problem with receiving WM_NOTIFY message from WC_TABCONTROL class window in parent window WinProc function. 
I check by "debug prints", that parent of child was set correctly. I receives WM_COMMAND messages and correctly in some function. 
I have not idea what can be a reason for this. Tab control in window looks good and responds for mouse clicks with do visual tab item select change.

for example, when I click to unselected tab, I receive following messages http://pastie.org/6571509

You can check my WIN Proc function here http://goo.gl/knJ4Z , line 346.

Create tab control:

```
ps_ext->d_handle = CreateWindowExW(0,                      // no extended styles           
                                       WC_TABCONTROL,          // class name                   
                                       L"",               // default text                  
                                       WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,  // overlapped window            
                                       CW_USEDEFAULT,          // default horizontal position  
                                       CW_USEDEFAULT,          // default vertical position    
                                       CW_USEDEFAULT,          // default width                
                                       CW_USEDEFAULT,          // default height               
                                       HWND_MESSAGE,            // no parent or owner window    
                                       (HMENU)WINSEM_Window_NextComponentID(),           // class menu used              
                                       WINSEM_Window_hInstance,// instance handle              
                                       (LPVOID)&ps_ext->s_window);          // no window creation data
```

After it, set correct parent by SetParent function call.
Tab is resized by something like:

```
  uFlags = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER;

  if (SetWindowPos(ps_window->d_handle, NULL, s0_x, s0_y, s0_w, s0_h, uFlags)==0)
  {
    DWORD dErr;

    dErr = GetLastError();

    HaveWinLastError_Error(ps_pack, WINSEM_WINDOW_fromerror_windowPos+0, dErr, dErr);        
    break;
  }
```

And showing window and clicking on tab control don't generate WM_NOTIFY message received by parent window winProc function.

This is my message receive code:

```
   bRet = PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

  if (bRet==FALSE)
  {
    // no messages received
  }
  else
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg); 
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
  }
```

Have anybody any idea about this problem? Thanks for you ideas and time.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308137/parent-less-button)?

Comment: It is really a wine bug.

Here is a link for bug example code. http://pastebin.com/YdFbZGxa
It work good on MS Window and bad in wine.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the tab control caches its parent window when it is created and never updates it. If you re-parent it, the messages will still go to the original parent - which is an invalid window in this case.

Why are you creating it with `HWND_MESSAGE` as a parent anyway? Why not just create it with its proper parent to begin with?

Comment: Hmm. It can be an problem.
I am writing this like win api module for some bigger library. It usually isn't know parent in creating time.

From yesterday eveing testing it looks like not a window problem but like wine problem only.

I will ask wine developer, if they know about it.

Thanks for you answer.