# Can't return nullpointer in Cpp function

Tags: c++, null-pointer

I am not able to return the nullptr at the end of this method? Is there some kind of library I need to import?

```
const char* strstr(const char* string1, const char* string2) {
    // TODO:
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(string2); j++) {
            if (string1[i] == string2[i]) {
                return &string1[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: What **exact** error are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able"? Do you get an error message? Does it crash? Does your boss slap you with a jellyfish if you try?

Comment: I actually don't know? I'm using eclipse and when I check build settings I have "g++"

Comment: OKAY FIXED added std=c++11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nullptr is a feature introduced in c++11, see: [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr). You'll need a compiler that supports at least some features of c++11.