# Condition checking: if(x==0) vs. if(!x)

Tags: c++

What's the differences of `if(x==0)` vs. `if(!x)`? Or are they always equivalent? And for different C++ build-in types of `x`:

- `bool`
- `int`
- `char`
- `pointer`
- `iostream`
- ...

Comment: That depends *greatly* on what `x` is...

Comment: nope the second one casts x to a bool type

Comment: It really depends on the type of `x`. I would expect them to be the **exact opposite** for well designed types.

Comment: Since C++ allows operator overloading, someone could have done horrible things to ! and !=.

Comment: It depends on what the != and ! operators for x are defeined as.

Comment: I _think_ you mean x==0 vs. !x, right?

Comment: OK, then the first part of my comment still applies. It depends on the type of `x`. For built-in types, it is the same.

Comment: @herohuyongtao, please stop creating fluffy generic meta tags like `[condition-checking]`.

Comment: This is not directly relevant, but in C they mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Charles Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is a conversion from a type to something that supports `if (x)` or `if (!x)`, then as long as there isn't a DIFFERENT conversion for `operator int()` than `opterator bool()`, the result will be the same.

`if (x == 0)` will use the "best" conversion, which includes a `bool` or `void *` converter. As long as there is any converter that can convert the type to some "standard type".

`if(!x)` will do exactly the same, it will use any converter that converts to a standard type.

Both of these of course assume the converter function isn't a C++11 "don't default convert".

Of course, if you have a class like this:

```
class
{
   int x;
  public:
   bool operator bool() { return x != 0; }
   int operator int() { return x == 0; } 
};
```

then `if (x == 0)` will do `if ( (x == 0) == 0)` and `if (!x)` will will do `if (! (x != 0)`, which isn't the same. But now we're really TRYING to make trouble, and this is VERY BADLY designed code.

Of course, the above example can be made to go wrong with any `operator int()` that doesn't result in `false` for `x == 0` and `true` for all other values.

Answer (score 2):

> if(!x)

is "if x is not false", that means that in order to evaluate that, you might have to cast x to a bool.

**>>** This can be harmful and if you wish to avoid it you should use something like the [Safe Bool Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool)

---

> if(x!=0)

means "if x is not 0", so that is evaluated comparing x to 0. That might also involve an implicit conversion.

**>>** Be careful when using pointers this way, C++11 introduces a **nullptr** to avoid the confusion of *NULL==0* (semantically different): [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Answer (score 1):

**Take into account what are you going to process**

If it is a *boolean*, the results are pretty clear:

```c
if (!false)   // If false TRUE
if (false==0) // If false TRUE
```

If it is an *integer*, pay attention to the `!` condition

```
if (0==0) // Unexpected behaviors are missing..

if (!-1) // False
if (! 0) // True
if (! 1) // False
```

For *chars* both conditions give me the same results:

```
if (! ' ')  // nothing
if (' '==0) // nothing

if (! 'z')  // nothing
if ('z'==0) // nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

No this all depends on the type of x. For example,

`if(cin)`

is used in the stl to check if an iostream type hasn't had an error. There is no equivalent cin != 0.

Besides most operators are overloadable and conversions too.

Comment: `if (cin != 0)` at least compiles for me; I think it has the same result as `if (cin)`. The operands are converted to a common type; I'm not sure of the details in this case.

Comment: Yes there can be multiple conversions, etc. That was a broad unchecked example - good catch though. I was just saying it has no operator int

Comment: Please discuss the differences on other C++ built-in types, see updated question. Thanks.

Comment: What @KeithThompson said. Once you provide an implicit conversion to `bool`, you open yourself to conversions from `bool` to other built-in types. C++11 explicit conversion operators were added to prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: broadly speaking, this is too broad, sorry. if(!x) converts x to a bool, if the class provides an operator bool - otherwise it does all manner of unspeakable witchcraft (google safe bool idiom). In the other case, it is converted to an int.

Comment: Just for the record, I had a look, and there was a `void*` conversion operator before C++11, and now there is an explicit bool operator.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **!x** will return true for every "false" value (i.e, 0, null, false, etc.) whereas **x!=0** will return true, iff x is not equal to **0**.

Comment: "empty string" I don't think it is true for C++, is it?

Comment: oops! I'm a c# guy. but still not sure. let me edit. anybody can is welcome to correct me please :)