# What is a reference-to-pointer?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I recently saw a function that is being declared as:

```
void func(type* &param);
```

I already know the difference between `type* param` and `type& param`. How does the above differ from them? And when to use this? Is it advisable to do this?

Comment: It's just same as `type& param`, and the type here is `type*`.

Answer (score 19):

The above will be able to modify not only the pointed object, but also the pointer in itself. As an example, consider the below code:

```
void func(int*& ptr) {
    *ptr = 1;
    ptr = 0;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int* y = &x;
    func(y);
}
```

At the end of the execution, `x` has value `1` and `y` is `0` (as you [can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32bbc7261de6ba56)).

Notice that for the sake of the example I've used `0` as a *null pointer*, but if you are using C++11 you [should probably use `nullptr` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) (which does not have an overloaded `operaror<<` for `std::ostream`).

---

This concept can possibly be assimilated by taking a look at the following code:

```
template<class Type> using ptr = Type*;
ptr<int>& x;
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<int>& x;
```

In these examples, `x` is a reference to a type (`ptr<int>` and then `std::unique_ptr<int>`), which just so happens to be a pointer/class with pointer semantic (`operator*` and `operator->`).

---

A possibly interesting digression can be made on the position of a `const` qualifier in the pointer. Consider these two instances:

1. `void func(const int*& ptr)`
2. `void func(int*const& ptr)`

Their meanings are:

1. *pointer by reference to a constant int*.
2. *pointer by constant reference to an int*.

And following the above analogy with `ptr` they would be:

1. `ptr<const int>&`
2. `ptr<int> const&`

Therefore the first will fail to execute `*ptr = 1` in the body of the function (because the `int` is constant), but will happily execute `ptr = 0`.

The second will behave conversely, allowing `*ptr = 1` (because the pointed int is not constant), while disallowing `ptr = 0` (because the pointer is constant).

Of course, in the case of:

```
void func(const int*const& ptr)
```

which in the `ptr` analogy would be `ptr<const int> const&`, both of them wouldn't be allowed.

---

> And when to use this? Is it advisable to do this?

Like every feature, you'll find its usefulness when you'll need it. But just as a general idea, some people used it to reset the pointer after freeing a dynamically allocated resource (I'm not recommending this, see below).

Let's take this example:

```
free_my_int(int*& ptr) {
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}

int* x = new int(42);
free_my_int(x);
```

At the end of the execution, `x` would be correctly freed and the pointer automatically set to [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) (null pointer). This was done to prevent ugly segmentation faults or "pointer freed has not been allocated" error messages caused by a missing `ptr = nullptr`.

But with C++11 and C++14 there is very little use of pointers and even less of reference to pointers. Most of the things pointers where used for are not replaced with other standard construct (see [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) for example).

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare all three options:

- `void func(type*  param); // 'param' is a 'type*' variable`
- `void func(type&  param); // 'param' is a reference to a 'type' variable`
- `void func(type*& param); // 'param' is a reference to a 'type*' variable`

---

```
void func(type* param)
{
    type x;
    ...
    param = &x;
    // Argument 'param' is regarded as a local variable in this function,
    // so setting 'param = ...' will have no effect outside this function
}
```

Of course, if you do `*param = ...`, then it **will** effect the contents of the memory pointed by `param`. And you can also do `param[5] = ...` for example, and effect other areas within that memory space.

---

```
void func(type& param)
{
    type x;
    ...
    param = x;
    // Argument 'param' is regarded as a reference to a variable outside this
    // function, so setting 'param = ...' will effect the referenced variable
}
```

Here, you will only change **the referenced variable itself**, so it's safer than declaring the function as `void func(type* param)`, and then pass the address of `type param` by calling `func(&param)`.

---

```
void func(type*& param)
{
    type x;
    ...
    param = &x;
    // Argument 'param' is regarded as a reference to a variable outside this
    // function, so setting 'param = ...' will effect the referenced variable
}
```

This is similar to declaring the function as `void func(type** param)`, and then pass the address of `type* param` by calling `func(&param)`, but again, it is safer for the same reason mentioned above.

---