# C++ AVLTree Rotation

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I'm trying to do a `LeftRotation` with my AVLTree. I'll insert 3, 5, and then 10 so it becomes a degenerate tree. When I traverse it'll give me `3, 5, 10` but when I do the rotation I just get `5, 10` instead of the expected `5, 3, 10`.

It's something to do with setting `a` as `b`'s `left` branch. I will step through it and the root of my tree will be `5`, the left will be `3`, and the right will be `10`, but when I go to traverse it shows the left side as being `null`.

Here is my rotation code:

```
void AVLTree::RotateLeft(Node *root)
{
    Node a = *root;
    Node b = *root->GetRight();
    *root = b;
    a.SetRight(b.GetLeft());
    b.SetLeft(&a); //This is where the problem occurs
}
```

And my `Traversal` code:

```
void AVLTree::Traverse(Node *node)
{
    cout << node->GetValue() << ", ";
    if (node->GetLeft() != nullptr)
        Traverse(node->GetLeft());
    if (node->GetRight() != nullptr)
        Traverse(node->GetRight());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: changed all `0`'s to `nullptr`, thanks for the correction!

Comment: As long as the C++11 standard is used, please use `nullptr`.  For more details: [What exactly is nullptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr).  If not, then it is much better to use the `NULL` macro.  It is highly likely comparing pointers to zero will cost points.

Comment: It seems that you want to do `b.SetLeft(a)`, not `&a`. `SetLeft` takes a `Node`, not a `Node*`. If possible, you should also exchange all `Node*` for `Node&` in your program, because you are using pointers as if they were references...

Comment: @cplusplusooaand  It hasn't, but thank you for the `nullptr` tip

Comment: @user3280133 I have posted one solution.  Keep in mind that additional testing and debugging will be necessary for the other functions.  It should help resolve it and obtain the balanced tree for one side.  Please review the references too.  I always find sources in addition to what is at hand to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with how `root` is moved to point to a new location.    If there are doubts about that, consider the following two statements.  Note that the variable naming convention from the original code above is used for consistency.

```
*root = b; // (1)
root = &b; // (2)
```

In `(1)`, the contents of the root pointer are modified to contain the value stored in the `b` variable.  The address of `root` has not been modified in any way.  The address `root` has prior to `(1)` executing remains unchanged after `(1)` is finished.

In `(2)`, `root` is now pointing to the address of the `b` variable.  Because the address where `root` is pointing has been modified, the contents of the `root` pointer now equal the value in the `b` variable.

I strongly recommend stepping through the `void AVLTree::RotateLeft(Node *root)` function line by line and inspecting all variables' addresses and contents to see this first hand.  I have performed a simulation of the above actions on sample integer data and pointers moved around as expected using `(2)`.

Before the rotation occurs on the sample data, it is expected that the unbalanced tree should be arranged such that the `3` node is pointed to by `root`.  Then `root->right` points to `5`, and the `root->right->right` points to `10`.  The `root->right->left` should be `nullptr`, and the `root->left` should also be `nullptr`.

If this not the case, then either the AVL insertion algorithm is implemented incorrectly or the design requirements are different than expected (e.g. [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) on Wikipedia, [Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ (3rd Edition) [Hardcover]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032144146X) by Mark Allen Weiss, [AVL Tree Tutorial on Eternally Confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_avl.aspx) by Julienne Walker).

Regarding the movement of balancing the tree, where the end result is `root` points to `5`, the `root->left` points to `3` and `root->right` points to `10`, the right pointer of the passed in `root` pointer will be set to point to the left pointer of the local `pB` pointer (see below), the left pointer of `pB` will point to the passed in `root` pointer, and `root` will be set to point to the local variable `pB` (originally set to the `root->right` pointer in this case).

Using the sample data above, the body of the function is modified.  Note that this is not consistent with how `GetRight()` and `GetLeft()` appear to return a Node copy in the original post above.  The modified function body below is consistent with the `single AVL rotation with right child` implemented by Mark Allen Weiss referenced above.  Since the original post does not have a height variable, the code below does not either.

```
//
// The `root` variable is passed as a pointer by reference
//
void AVLTree::RotateLeft(Node* & root)
{
    //
    // This works as long as the GetRight() method returns a pointer, not a Node copy
    //
    Node *pB = root->GetRight();

    //
    // In the example values for three nodes, the root->right will become nullptr
    //
    root->SetRight(pB->GetLeft());

    //
    // In the example values, the pB->left will point to the node with value of 3
    //
    pB->SetLeft(root);

    //
    // Move root to point to where pB does (root->right)
    //
    root = pB;
}
```