# Having trouble with a string. Debug is claiming "bad pointer"

Tags: c++, string, error-code

I'm writing a program that acts as a number system converter and haven't even made it to the fun math and number values part before screwing up.

At the very end I declared a string "value_array" and it is has a "bad ptr" note on it when I step through the program. This is impeding me from moving on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Initialization:
int base = 0;
int target = 0;
int i = 0;

//Won't exit until the user inputs a viable number for a base (between 1 and 16 inclusively).
for (i = 0; i < 1; i += 0)
{
    cout << "Enter the base number system: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << endl;

    if (base>=2 && base<=16)
    {
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
    }
}


//Same as before but makes sure the target is a valid number.

for (i = 0; i < 1; i += 0)
{
    cout << "Enter the target number system: ";
    cin >> target;
    cout << endl;

    if (target>=2 && target<=16)
    {
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
    }
}

string value_array = ""; //editted

cout << "Enter value in base (with no spaces): ";
cin >> value_array; //editted 

//int k = basevalue(value_array,base);//Please disregard. Can't use this function until the strings are usable.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *have* use `std::cin` and the input operator `>>` before, what makes you think it's different with a `std::string` object like `value_array`? You can use `std::cin >> value_array;` just like you did e.g. `std::cin >> target;` earlier in the program.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. I get "no operator '>>' meets these operands"

Comment: If you get build errors, please include hem in your question, *complete* and *unedited*.

Comment: I apologize. I figured I was just doing it wrong

Comment: Oh, and you seem to have *two* different problems, one is the compilation error and one is the crash/abnormal exit. You should concentrate on one problem here in this question, and ask another question for the other problem.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::cin` on `value_array`, but first remove constness. You can't modify `const string`.

#### Edit

You have to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Ok I removed the const but the ">>" is still showing an error.

Comment: "No operator '>>' matches these operands"

Comment: @rynoclank That error usually comes with more information, please *edit your question* to include the *complete* error output.

Comment: @rynoclank Could you add full output in your question?

Comment: That's what it what it was. Thanks so much @Alvarey! I'll update the question. Any idea about why value_array has the "bad ptr" on it when I step through the program?

Comment: @rynoclank No problem. I have no idea why you get `bad ptr` in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experience is caused by the constness by `value_array`. You declared it `const` which means that it cannot be modified by anything (it is read-only) during it's lifetime. Thus when you try to assign a string obtained from user input to it, compiler informs you that it is impossible. Everything works fine after removal of the `const` keyword.

It's hard to say what is the exact reason of the *bad pointer* error you experience. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802466/what-are-bad-ptr-mean-in-visual-c) it can be caused by inappropriate usage of raw pointers. If you use them somewhere after the above code, make sure any of them is `NULL`, `nullptr` nor `0` when used.

---

I modified your code a little bit and added a few comments, I hope they will  be useful during development of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Initialization:
    int base = 0;
    int target = 0;

    //PiotrSliwa: The loop can be removed with if-statement modified like below
    cout << "Enter the base number system: ";
    cin >> base;
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n'); // PiotrSliwa: ignore up to 1024 characters or until newline is found in order to avoid bugs caused by more-than-required user input characters
    cout << endl;

    if (base<2 || base>16)
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //PiotrSliwa: The loop can be removed with if-statement modified like below
    cout << "Enter the target number system: ";
    cin >> target;
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    cout << endl;

    if (target<2 && target>16)
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    string value_array = ""; //PiotrSliwa: removed 'const' from string which caused an error
    cout << "Enter value in base (with no spaces): ";
    cin >> value_array; //PiotrSliwa: The simplest method of obtaining user input and redirecting it to 'string' variable
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');

    //int k = basevalue(value_array,base);//Please disregard. Can't use this function until the strings are usable.

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://cpp.sh/9uev)

---

Also, consider enclosing functionalities into functions (or objects) to avoid code duplications as well as to provide reusable code and improve readability. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T getUserInput(string message)
{
    cout << message;
    T input;
    cin >> input;
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
    cout << endl;
    return input;
}

bool isValidNumberSystem(int numberSystem)
{
    return numberSystem>=2 && numberSystem<=16;
}

int main()
{
    int base = getUserInput<int>("Enter the base number system: ");
    if (!isValidNumberSystem(base))
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int target = getUserInput<int>("Enter the target number system: ");
    if (!isValidNumberSystem(target))
    {
        cout << "Invalid value. Please input a value between 1 and 16 inclusively." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    string value_array = getUserInput<string>("Enter value in base (with no spaces): ");

    //int k = basevalue(value_array,base);//Please disregard. Can't use this function until the strings are usable.

    return 0;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://cpp.sh/66xw)