# Can a preexisting return of a typecast NULL be safely compared to a newer nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, null, nullptr

I am required to use a library which was written before C++11, and one of the functions can return a typecast NULL. I'm trying to write my program following C++11 standards, so when protecting against a null reference, i would use something like:

```
if(retPtr==nullptr){...}
```

Is this a safe comparison? for arguments sake say between (int*)NULL and (int*)nullptr?
or should i just use an:

```
if(retPtr){...}?
```

Comment: The two statements that you've shown do opposite things - the equivalent of `if(retPtr==nullptr)` is `if(!retPtr)`

Comment: very true, those were just examples of course. thank you though :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a preexisting return of a typecast `NULL` be safely compared to a
>   newer `nullptr`?

**Yes.** From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr):

> There exist implicit conversions from `nullptr` to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type. Similar conversions exist for any value of type `std::nullptr_t` as well as for the macro `NULL`, the null pointer constant.

As [Praetorian kindly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123566/can-a-preexisting-return-of-a-typecast-null-be-safely-compared-to-a-newer-nullpt/24124147#comment37219530_24124147), the corresponding section of the standard is **4.10 [conv.ptr]**.

See also [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282295/341970)

Comment: And the standard reference is 4.10 [conv.ptr]

Comment: @Praetorian FYI cppreference wiki has a [ref std...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:ref_std_c%2B%2B11) template, so you can add c++ standart reference to the pages :) Updated version: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr