# C++ can not store pointer in structure

Tags: c++, qt

First off, I'm new to c++. If there's a better way to do this then a structure, please mention it.

So what I'm trying to do is create a structure to store pointers to some custom objects. The reason for this is instead of having to pass many pointers of parameters, I can declare this structure and pass the structure to the function that needs this group of objects.

The reason for all the objects is I am doing repative interactions with web services. I have made a class to simplify the interactions with the web services and do not wish to destroy and recreate them every time I need them.

Note: This is being done in Qt 5

This is in the header:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyClass* Class1;
    MyClass* Class2;
    MyClass* Class3;
    MyClass* Class4;
};
```

Now this is a snip of how I'm trying to fill in the structure:

```
//Stucture of commonly used objects, for all to access
MyStruct* theStruct;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //Build object
    MyClass* firstClass = new MyClass(/*params for object*/);
    theStruct->Class1 = firstClass;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(firstclass, SIGNAL(dataReady()),this,SLOT(updateWebStats(MyStruct)));
}
```

And now the error I am getting:

App output:

> Starting MyExe.exe
>   Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to

launch the process directly:

> The program has unexpectedly finished. 
>   MyExe.exe crashed

When I debug I get a popup

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

At this time the debugger is at this line, in the mainwindow constructor:

```
theStruct->Class1 = firstClass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with the idea of using globals to make life easier. [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

But here is your error.

`theStruct`, must also be initialized.

If it is a static member, you should set it to zero.

And it is good practice to set the pointers for your classes to zero, too.

```
struct theStruct
{
    // default constructor
    theStruct() : Class1(0), Class2(0), Class3(0), Class4(0) {}
    MyClass* Class1;
    MyClass* Class2;
    MyClass* Class3;
    MyClass* Class4;
};
```

Then at time of access, you should check to make sure it is initialized with:

```
if(theStruct && theStruct->Class1)
    theStruct->Class1->foo();
```

The ordering of the above if statement does the following:  if theStruct is not zero aka, has had `new` called and is a valid pointer, and if Class1 in theStruct is not zero (also has had `new` called on it), then use it because it is safe and available.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually it's better practice to set your pointers to `nullptr` -> [Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: That's actually a lot of good information for a c++ newbie, also the part where is was declared globally is actually a copy paste error, its local to the MainWindow constructor. I just pass the structure around instead of having a parameter list thats 10+ elements long.

Comment: The difference between a struct and a class is only that by default everything in a `class` is `private`, and everything by default in a `struct` is `public`.  Using a `struct` to hold a bunch of common settings or elements is a great way to do it.  Qt also supports passing something like this around using signals and slots, but you have to register the custom types.

Comment: @deW1, good point, but it requires use of C++11.  I'm still using MSVC 2010 most of the time lately.  For those with modern compilers, you can use `CONFIG += c++11` in Qt .pro file to enable use of `nullptr` instead of `0` for your pointers.

Comment: @phyatt Funny you mention the slots and signals thing, just ran into QObject::connect: No such slot, MainWindow::updateWebStats(engines). I have this slot listed in the header and implemented in the cpp file, would not regestering my structure then passing it to a slot cause this problem?

Comment: use `qRegisterMetaType<myStruct>("myStruct");` in your main.cpp or in MainWindow constructor. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType

Comment: Ended up needing to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myStruct) but you put me on the right track, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access an unassigned pointer which results in a segmentation fault.

Try initialize it:

```
MyStruct* theStruct = new MyStruct();
```

Comment: Yea this was the problem, thanks. New to c++ and didn't realize structures are constructed like classes, thought they only needed a type. I would vote you up but it won't let me

Comment: Neither structures nor classes need to be initialized with `new`, and you should not do so unless you have a compelling reason for it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no reason to use a pointer to `MyStruct` in your example. You should not be using one unless you have some compelling reason to do so, which does not appear to be the case. If you don't use a pointer, you don't need to initialize it in your code with `new`. It is automatically intialized at compile time, by way of your declaration and definition.

```
MyStruct theStruct;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //Build object
    MyClass* firstClass = new MyClass(/*params for object*/);
    theStruct.Class1 = firstClass;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(firstclass, SIGNAL(dataReady()),this,SLOT(updateWebStats(&MyStruct)));
}
```

See [***Resource Acquisition Is Initialization***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for starters. Far too many programmers automatically use pointers in C++ when they are not necesssary at all. Only use pointers when you absolutely need them, and in C++11 use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` whenever possible.

**Do not confuse C++ with languages like Java, Delphi, or C#, which require you to allocate classes on the free store and access them only with references/pointers. In C++ you can and *should* declare stack based variables for `class` and `struct` objects.**

> ***If there's a better way to do this then a structure, please mention it.***

`std::vector<MyClass*>` might be preferable. See:  [***std::vector***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> std::vector is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size
>   arrays.
>
> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular
>   pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a
>   vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an
>   element of an array....