# Build failure when transitioning from OSX platforms and using gcc and llvm

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I have inherited a fairly large and complex software package written in both C and C++ which successfully builds on Mac OSX Lion using gcc:

```
$> gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I have been tasked with getting this same package to build on OSX Mavericks using the default Mac compiler that comes with Command Line Tools.

```
$> gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

The OSX Lion build finishes to completion but the OSX Mavericks build fails with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_MRIsetVoxVal", referenced from ...
```

I have traced source of the error to a header file with the following code block:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
float  MRIgetVoxVal( const MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f);
int    MRIsetVoxVal(MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f, float voxval);
void   MRIdbl2ptr(double v, void *pmric, int mritype);
double MRIptr2dbl(void *pmric, int mritype);
#else
inline float  MRIgetVoxVal(const MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f);
inline int    MRIsetVoxVal(MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f, float voxval);
inline void   MRIdbl2ptr(double v, void *pmric, int mritype);
inline double MRIptr2dbl(void *pmric, int mritype);
#endif
```

If I modify the above code block by simply removing the `if else` and `inline` statements so that it looks like the following, then the build finishes to completion on both platforms:

```
float  MRIgetVoxVal( const MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f);
int    MRIsetVoxVal(MRI *mri, int c, int r, int s, int f, float voxval);
void   MRIdbl2ptr(double v, void *pmric, int mritype);
double MRIptr2dbl(void *pmric, int mritype);
```

So it appears that on OSX Lion, the `ifdef __cplusplus` statement is triggered which produces the desired behavior. And on Mavericks the `else` statement is triggered which ultimately results in a error.

Pardon me if this is a very basic question, but C and C++ are outside my area of expertise. What is going on here? What does `#ifdef __cplusplus` even mean, and why does one version of gcc get triggered by it and the other does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the compiler proper steps in, the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) performs a number of tasks. Lines beginning with a hash ('#') are preprocessor directives, and include tasks such as file inclusion (`#include <stdio.h>`), macro variable definition (`#define DEBUG 1`), macro function definition (`#define LENGTH(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(0[array]))`), and conditional compilation (`#if ... #endif`), as seen in your code fragment.

Macros allow source code to be rewritten at compile time by replacing the macro name with its value. They're an early way of achieving a number of tasks, but don't by and large respect C/C++ syntax and have thus been replaced in a number of ways by (e.g.) the `inline` specifier, templates, [trait](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442) classes and [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282295/90527), which better respect syntax & semantics.

Some macros are defined in headers (see "limits.h", replaced in C++ by `numeric_limits`, for some examples). Others are defined by the preprocessor; `__cplusplus` is one of these, which should be defined when the compiler is processing a C++ file (as determined by the file extension or possibly command-line arguments, such as GCC's '-x'). You can direct gcc to list macros by using the '-dD' or '-dM' options (as mentioned in the gcc [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) page and [online docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)), along with the '-E' option to stop after preprocessing. Nadeau Software Consulting posted a tip on how to list [predefined macros](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros) for various compilers. According to it, clang should accept the same arguments as gcc, so try the following on Mavericks:

```
gcc -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | less
```

`__cplusplus` is required by the C++ standards (§ 16.8 1 in C++11). One big difference between the Lion and Mavericks builds of gcc is the latter uses the clang frontend while the former uses GCC. A web search for "clang __cplusplus" suggests that clang should support it, so if `__cplusplus` isn't being defined, then clang is likely compiling the file as C. You can try the '-x c++' option to force C++. You could also try the '-std=gnu++11' option, though I suspect it won't make a difference here, as it's designed to support non-standard [Gnu C++ extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) rather than providing full GCC compatibility.