# setenv, and getenv documentation

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables, system-calls

I know this is a bit off topic for what is suppose to be posted on stack overflow but wanted to know if these examples are well done.

### setenv:

[man page - setenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv)

**includes:** `#include <stdlib.h>`

**declaration:** `int setenv(const char *v_name, const char *v_value, int overwrite);`

**returns:** If successful returns zero, otherwise returns -1, with errno set to indicate the cause of the error.

### getenv:

[man page - getenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv)

**includes:** `#include <stdlib.h>`

**declaration:** `char *getenv(const char *name)`

**returns:**  If successful returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL if there is no match.

### Examples

`char *ppath` is used as a variable in the following examples.

Example 1: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a non-zero and `v_name` has a value.

```
ppath = getenv("PWD");                  //puts the environment of $PWD into ppath
if(ppath == NULL)                       //error checking
  perror("getenv");   
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;     //prints the environment of $PWD
```

Output of this code is `$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100` this is because the char variable `ppath` is getting the
environment from `getenv("PWD")` and the environment of `$PWD` is `/class/classes/username/CS100`. Therefore `ppath` points to that
environment. There is also proper error checking to make sure that `$PWD` has a environment and if it does not `perror`
is called.

```
ppath = getenv("HOME");                 //gets the environment of the $HOME
if(ppath == NULL)                       //error checking
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$HOME = " << ppath << endl;    //prints the environment of $PWD
```

Output of this code is `$HOME = /class/classes/username` this is because the char variable `ppath` is getting the
environment from `getenv("HOME")` and the environment of `$HOME` is `/class/classes/username`. Therefore `ppath` points to that
environment. There is also proper error checking to make sure that `$HOME` has a environment and if it does not `perror`
is called.

```
if(-1==setenv("PWD",ppath,1))           //since the overwrite parameter is non-zero it replaces environment 
  perror("setenv");                     //of $PWD with the value of ppath which is defined by the environment 
                                        //of $HOME
```

This is to change the environment of `$PWD` in this case it take the value that the `ppath` is pointing to which in this case is `/class/classes/username` which is also `$HOME`. The `overwrite` parameter is non-zero, so it replaces the environment of `$PWD` to `ppath`

```
ppath = getenv("PWD");                  //gets the environment of $PWD
if(ppath == NULL)                       //error checking
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;     //the value should now be the same as the value of $HOME
```

Output of this code is `$PWD = /class/classes/username` this is because the char variable `ppath` is getting the
environment from `getenv("PWD")` and the environment of `$PWD` is `/class/classes/username`. Therefore `ppath` points to that
environment. There is also proper error checking to make sure that `$PWD` has a environment and if it does not `perror`
is called. The full output of example 1 is as follows.

Output 1:

```
$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100
$HOME = /class/classes/username
$PWD = /class/classes/username
```

Example 2: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a non-zero and `v_name` has a blank value as in `v_name = ""` so an empty string.

```
ppath = getenv("PWD");                  
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath  << endl;    //in this case ppath ="" because the environment of $PWD is not set
```

Output of the following code will be `$PWD =`  this is because the environment of `$PWD` is set to `""` in this case, it makes the `ppath` point to an empty string. Hence the reason it does not throw an error, however if `$PWD` was an undefined variable then `perror` is called.

```
ppath = getenv("HOME"); 
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$HOME = " << ppath << endl;
```

Output: of this code is `$HOME = /class/classes/username` this is because the char variable `ppath` is getting the
environment from `getenv("HOME")` and the environment of `$HOME` is `/class/classes/username`. Therefore `ppath` points to that
environment. There is also proper error checking to make sure that `$HOME` has an environment and if it does not `perror`
is called.

```
if(-1==setenv("PWD",ppath,1))           //since the overwrite parameter is non-zero it replaces environment 
  perror("setenv");                     //of $PWD with the value of ppath which is defined by the environment 
                                        //of $HOME
```

Since the `overwrite` parameter is 1 it does not matter what the `$PWD` it is set to `ppath` as defined in the earlier example.

```
ppath = getenv("PWD");                  
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");  
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;     //the value should now be the same as the value of $HOME
```

The output of the following code is `$PWD = /class/classes/username` this is because `setenv` changed the value of `$PWD` as defined in the past code block, to `ppath`.

Output 2:

```
$PWD =
$HOME = /class/classes/username
$PWD = /class/classes/username
```

Example 3: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a zero and v_name does have a value.

```
ppath = getenv("PWD"); 
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;
```

In this case `ppath` is set to the environment of `$PWD`. The output of this code block is
`$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100`.

```
ppath = getenv("HOME"); 
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$HOME = " << ppath << endl;
```

In this code block `ppath` is set to the environment of `$HOME`. The output of the following code block will be
`$HOME = /class/classes/username`.

```
if(-1==setenv("PWD",ppath,0))           //since the overwrite parameter is zero it does not replaces  
  perror("setenv");                     //environment of $PWD with ppath.
```

Here there is a new case where the `overwrite` parameter is zero. In this case it does not matter what `ppath` is because the
zero flag makes it so that the `$PWD` is not replaced by the `ppath`, unless `$PWD` was a undefined variable, in which case
`$PWD` would be given the value of `ppath`.

```
ppath = getenv("PWD");                
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;     //the value should not be changed.
```

The output of this code block is `$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100`. This is because `setenv` did not change the
environment of `$PWD` because of the `overwrite` parameter.

Output 3:

```
$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100
$HOME = /class/classes/username
$PWD = /class/classes/username/CS100
```

Example 4: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a zero *or* a non-zero and `v_name` is a parameter that is not defined in the environment.

```
ppath = getenv("HOME"); 
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$HOME = " << ppath << endl;
```

In this case ppath is given the environment of `$HOME`, there is also proper error checking done. The output of the code
block is `$HOME = /class/classes/username`.

```
if(-1==setenv("random_name",ppath,0))   //since the overwrite parameter is zero and the variable     
perror("setenv");                       //$random_name is undefined, setenv makes the environment of 
                                        //$random_variable is the value of ppath. If the case where
                                        //there is a undefined variable the setenv behaves the
                                        //same way regardless of a non-zero or zero overwrites parameter.
```

In this case the `overwrite` parameter is still zero, but the `v_name` is not declared so this is where the `overwrite` parameter of zero is helpful. In this case `random_name` is set to `ppath` which is pointing to the environment of `$HOME` which is `/class/classes/username`.

```
ppath = getenv("random_name");                  //gets the value of $PWD
if(ppath == NULL)
  perror("getenv");
cout << "$random_name = " << ppath << endl;     //the value should now be the same as the value of $HOME
```

The `ppath` is contains the environment of `$random_name` which is set by the `setenv` in the previous code block. The output
of this code block is     `$random_name = /class/classes/username`

Output 4:

```
$HOME = /class/classes/username
$random_name = /class/classes/username
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documentation for setenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655943/documentation-for-setenv)

Comment: I've already addressed some of that in your [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30655943/207421). You don't seem to have taken much notice.

Comment: Actually as you can notice the two posts have very different documentation as there is no description in this one just examples, and description of examples.

Comment: If you've provided a link to the real documentation you don't need to repeat any of it, but otherwise you should certainly provide documentation for all the arguments. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are using C++; you can declare variables easily as you write.  Indeed, both C99 and C11 also allow you to declare variables when they're used.

#### Example 1

> Example 1: This example shows what happens when the overwrite parameter is a non-zero and v_name has a value.

Actually, it is very hard to spot the code in Example 1 that has anything to do with the `overwrite` parameter.

> ```
> ppath = getenv("PWD");                  //puts the environment of $PWD into ppath
> if(ppath == NULL)                       //error checking
>   perror("getenv");   
> cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;     //prints the environment of $PWD
> ```

You shouldn't use `ppath` when you've established that it is NULL; this is a pervasive problem.  And these days, shouldn't you use [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr) since this is C++?  I think this could be:

```
const char *ppath = getenv("PWD");
if (ppath == nullptr)
    perror("getenv");   
else
    cout << "$PWD = " << ppath << endl;
```

If you state that you're coding for backwards compatibility, I've no major problem with using NULL or `0` instead of `nullptr`.

In fact, you have the almost identical block of code three times; you need to write a function:

```
void show_env(const char *varname)
{
    const char *ppath = getenv(varname);
    if (ppath == nullptr)
        perror("getenv");   
    else
        cout << "$" << varname << " = " << ppath << endl;
}
```

This is a direct transliteration of the original code.  It also shows why `perror()` is a bad function; it is hard to make the error message meaningful (it won't include the variable name).  Add to that the fact that the POSIX specification for [`getenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html) does not specify that `errno` is set by `getenv()`, and we should revise the code to:

```
void show_env(const char *varname)
{
    const char *ppath = getenv(varname);
    if (ppath == nullptr)
        cerr << "No value in the environment for $" << varname << endl;   
    else
        cout << "$" << varname << " = " << ppath << endl;
}
```

You can then call:

```
show_env("PWD");
show_env("HOME");
…code using setenv()…
show_env("PWD");
```

Etc.  I'm not convinced that the code referencing `$HOME` is relevant; you really don't use it.

Personally, I dislike (intensely) the back-to-front comparison style you use in the code for `setenv()`.  When Yoda I want like to speak…

Note that setting the environment variable `$PWD` alone does not change the current working directory.

#### Example 2

Your example 2 does not clearly show the `v_name` set to an empty string.  However, that is a case covered by the POSIX specification for [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html).  This time, an error is defined (`errno` will be set to `EINVAL`).

There is so much repeated code, again, it is hard to spot what's interesting.

#### Example 3

You say:

> Example 3: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a zero and `v_name` does have a value.

I think you mean:

> Example 3: This example shows what happens when the `overwrite` parameter is a zero and the environment variable identified by `v_name` does have a value.

This is probably applicable previously, too.

#### Example 4

You say:

> ```
> ppath = getenv("random_name");                  //gets the value of $PWD
> ```

The comment doesn't match the code.

#### Style on SO

You should make a heading for each example with `###` as the line prefix.  You might or might not have a super-heading `## Examples`.  You might mimic the style of a manual page for the function outline, or you might simply omit everything except the synopsis, referring to where the function behaviour is defined.

As written, it is extremely hard to find the 4 examples (it was only late in the process of answering that I realized there *were* four examples rather than three).  You have a lot of repetition.  You also have a good deal of noise (the code referencing `$HOME` is basically noise.