# pointer to class vs pointer to builtin types

Tags: c++

after declaration the pointer to int is not NULL whereas a pointer to class is NULL.

```
int *pint;
MyClass *Myob;
if (pint){
    cout << "pint is not null";
}
if (!Myob){
    cout << "Myob is null";
}
```

Why aren't pointers to Built in types and pointers to classes behaving the same way?

Comment: Their behavior should be undefined. You didn't initialize your pointers. This also isn't python. Objects (or pointers for that matter), by default, will not be 'false' is they're null (or nullptr in this case). They won't be anything.

Comment: Increase warning level of your compiler and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: In C++ you can use smart pointers and avoid a lot of problems. Use these instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the pointer to both the in-built and as well as class type have indeterminate value and will lead to undefined behavior. In C or C++, if you write

```
int a;
```

or

```
int *b;
MyClass *c;
```

then a, b, c will have indeterminate value (or garbage value). If you want to initialize them as `nullptr` then you can declare them `static` (not a good approach) or initialize them explicitly as `int a = 10` or `int *b = nullptr`.

You should always initialize pointers to `NULL` or `nullptr` (if your compiler supports C++11, assigning NULL to pointers is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1282295/5006740)).

Comment: You should always initialize pointers (and other variables). Sometimes `nullptr` is the appropriate initializer; other times it is not.