# Can't manage to create an Instance of a Class on the Heap. (c++)

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory

I'm currently doing a task in a book but I seem to struggle with creating an Instance. I'll give you the quick version of my code.
Also, I'm new here, therfore I'm sorry in advance for any errors in etiquette.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CShip
{
private:
int m_xPos;
int m_yPos;
int m_Energy;

public:
CShip();
}

// Constructor

CShip::CShip
{
m_xPos = 0;
m_yPos = 0;
m_Energy = 0;
}

int main()
{
// Pointer for the object
CShip *pPlayer = NULL;

// Create Instance on the Heap
// My problem: "Player" is marked as an error...';' was expected but every semicolon was set
pPlayer = new CShip Player;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pPlayer = new CShip Player;` should be `pPlayer = new CShip;` With that said I am sure what you wanted with the use of `Player` since `Player` is not defined in the code above.

Comment: By the way there's no reason here to separate the declaration of the pointer and the initialization. Also since C++11 `nullptr` should be preferred over `NULL`

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much. Yeah, it makes more sense to me now.

And I suppose, I'm using a rather outdated book then because I was tought to initialize a pointer with NULL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr