# Does std::malloc return NULL or nullptr on failure

Tags: c++, malloc

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc std::malloc returns a null ptr on failure

Is that a NULL pointer or a nullptr?

If it is nullptr, that implies there is a difference between std::malloc and the C malloc. Then the other question that follows, in that case, are there any other differences?

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate as suggested in the comment. That explains what a nullptr is, clearly says they are different. The question is not asking about the difference between them.

Comment: There is no difference between `NULL` and `nullptr` *in this context*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr)

Comment: @Fatih, I appreciate your comment. However, it leaves us with more question. Why, who decides, ...

Comment: @Makketronix, who decides on what? `NULL` being equivalent with `nullptr` in terms of being the value of a pointer returned from a function? I'm going to say the standardization committee in that case

Comment: @Fatih, of course the committee decides... anyway, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `NULL`. From the N4296 draft of the C++ standard:

> ## 20.7.13 C library [c.malloc]
>
> 1. Table 45 describes the header `<cstdlib>`.
>
>    Table 45 — Header `<cstdlib>` synopsis:
>
>    ```
>    +------------+---------------+
>    | Type       | Name(s)       |
>    +------------+---------------+
>    | Functions:   calloc malloc |
>    |              free realloc  |
>    +----------------------------+
>    ```
> 2. The contents are the same as the Standard C library header 11, with the following changes:
> 3. The functions `calloc()`, `malloc()`, and `realloc()` do not attempt to allocate storage by calling `::operator new()` (18.6).
> 4. The function `free()` does not attempt to deallocate storage by calling `::operator delete()`.
> 5. Storage allocated directly with `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` is implicitly declared reachable (see 3.7.4.3) on allocation, ceases to be declared reachable on deallocation, and need not cease to be declared reachable as the result of an `undeclare_reachable()` call.

As you can see, the C++ standard delegates to the C standard for the definition of `malloc`, and places no further restrictions on its return value or type. Since C has `NULL` but not `nullptr`, we can safely say that `malloc` returns `NULL`.

But all of this is moot since `NULL == nullptr` is always true, since they are both "null pointer constants" (a term which is clearly defined in 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]). The two are equivalent.

Comment: if I could, I would've given more, for showing the N4296. Teach a man how to fish...

Comment: @Makketronix Left sidebar right below the logo you will find a link to the current standard draft: https://isocpp.org/ Come to think of it, there's a lot of cool stuff at that site.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

The return type is `std::malloc` is `void*`. The return value of allocation failure is **the null pointer value of type `void*`**.

`NULL` is a pre-processor macro. A macro by itself has no type or value. This macro may be defined to be `nullptr` or `0`. So we can't really say `std::malloc` return `NULL`. We can say it returns something equals to the value convertible from the value resolved from `NULL`.

Although `nullptr` is a "null pointer literal", it is not a pointer by itself. Its type is not traditional pointer type. Its type is, curiously, `decltype(nullptr)`, which is not the return type of `std::malloc`. So `std::malloc` does not return `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

`std::malloc` returns, first and foremost, a pointer. `nullptr` *is not a pointer* (that is literally the whole point of it). Therefore, `std::malloc` cannot return `nullptr`.

On failure, `std::malloc` will return a pointer value which is defined to be the "null pointer constant". `nullptr` is a non-pointer type that is implicitly convertible to the "null pointer constant", and is equality-comparable to any pointer value (returning equals if the pointer value is the "null pointer constant").

So if you test the return value against `nullptr`, it will test true if and only if `std::malloc` failed.

The macro `NULL` results ([for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)) in the integer literal 0 (note: it can also result in `nullptr`, but pretty much no implementation does so). By C++'s rules, the integer literal 0 is implicit convertible to the null pointer constant, and is comparable to any pointer value (resulting in equals if the pointer value is the "null pointer constant").

So if you test the return value against `NULL`, it will test true if and only if `std::malloc` failed.

Comment: Ok, so malloc fails. What is the value of the register EAX/ RAX? Would that be 0, or would that be a memory location?

Comment: @Makketronix: The value is the "null pointer constant", as defined by the implementation. What value the implementation gives this value is not defined by the standard. But most platforms do pick a value that converts to a `uintptr_t` value of 0.