# A nullptr or the nullptr

Tags: c++, null, language-lawyer

If I am talking about [`nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr), is the correct terminology **the** `nullptr` (there is only one, and all mentions are references to the same thing), or **a** `nullptr` (there are several identical things).

That is, should function documentation say

> If *ptr* is the `nullptr`, the function uses an internal buffer...

or

> If *ptr* is a `nullptr`, the function uses an internal buffer...

(Pedantically, this is not an opinion based question, because it can be answered by reference to what *exactly* `nullptr` is)

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md seems to *mostly* use no article at all, which I find consistent with saying "x is 5" or "x is true". However, after reading a bit more, I found a few occurrences of "the nullptr".

Comment: I use "the nullptr" only when that phrasing gives insight to the problem domain.  For instance, if I am making functions that return sets of things, then I might return "the nullptr" for the empty set.  Though usually I'd actually return an empty iterable of some kind to save a branch in usercode.

Comment: For a pointer, I'd say null.  If referring to nullptr in particular as a keyword that does magical things regarding nulliness, I'd use nullptr.  If the meta-topic is about the nullptr itself, then I'd use the nullptr (in the same way that I'd be talking about the true or the false, which is at a meta-level, rather than about true and its truthiness, or false and its property of being falsy).

Comment: I like the use of the `language-lawyer` tag here.

Comment: I'm trying to see value in the question, but not being successful. This seems more like an editorial problem, since it doesn't alter the semantics of the language. I'd even argue this isn't on-topic.

Comment: @Passer By To provide the correct answer to thus question you must understand what exactly `nullptr` is. So not an arbitrary word choice. Refer to the highly upvotes answers for the subtleties that must be considered.

Comment: @Raedwald I don't understand. How then is it different from the linked "What exactly is a nullptr?"

Comment: Do you ever say `x is the 5` or `x is a 5`? The premise of your question ("how do I write this in documentation?") is partly about English grammar and not technicality of the language. I think you should have been more direct about what you actually want to know - "what is the formal definition of nullptr."

Comment: I guess, [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-nullptr) is all you need.

Answer (score 24):

The standard itself uses three forms interchangeably, but none of them is "is a nullptr" or "is the nullptr". If you use any of these three, you're in good company.

## is null

> ```
> int_type underflow();
> ```
>
> 7 *Remarks:* The public members of `basic_streambuf` call this virtual function only if `gptr()` is null or `gptr() >= egptr()`

## is a null pointer

> ```
> int sync();
> ```
>
> 38 *Effects:* [...] After constructing a sentry object, if `rdbuf()` is a null pointer, returns `-1`. [...]

## is `nullptr`

> ```
> void lock();
> ```
>
> 3 *Throws:* [...] `system_error` with an error condition of `operation_not_permitted` if `pm` is `nullptr`. [...]

Comment: FWIW, I'd consider the third case, "if `pm` is `nullptr`", to be an editorial error. `pm` is an (exposition-only) lvalue expression of pointer type, and `nullptr` is a prvalue expression of non-pointer type, so I wouldn't say that technically `pm` *can* "be" `nullptr`. I'd use the first or second phrasing instead.

Answer (score 15):

`nullptr` is a keyword which designates a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. Super-formally, a pointer can therefore not be [a|the] `nullptr`. It can, however, "be null" (or "have a null value").

In your documentation example, I would simply say

> If *ptr* is null, the function ...

Note that `std::nullptr_t` (and thus `nullptr`) is not even a pointer type! It's a special type which can be converted to any pointer to object, pointer to function, or pointer to member. Which I consider as extra justification for not speaking about pointers being `nullptr`; pointers are just null.

Comment: And `nullptr` is _the null pointer literal_.

Comment: @YSC - and it is *a* null pointer constant.

Comment: @Peter mmh ... not sure. It is convertible into a null pointer of any type, but it is not a pointer _per se_.

Comment: @YSC "[ *Note:* `std::nullptr_t`
is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is
a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 7.11
and 7.12.* —end note* ]" C++17 5.13.7/1

Comment: Ho yes! Thank you @Angew.

Answer (score 0):

One context where it might make sense to say “a `nullptr`” is that there is a `NULL` pointer value for every pointer type, and these are not necessarily the same value for all types in every implementation.  (Although you have to go back to some obsolete computers from nearly fifty years ago to find exceptions.)  Someone might call `int* maybe_int_p = nullptr;` “a `nullptr`” and `char* maybe_string_p = nullptr;` “a `nullptr`,” even though neither of these is exactly the same as the constant of type `nullptr_t`.  I’d pronounce it the same as “a `NULL` pointer” anyway.

Even then, you would still say “the `nullptr`” in a context where it was clear which you meant.

As for actual usage, Google ngram viewer can't find any examples of either.  As an earlier answer pointed out, neither term is the official one.  So there’s no established usage to follow, neither one sounds off to me, and people won’t have any trouble understanding what you meant.  If you’re referring to the keyword `nullptr`, that’s a singleton, so it feels more logical to call it “the.” But use whichever you prefer.